# Solve an Anagram

Tags: code-golf, string, permutations

*See also: Granma loves Ana*

You will be given a string of lowercase ASCII letters. Using [this dictionary file](https://hastebin.com/raw/itudojikot) (UPDATED), your task is to solve the anagram. To solve an anagram, you must output all words or groups of words that can be formed using each letter from the input string exactly once, separated by newlines. Groups of the same words in a different order are not unique and should not be output separately; however, the order of the words **does not matter**. The order of output solutions also **does not matter**. If the input cannot form a word, output nothing.

Some useful test cases:

```
Input:  viinlg
Output: living

Input:  fceodglo
Output: code golf

Input:  flogflog
Output: golf golf

Input:  ahwhygi
Output: highway
        high way

Input:  bbbbbb
Output:
```

Rules/caveats:

- You may access the dictionary list any way you like. Command line argument, stdin, reading from file, or reading from internet are all acceptable.
- Input will consist of lowercase ASCII letters only. You are not required to output results in any particular case.
- You will not be given a string that already forms a valid word (you may, however, be given a string that forms *multiple* words, such as `bluehouse`).
- Trailing newlines are allowed but not required.
- Standard loopholes apply.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf). Shortest code in bytes wins. Good luck!

Comment: [Sandbox post.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12926/70388)

Comment: Should we use 1 space to separate sets of words or any non-letter separator suffices?

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer To separate _sets_ of words, any separator is fine; however you should still separate words within a single solution with a space.

Comment: @Christian Rules say you must separate sets of words with newlines though.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Then why did you ask "Should we use 1 space to separate sets of words"? Your question confused me, and there should be no reason to prefer anything over newlines for separating sets. I'd say stick to the spec.

Comment: @Christian What I meant is the separator in-between words of the same set.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Yeah, stick with spaces then.

Comment: Out of curiosity, where did the dictionary file come from? It's pretty small.

Comment: @SteveBennett I put together the medium and long files from here: https://github.com/first20hours/google-10000-english

Comment: No I mean, how was it constructed? How did you choose which words to put in it?

Comment: @SteveBennett I didn't choose the words. I got the files from that GitHub repo.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I get it now, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>341</s> <s>327</s> <s>337</s> 320 bytes

This solution assumes the dictionary is stored in a variable `w` as a set of strings. The first set of `combinations` does not need to use `combinations_with_replacement`, but using the latter saves bytes.

```python
from itertools import*
d,o,j,c={},sorted,''.join,combinations_with_replacement
s,w=o(raw_input()),input()
l=len(s)
r=range(l)
for x in w:d.setdefault(j(o(x)),[]).append(x)
b=set(chain(*[d[j(x)]for y in r for x in c(s,y+1)if j(x) in d]))
print'\n'.join(' '.join(x)for y in r for x in c(b,y+1)if(len(j(x)),o(j(x)))==(l,s))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bL1bj/TKERz4rl@hNx15BQPexwX0S7yGUSSr2TXN22GR3cMx9rd7MzMiszhHBiR8c@bCJotVeYmMjNyu47ku//f//t@PfZ3/Xo68H@s61b@XeVv347/8bfjX@q@vf/X//l//37@qfCMP//rHP/7r11qWf/Xr3JUlHWVd6v/8lOP5P/e8TanPc16Ov9V/ff69/rGnz/8sy3Yef/zzn//iF3@b/j3l5Y/6z7/t/97TMuY/pn/@7bHuf//@e1n@/vl/hv9a8zHkRzqn44@vP9Y/vuVv//v/@Od/TduWl0H@82/dv@VX/uifqSx//Jf/Pvz3L/nm/9BLXHqJ/e9xtf6P@q/r//pv/yyPv@vv6LeG//HPf/5t28ty/OP/XfAof/zj7/zi@5//56t0vMofeudfdkcr/v3nv//9x/Sv@s9/ygr2eR3GaX1M6/i3//WP45n/8a9/JPn/@tAvuvU85N@a094/9bvyC7v8@3kW@2/5z7Lj313/sl@XI/X6J91Zy5Jr1T9aJvlSvniUverPPus5DXbZ/V36XHGBaheYSv9qP5Kv5LHxb163Sb@oRzr03zynMsm/z5ym42mX3e2y274OZ3/oZWe5i17/5smP5M/0W1c98qzfWuUzL/liOefOnk4@J9nd1HPTHaUXkkdJoy3O47Bfquvj@CR76ncZ8mqrglXYy/i0j9/ObrLP79b1pd@o/VN2qj3vvp6j3rWsjf1oz@@SP/LFJYtty7YPuJu9vJPdoOz0udoqz1ta9DujXGWTf88FvzvmJe9pssvFS/tKy5n2Kz6jYh3GPenjj2nOuChWaNxzOuyS8nH6jed6ZL1iL0cET36s9pjHnt74yTrr@cFTxIJxMYd8yHuyd5x3u/0uP3ABu3L1BbOf9Om0lZ/WPmGdVvtv3U0jHkuOmC3P44GNgeNsvz3kWsbF3mnFzRe95yXrxdMw7NiQevDL4lvJlkPsib3wZ9m2@CTZg3aRenZfGbs6H5@c9U/lEU5dvkeay6Rr28mW0V/uxJzoDu6fGTt5y32xu7OdbJ@fu1psDxd5b992XXzoZ53t6sc6pMs22WlbW14X72CTXajXeOe9ymPbUekPfPVYZR/YR8o7qLbAWM09TwnrIb987uW48MIX@0I2gNxZWrAOxxpvz1Zm/fiJt9Mnaynn7MVdeHJH2FnCOd6z7Y31wDOrcdU3s36WaU0DVx9mJfU9Xoi@Dr3kIvetjyv3uMuG4ou0g5yHkmhgdjtBn4TPfhbdj/ocW@mPc8f7lJvnnpCNY3cwnnJK7SimfeAO47qJUV7sbMtD2mupc5rsEMlv2Hvp5ell9@gvD7J@3CDyadhF58DtL3bG9488nC6wPl3BCdN3rv9OGcdmKGPhKu3rA8u76RGVt6b27c2LymrZqygzLNBRDvvdtLg5rk/cr1xHnhxvd0q2tPUo9qNZNrh@/88zTXj/cn1btkkWkE8pi4tlt1vHoqr1sUWRP8Pnvos8ib3jdeKZtxPQn/ImZh763s@/GSs77vMq1sceZOmnc4C/mKZsD/VO02kPtR@l51Ksb7wyOQW7vcMkp2GFTcTGEUNtryDt3PpwkvYAOxxKWtKQcDnuNrlLO5liv8rCJ99lf2G/4e9rXzL2TRreSb6yw5Mmu/@8jLJoulGzO6OaJ5zPjxzp9VP9LPmZsJ0vGy6P2KtT2u2xR3lxeA1H6iac1VFeCLa2nL23fbX2x4rlXNa3r@yc9pdZtql0uxt4uZ6dabcJcoM7XPiOxZ/XwXbfQ8w8T4vcsrw6u8DznGEIsPiDXfPPs@xuPVZbZnuVbgUr7sV8jRhI3PuVxNPpA65YYT3AMOkPuZHF3T8dyjlcuNfHo@2BaneZhw4GNY3JjPYkvhTXLLWe9ltJXvtkxgkXFKu3u6OcMl7QIYYJu3Yzl0ynReszVgQQvLJ9lsUqck/LAIsBo2IPOa0fW4WOpzbh0G3p4jUlnCo329A8Ll0X7k/2vi2JxFlvvPsev2wuln5atsUMk4ytU1f6k3SOp93jn@eKEypm7ISNcJu4bhbrwpbBz6t/11@55MiMzfxbfJYRJKUN70UWw54vf6cZwddYdjvzm1gXWS4zpHph3Ib8e7eo@osLXfsh14A/efGdy/azaGCX45L9bdqNwhh3p9hcvA45XRONyWm7@ZG7nTFNmj7pqhEa2LoMZbVjgY/@7LDqtuweNFV7mDd8eeG5fmP1xV0yABTjMV21VB4DPKc4gyXZnuduoeOxDZgHPGWtBed55l2IATbfNqcvM2FiE21BHif/tm5wlb3stturt30ip87WdZY9jM@UUElsrUc4cWP2/iJQe8Lw1iIxSrJHl2vbIyMQtZMr/gEvTQIkO@XqEPCFWld8nMaV42WWfSp0HNu6nbis7jZYly95QQsDUI9CPnniveruRnhqvsz2x3ogjJMryJHBnya8QPFBBfHltPLtL719hx6kworDPIgBKnaKzCtWWKfZYll9nQePTraTam/DnEF64DswS7yiuR11CYXLbtE/XtdOp3tuA4OqZ3pzI8Bq6u8N8r3Btqcaf8TqiBzVJGCx@gnBrZoi@5xhxxNYzPhA5qImzVZF1p3OSn3GgGjDTsNQqsRZ8OUzo3aL2@yrOSczAIMYcXEj5p4TY9aczGov6grsQySF4eOJCSjrgBBu4S6QB04dToaF37BDHzEo@Juk94pIytygLWuCH1W/Zg9ZqlwQjqWHBcGdxXdws2Kwi31THjerCbaFQjRYj8vOluT/dmDxKmiI7SSn3R5w5smuDA/koHgsoSEEjnsuvP1h7U/ab3UF8GtylPiYYkYO2Is88J1IdsLzuJ90WNzDaYAxkt0tTtqD3NEPQUaGkDb@CdZoLst5MB8utjRjeeCBTg3t4OFpFM2Rwcu51zvp/Y919NdouSlDYjqXh5wibmz5Nd7/OK2d3bi6@HW2vaebiimopR9miq4dnyrpL7bz2c0WOo2S3iErTTMjX4nRbX/xuA5I6JD3HuIibIkHiVkso0k7I98PN4Gkxue3JbAz8ybaUlm4nfslF@Roas9gsmEHqgdzeItj@gEGkfcdtkTdnmUUauXatWwbzIg0ZlnE1e5E/Nl2MOh68dqS2eMYyyk6YVTEXYz2W7L7LV0RP@A25JA/XFq4HaEYbLB8gEVlr0USJbu9iu0klq9Y/CpGHC5YojEzeJ@ifgphsJjQpeJEFGSOn@fKJEGS/4luekee6pCIhanjusLJ988TMRwe2@AL@QYdoewYhiiSXeKztl2/axtXHM1AMORRxpPZ/cR7yQvfOfLzDLu4MvrAv4MaEZ4yOv0tI6HeYS7EJHhG9ZR9YA@TxaVjXyKswRkP7OGSuMGskGzAnS5dfba84diKCLdOCzwfkuLZEqhDgyH7SpsFxAPjWEliF2Z6zAUQOJsJzQ7bWFD6YFhVz3lGrCKRx8eeUrweAtdRPpD@iGtlB90@0tYcuZoiXFzDT9bsYMFDwa2Kn4MLNVdhHrTAJEhI8cJzMLercayZyOBUpKkzNANGGnnzuW0TNrjlELa2AR9N9CnriSjHgjWLK@jl8ndk1ce1ZR5nIk3i1xdke/2@VpyhJT@K3Z7GUMw2EuLttCHBrPK4wGnEzrg5tYwPO1tCk2ybFNtCf6@@iOBweeVclUVji/c6nYhJeAdySVxbwuxjZBRdpjfPc/VUdDo9KPA3vrv7@@RsFk0CKT/1tooX3njY//2AfdlPd6wTUZZzwZ99ZQmaduTx8YcLzeCuqaAdA1mPjXf6kjCuhnfFXRBBlYAyw3YVyeE9UVwOQmZ9IZAkhtBWr9MjaOntIe8SBhlZIeJwWKxhgNVg2np4MGyJPFz4268s@5Q@S36EF7E6pCYmrCsJC6qRtSUysjHtnMgRcJ8mh38nQuxRuuIvtqHSRiDlsfLAV09Y1MzZrevbcnM0MgLpxUfjHT6mZE885hWJufgTrJ5tft69WEjePvAF7mY54Ah/yk70UwFOIJH6xxZ7rufBPWT4D73KspjZnzxtNiDS3uOA9ECNBy7OJxvyCIjNoDAH24/DFpqZS@XmwAU2Oi5@BGAaO8y7HH/zU2ma13o4KoawUdamYA3lzNgL0oCYzhO44kMCptqwBLO@6zrjW3PCxpAbQea3F5rBXsOdPRB3ZFc860gHLanYCLSJqcHpePOVIFTnrnhmibQyvNWGEIC3g43XvHV20Is2ZJOwBvEvggHPRgGEStoHvMKQC@xL4IF4dfLTcWWSYX6UgJtECpvdmURFZq/TcjDySQZyyhn/80R1YX9nYmzr7rgtYzyz@ous2BQAGHDQ79KvsNSefCmkmz1CALInu2fx3UtLFAhZujaclfRePTPewqYRenprjnEFJDFdTEjltDfzUWn4bQtOq8UMcg87wAyDuPYGGTMuB56ddjqjZX3ZDpS/w16WPb1UJOqvIuEjc6Z9Ze6zy6u09PuTB0bCEoW7ARj9MdUXsqAibxSbTCIIBgH62xeCYnoKw0tRq0lI@DUro5kQe4gAVHNlq5rkb4cg0ycxiVGoiKUqLKIYT7yZsoi7QZyavw8LOzVT4W115zAaNLXz6BlUjbPrCPmcvst84pMDr5VI8AY@Iqya04@9yU3eO5f4E1m85Is8tzvv@mGex518ZXxafdVgZlFnw26sgNce5xSJm62klhpoJRkhd7unq7LY6xhlRGbtF3FBx7BlWR5IebWqyeLNhvLjoStj8IMGTAf2ZxkYQgOEzwsOkUbFeG1HNodi2c3u3/K1O5jViQ2Gwdd6F8BQOQKEaxfJtczyLYokIAkE1KaFIoZ/ZYdR97xMwmeA@hb7vxETH6yFmodDAr2Vxcs269EhbktddZsu/gJPL@ma@XMrzNlSTeWVJ4Ax4knWLdyM/RpRqppZkdkBElpptiB2lXvheVcjD7DGS5Xv1Ooi8nQnQLY@DRlJoSzl9kQKaFkOgr3NN@BI8GTw0okca0IZlhUi8nmI0aBXkpgEcUN@EvjXzIBon4Vdu1eG8KY7@UVaMjhP2cPrHgmoHSjfXMw/tS6yojzHIn3DtbHUAy4hsR@PirlbwnBHtpvWoPcIZIsoi0RUWAwe6KhSVK81mTdMGmpc/DUC8cXfgkIdxDmRWcmuljVjNmMefcAJHQPxQ5AuyZtd/1yYCe6aScIe2bm1P7QcBrvOnB4s0aEb/0ConjeLlrvC2tCcrs5LNoAbd0aVVtDDukjMcgG3BNSttUq8osuio@kBIMjzTo0/LvyURU25ZxjITqIPW4pXvjz7V79rFq@Tjf9qDh7oGiytHFl8jLxWGg0Drz3N4bv88DUY9LbSwxIe2Y@TgTDDZYQbCEpmnHYx2r7imosEmEy/noG15@Vrvfhnbzr4R3Jgh@ZbYmJ8nsIdQB7NTjGstlgTUAJ@TfwqysioQXvS6MX2ZPSLXkJtixMkYEe8gCjlUb7tFj/0nk@@RAOpzIIAOQMMU1@H2RJzhZl7ulSWmBn46XE@rnZ8DPSVm7dgQbyCXfXhGZE5pt1OvxUpWuF@d7hzJ6gAN3wujoB8WAvm6hCTwzJZlA6AJTtoPm8n8/JP1PQS7W@/Av9llunVGBwZta@EN7PTUdRf2IlgrC13TJtokBYCf0urkLxeKIsZGYCnW5wkdq/4vspi9waroSFj1EYnIwAYEFB80VkEklOLPEzxoTImpFKSt3b27DXAu9onp8bYfQDDuxwpqcDMpg1e27BvVGw10/OqXLJ02Bgz2OlihVkXkbtcLyQdz5IfLJ3Awh1IJog01LA8UQUaCNgZlpNRFjNEPw12FNcLjngC6lE/BUZb/BbzDosk7SGAqSxeBK80kG@8rS/xdEx5V0mskBqxDNMpFHDwAMO0arpON8pArzKgeucRydefZyJUi4PAYrAZed8R5imAQa47gWw1wri9xZ2p5s5eLsqIzZ@oSCrEr7@xTrBJGmQuq32ePJsza6wmgI2XkeqLlzhZMq5MO@Vw0oKrvcaL2TV7GWmEGN6LXWPOT2LSQ9JffMeq@3BfslGY8GlJBBfRzLYSlre7@Dy9iBHgvyTHXi30ksWTyxaQQPZDh3y@Rs3aY1CQLUqVDLMdH1tQQDrydwt3Kov1NWrilZBKdbAQNfFtA9Q7cfOCZmL42xQ1DAbOAT4ADVy8TpNZPci7JHqNalIZXBqQLS@QXDFwQCoC8yOfO14S17dXJ5LbSUYycDFLn7wmI2sBVEsSE2QtK1@jFZCGhrXqBX5yYvzb6RfgvsjrO1EhUbKGszDk8BMa7vLkNBy3KHKwEQM7NjRa0vrRDDFKFa3mtUcaiXvO8TKV8mjPLbaMxcTHA/t1I7pshWdsQ4kQ6xWICHYhfY8imN8HQ3TEy3LFnYdaDuoEkzZnZ7AweLBt8LU@F0AMBqDj4K/ypvYbJYsGpbBUJZ6wzHRUXJdTk1oEcgfR8lTJo3hJ6JDwyBosI6xY6TolWDh7wGsOOz/LzPAlL4TR8rdssALyoa4FMwu4y6JguSVGdUe5ABSKSjw9twpxDbYGqrIAlcSdS3aYWpxl0TOLKvLL7hKVP7HAH4AwiXRMFh0GeVt7GNOaQJd5iCuEuRFT7TU0OGB41v0cK1M7uF9ZIPDn5CMN6RM/soOidG6eROCoEDjnCzjkqjNdCrdTckScRpmEUklULiL0hVHjQSIWixDnRqJD9tLTxu1T01xBj7CSKlwXnNF6IiY6MjJALSg596vG7sYJM0/fyl5eqcgvD2cGULIkizSrfe4dnKAnGPPFHXKQBCZR7aFXxbEFk2CYzaku8hseyDw8kwCmWrFg78sNdfYCLGv5atee8KKazO2HZz7gyq7ItpWfOaPIQWyfWRsTgrcTavLsQVkCDDrryyIN70gwB@4ByC5BNf7y4k/Zy@FHMMzAOhla@XiISalYFRYYxV@wwLh6tD@ugCssCHU4fmQkoQkNsD8DAKofpsAiWTdsmSt4gbYychBoJ6eEeD29V@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@nMgSN9k1mJY6zuJXksQjqIkdtYzQZakr9PwoSfvBNOpWtbO4XJkCqKCcuB05J4x5JmJDIPhuKEFPnWiV0YQ5XwEejE6ZNKiXiYqex@sRg4cC8yrnhqCT1K9zCKxWE8dUqlzl7CYK16IENfIvQNRv3NiITYYWNK2gELRyBHLSMawk2Iy3f6WfFCvSwfv5TV3Q432wMrLXREvm2HEnAefFo6JoZVQ3qt9oXYJtur4ABXp4QA1ZZIGpn1B7maZsxKCEJzx8wPyVYJEqNjpq3LSghbUQFwoq85RxhbBIyeHxP9JDii@RjeqZphGIy1R2aMSK2Gi/ZQBnt1Q7XpmQ6SYKd1RPI9pQ3Azltf3Jid@gzXS/xeLjmhwKpFOq@ProtnXb4iFhx3JIzk/gUmv/KO8fblVI/r4UtHs2TUPthuuivyJLsgH2rCwU99eBFqkH2NqpxHzGzdQjnraNacR2sFxUY5Z0YJlL9@JWKPZMMwvNsIKYrJWXvrJ5BtABRPqyoX@ScEIpiHPbmrjE1mxviEa@guvD0zaQNIMCQq@W7VD4QjIiiLQx54WG30GGQLzkGygGKgB4OLldNa8B5f8srwgOBSSci/2z59ZSBxavRBqhjdfSVFSXB6lT63utm8FV0dntbjbasmlunDchliTzRdXTSJjHa/UCz4kqR0ewbgAMtiUJ/t8PS5uBAj8yZ7oDwEUB@rTbxEnQBaPpwbZBEUKvGjFmUr1yDsCDCilVWuaidn4u0Wr4ewE0x3qbLjCWq4m9obqdMJwrO4/UI@Q1@jqB6tNu5cYf3RqlIdwQ6f2tG2a@1lhi/8JP@AZWVwDORPiUJDZI9DVKaJCHmktWfPWhhIK/2UQHnJU7R@OfwocXw9AqoeCA/W4HybFbxQjgGbr7YSEoANORSGnNQp5w25/D7jW@LjfgAAWgbofQgMKyXiM3qYR2b9fnHFHvpR1Rnbu2MHKOqIRZ0YRK6vKSmroJ2rii2GU2@1Ktt0l8QFKFplNsgZyhjdLn0GgURM84Di4YJeN2LUCMEkptrD5TK1A1EKNoCFxzg48QlTItH3mRf0eBTmzVqkq44vw6T0wMTRw8p95BtQmaqodyjygQKovE0vcn256zWYErynzYsF2tkBjscTZU2lTNhuOQ8HC7doPpyVkUK6yF6@vcYI47SVaKUgP0dCsRcpDOvGzh99JIZPB2Dq7P0aC6Hz7blKRPXtNhUbVU28twYEOLjOhIoMMbZNqDRA59m5c5fN5wEN9t0JDKVbFzQZiFtVaLD145EPAMQhDWuHvi9vLQG9vrrlAsKSujSnxnFAooGH1TQbKJ03GSqtlfSHtHcXo6xCwri2BcPrrgwGxDd2k3eWPZyvhUuwQFmdD8b6w4lIcDq/YXi71MEN7WSKaXshwrmy9yeygKD0liX4ksxMFGC8/XB3Lpvd1EuLwf0LZMUKY3qka1rjD9wmDYHcXF6t5AmRXYZbVqSwZ5vAFI5pVpIuMGEUvZCrwhufhOckdOAyPcuALONd9MNYE2FdX1E8CybtQ0mBUWPE3BjRnETMxPw0vYSHA9wjuzbMv/VCSza7wM/kQUlOqIswiQjqB5m49oy7xjOrYbpiB0@Gzpnkrol7sQbvHeZdiwM1XADzHLBn5E3gcMKH2npfA7awHsrqRNgZO3NxKr0zxJkw4UQgaXmSN/jQzponaYNIkxIZvZLvIuOUw2qLVHY4J5KLasQrjaZgVuhRQI1S05AI5GkjiZnkk/3UlgbD96FYqQuIBshvGLPPE1VNYwYBFFqdLbSt@WAXI2Nj6wdx4tgIUrV4KH5Hnn@2gHaOOt6nDOTkwmaAFMtwDhVyzRevcHs0ghLjIG@Y3IunqV@f68Rej5dHbwwovPbyCfBIY25mg3Oa3Fp42cJshHOGWBGUtdoaZ5KpABuuQT6v4CH2BBlQI6rIYHBaxO9JJmGrxybiW40PzYa9FSq0EsuwVNKeLjefabamf1nruaIA5Ej9gC0qOXxhniGr4d0Ku1OFJcQkv4bsu5ecUBpDJADawOV4UQ2wVrzcAF60s3tBYLSDTbsCQhKJHolcVaPV0WRIlMOdYBchYniwGq7gqmMhS3UTWnp8t9M2LGQRg7cCyg4Rb987hZrgf2pMnMouEd5edXrmkt/oSz0kxGHio0Vg@15aro9tONvMtZ3Ki62FvRmk2e9XzS/qnvLmp@wFbNKaXZYAua/9bR4YGZdFnBuOptJ/2YVeJkndHnjh7hEt0vIvDUmp0Q5gYYW8fgLUeJvWl4b883SoNfcRBlcLDro8jSgEKOmNRlSzUzOP19yt8OcJbTBay8PKdOcwAK5pbfr5sB3ZxT2P01orOKePUlks1N4hbOvl7RnZxB4S4@MC1ZcYO9jnWqz8ZrOaIacdOc62szx/3XKDZXanRiNuJj23kxh2ZRsdgdOXf3jneg9JiQB23IfcubGhjTSfj0pOFJumXBhCWL@eXUzTBl2Glti3VnnsVsVhn/TFNDPPs3bRaqH3PmDpf1CUCRK38sMTy/hqDg5nZ5M1mQfGVKQ7fHIH/p82ACQw9RvuhLVS6MVBUA9xZ/KEviTSrWxMIf9teQU8@BuqYMTOZmw2Kxp@yQRAeVKweI/99MJOoQ9jcmtgEXyJN5XMV/2zhSuOBaKDQHNG7ly1rcWusURX2aS3j25unDlJLibnuad3bo0YzPxdM8GOS3W0PQ8elvIQpkey7LyeI5sw0ReknmSJW2Wx3V@nWBhwhSdw0ZULAvxTfTa8zeLFekOHAL/APg3eBfVwPuRTK4EXO2ZmUFX2tXX218CfnJyDzxicY4DmeBLVmcYSCK6tS68So6/ouXeHa0TyyYt0gPTTRgSUpUnZAwnqENNKXuWE4O8H8I521E9Ix42Z@/EoS@zRUx9FgocKJ7etTtOfUGzvTnlKMraUs2cW6fuByuqxn4DMbrBsiiKBpI3qftG1SP8e9VLruSSoGej@tAJtmgt72DSgCLiiuid/qeDJ5DoHwSm4deeiwiDh7IMGR6yTBcaohRFLSyAJlg94R0rzWBjagL4i2xrw7p6eqNRZgqUyL0S9Fw/KFBK1MuZU/jytULbkbic6VyWzgo0mm3GU25yZJ7P13tJLW00Jq9nQWt1fiSMEkVNbwG0HHZ8MfF/CKRDWU2HPWqYaRXonFCLVAKMN/3kq0OWth7KDF4YMxKbyDGN1rPMqr@ATiDntFq32jizRiDReVfvIGn9IcHQFEiM0oBhJXp4mOcnbxg0ZtXuh@9SwiIUj9reJz1xyasVUEs8QApiUkiNoODrHtTHtOlhOuFhW1n4GgKcaIi@DH1ZUxz0d/2KThu4XApxa6ZlBZnIJkrcHI@lQXorhL5qAANpSXjLc9afMbsu2y7sHxYqcVuStKypyvXN4JfpQz8DcjsukDWgHF4AdVPwJ@pftqWWf1ag9es@OvSom1RJoiImaa3CpgE17rdikFwrrnJWUqAf5ieI74AJHOcWITZLWYAu2wsch8IHR0KOVwhDiA82eaXO7HaXMKlFE1NJDiMfr@BkaHXlc4CqPDztjtCEHFna8NmytnboZShtjy8ii/P8LCcCMFmpZI3r3iVYDnHeUQU63WoMsfCaL4lke8A7ezn4GH7Ggnx04nvOy0M8qWV1HmvebcLZL5izaRwUEsCuo4ZtAkoNvjiPIwWdefHmLgSrAIUVdkUyuKGZYHOwNwoTZ5bc7/PIWO3tOkmUgNoYAy05@JHpB1GkgnJo1IwHQkxdCSsydYDdd74IyWk9n72x6BLxEMjPXT9aLaERAuAcly4LrrKJ2rbefkXWdkzMOnftihPWKEIUEazPzmWoNnsV3xZEceagXAfPFUdbdSdq7/C955bxEkFu9PFlJaR0bVFedpeu5I9klaSsAu4qLj9HfDdl6I8wYqKvYnUiRPNtHLeO7NyQDagj2OCdsAYQdWPcizCHhLpMtUMmsQETemBZFQtHBLSKLTc66NOktIz9tFKraTtRe32voI5370UQryHXd1wIjcVjgc6xyMLpEWv8GjvI@AT0og/cuVv@SUiEX8nYGhrIH4SMMA6mAJtfjyau@omXRO0PpjiyaOqK3jKpT/sxxPt8lHwtRIq0qwc5WFu9NI8RLQDyiugWBIsuuQPuasQajK4qaV5FnM6ZTHRuobY0r1UYetV2GeVgFxkf/yzovCEZaJS7saNLm5oyok3ny7KViQEyZJUXsbtXYM5yuulO13wpSXo10wDLnJeNwaT3LywmOx4acUjehtMggmWorykUeXKwjhw7fgc0@nd8oeMzsMVk8@J0oXjCcu4fqm/jjE0b9kToka@Z07JTRuEChoEYTKNC26XLsWreRvfrMPW3JmGuZ4Oq9ROVIGzcvZ3bn45GmQEhZkdydyuXtTdlVXR4kRydWZ418OzhmvrRaN2RIBm5u5YxPrDS7cpmaVXJ@zq4Lcqt3lM1bIomu4thqbrGw3wj@Un@CHMVs1GYaoVhu72lUXm5wpECFkP14sEV5fTkvdiEJ5XCvHyg0CgtuZmjX9@McyaP97MStdnZMi8XCVbUt2pk2B/untBD3ZidEAklM3wp5Wko@W7I30tHzB@FfyQ@kIe4mPnmQmKu4VxRPgGXTrmDHdU1OJve0AeRpsOuwtVX3z0zKkR2JVdaaL@6QuORDZR1E08V38HPtuuLiVefABqNKKNpr@xqCQaGCfZYQZGLbBaopg1eViwcc2@bKAAdLMpZ0vteJgKP8vbx2i/zBCVxdGAXaDS4opVuqBgcGgZmyBnBwEnWvJJK9JhayEcYtrmf2WaFlitc0UvqMiZousu2Xz@XpujzvmxQU05RCxEjCvCxQiR5z9u7oSyfvXIJbeqvZ8EZ7yztth4mVuuIGQmwVY2LUkxOehN09CDKWRhXsLNpaKJa37awOSZKWvQiJWyTJDuFCzq5bBCk1Nk3PpDj0lGSSZIOshDnztT8ypQVSqEtAkoE@7oUmNe48tAlWRwDxIwqAsR1ea2ZwMOdC4qXXIVaq/WnzE8JYP@zs6cM5ZjKN3p3kXU6RXoygoAyZKgV5q07nJH5s7Cl3rF72mmWr8RchBuHUKUACx5OoMQnOj@KdWQ8QFwGnI0T3Wtm2y/c8yAJx1PQoPP9kqKDiGKS5KPzOlinNpNlOk12uTLw6@Dvsfq7eI0y9KOzhdMEXrCTuHW7v0ZBl5xAhsUHS3hRAGagxCBCVjhFhtul3OlUtknMgEk657JNyJVjHsDRTWXoluosZA5ttxa0V8WALkPPVc12DotBbvl7gfEENEKV/vgHxRCzpnt4Dqv4QNv7c8VwTiXLzydaQrWyZbq1ey5G@8ZpYL3tBe9NYDNXVB0BbUd4FvI220XFPuFStIX8s/UgwyUSQId7O9Fxe7O44Q@eHHCZGfRP4HU8AV0rvRo3YmkkW8rMIES9ivUcSUdghrrIT5eCOBgHb9OkQJoQqXO1REdSOH2xx1WhRElpTVEKDomwRdsQeVEugQIGC4zQJew/avzaxstNByaYAFg52Pa2dC6Q@ClEQZRU6ZzHwM5WYmcnRct41KreVDG5cY/K@pmiNGrzArFzLWwcpC/4kDxyuV6iNSMdNPQGPSQ2WST1BCo03VufPgWnNARFh3dRvskG9S1aO0pNKBPuKbCt5l2T65ArpH9ODYGPg6fTH0jt0X58RxIUasvcN7YFh12Cqwc0mSLfJKeTaFIXGv1thDOb1jQaAxbU2rCHLSWkLSWJNpIcxgNWFojWcbSQb6qvoz62haOLtmd5CMdP2AqKtwTK3NULGMWgfO/QuPCsBfMOqG0vZtuJcpcy2kAf3N1itCGgvhOyn12YGZV1TdGFhTfuibKZ1rdQGR8CIEkNS8NZzI6LrJh1AOY1grss1KEdWe6RZa3WhmbnjuRJP7HHMypBoouqCvVo0NxWgqi9vB3qunshK6gizTIeNCp1rCkJdjJzi5Ehw7hBXKaZFYZvnuXt2Qqx6orgn2iwojgb5GyRorfG8UqSjQudmILit27hmmNafn4QSJa9/RWPHDjlMSUBm7ANlb@IVn6@dLAvxjlxqLTuxa3E6PRswzld12fYUHSAQPFoJyO5qzV1asJCZqIvODr6ThLs92Idf64tdRr5dj095oVIjexNdVYk1HrVYBm2o/l52uQZWwtidNCg0C2B/d0kWUp@VkOZsk0GRFEhNdSsUJ58Q9TH9rDiIZmK1tu/JrakZWME/R6uIZHvsgFuhzathVqLGKFotiLAr6s1lVhdlO7SMS3CJDTU4l8La2sfV@t@pP834adU3RAZq0P@IeNkWkCClDzmj/U1b6XqsJl0BvaodlYEvDVWeZoPk5boqsJa0GRjp06HcprDRRSUyHC8rqoPTtVNqnWJlx3Ni8KKuGgUwVQa90PWJgu4Rfb7apIQ2a20/d07oo7Ahlpw9TY4m@p3KTLuDyxNz6BDajlavpwS5eMkQ3yc@7w7OaNg/MC6gQG7nzw96hIu7Mon66Ro/dKlaXp2KH9OFKijOXDZKMeoQoH9NriSleeyrgUiUJCAAdS3ibLHYsmUKe2Ul9zkuV0ti6dPL5GVPfxbXkmPGDpbAl1a3em6/jbMEUDKi7JD2zIOUv2HYQFUwfj/a5gmCCWN25oSjCz6t3EMKS5MRf0ATCoKdFDqgKBsFsOpcGBe6dOyKJEvlT@2Ndec08hAkwr7GU9@j3HaTrsOxXyenzJw9eV9vKvzJ51rMRxNkzup1rTRP6EspLyIJy8C6J@OVkSKn8g6IfDI7Y1uMkRFhoTW5QTunUqgItJ4872kipJfY3qWMXkKw1YULXh5WufvuxTggPig9s6EVSESfIiJ4FEq/KGWrOjYVumTeuUClsZo9twCNp9N@a1pvwE@rV5kpngjpPGrQOwI7rovtHdKF8bShF9mfsxcVekop6BkhHFim6WrdHSBS5X1sGMHTIOBe21ZAjWI/J9Q2SX11MWT2uyGOnt7ZNX6DGg6TMUTlWJual6sxCNlf7qgwetsPdv9aOIvExHFE7RPts3cz8x4eWHItWJIEMXcTBf3wLm30CjjiG1oYSyj1ENKvjgdU12ulsisV4OhytPTaXzFzZYA/GHn6j4TO1o9cGwSt5463Innk6S2QbtkUIB7grJ@Xtu2xgQ4hNGyMuFlQZQsrGF2A11rFMkusi3vWxtWnkeYIAIlQbZEhItQlYl2vtJNdJ65z4gadnW@l@4PHBikB215x9a8yz2xleCYo3ihTB7joLuYjB@nxT@NurCxqn2N3NRYSW44BoUGyBWXy@aROEkrv0EirUWaggBCqChbfcnObZAYdMge0MP@1/H5xjHBgT91N3npoLQd7E0Br/YiVciswwXD7poZyMWrILn5LZfPsHWrnUckaXC7IwHWAMWXbEtpcTgo1Zw3zEf2aOI@zvDZHlZ7WHYhYoss9qhGg@ZpwNTq9xaWyt3dMUf0ha58JTJmo@68FT3hotAGyF93Aq@o97MZrqz5uoRIUXNnI68Jka8O/efUhprhkeBDx3Gi7t@DeqTqJAgX9KwhHqGlsiegDXDLauY4ccHZtrsgpo3CK2woxsUGOk5eoJMrEwIvQNrOMq7KHyqHag7btQ4RrWz8wFJZYsGDex4gJCwuqi264wq7rWCxw5DtrfVEhIK8X/cEDs4tlBSyiscYIGWCjDSOFkFyawfzu1WifhYGX@3KOw0Rl6SkKQmg0oKAhteqmicugCqzUz47ysjK4ae86KmrI/l3AlFOVVW/Lo@KmBAEbbeDiIyFM5tH6hhYHtCFVhXWesCSKOtIRaAUU70ontXRIK1ncP8S2LiRMecewN9mNdOfW98N@hU5@n5Tu/GHJJhNPrL0XkjWRIoBuFK0B@IsLxSv8QKurZgOtA/LqyoFpMHkZo9fNrbLJVVOMRmvqCBj2LbMdlC1cTtftPAki0FiD0cLClOfL8hCuGux1j6fPGlq9NVUZszUE2rz7AAHFTtgDXcJmH0yukoODpu1J6UXwG@cuc7yC7KKvjJPz40SgfasOBntdEBkLcWg5KxowUJ4YCKgsgasMq8vN0G/uKSSoSRki4kIoEVjP4Ef8QfKpN9TJ1i4AS8Q41JiZ5uN8QBFeV5C@VYgFBbT9TWUnC2orZUpI1FyPI32ggz6w46yGuMLuIgbKTIh5I1itd3ImOWJVmNX@YhskWqcc6jtBAh9cowWAAWBpRs3KLagtYW4eySUkGVy6OrzNRvEcBzD4uhlpITuzgcpRaWJKWRbU/00hiKmcJEUvcrmcRcIDqRyxYUUte2rzEDJ7jb5IcXusrvTGiTEm2moxii7IwhZgK1x/P48Z7cJaUVmXAG9D4ap6u16wZqjjCTQMOtnwFEY8p6DDntk@Yip2rKQ5TGm9RtheVDfWDhiK3tlxyJ4lY2@Imzu9osxQe2IFLqV9dWj6CUztYHlXaTBsDGVUUOniamiG5WBS@agwDoSxlhQMvFDmCp/@6h0fLMMSGjiK0k5XiLewx41eUCE7y5xNssW@mk/2hhSfnWUd31PEtKxoLosOLwGzi1UucjasaZNYTGi8F7LzVQfFFZ44A2Fwpl83AS6vp/ZBgRz5fY25lbNRgUekbvrmTqJGnyLRxy3k/tYSI/4k5rQwazh3xKTojCLDcLJdpXvpzaFwUQlQdiargN7tqN3eod6Dh7fkArkRkTMqmxO7lX@ra2OaBom2viCvlVWzoGa65o3B9ew5oRXqnY1WndInP@2AaItFU10pbjsq0oTrN1WlEsOqdgqrR0@awfbvBLPxzB@9VmvjqT5kLFNWqX/trV@tIqJ4oKAuN4zRAE@q@5TZS8c01krYQDhKjQcOE1PyPbhdqrlEbpeV5nDknfVk8xSqjwJgyYOZinqz5JGKBUos/Es42gESAAu2L3fEFnHG6/I5JBPj4uOTsSRI9ukwsDd1umR/dn6ET1bpqJzpA1XS4AmtJlo7sM0DfWzGw6mu/g03yZKn7MIucPCVI7oelPVPO83rQulAiYCYKvsAyxpaNHMmZNqf0JuxqgDiE5@2ZoKOiHOjp0mNpKtyeAh3GkHoWWI4lLYPm02fdGaos6PAqEiv6F@YVuo6ftgUoFpLoJXAUtazkGzMGScAvhL@6uuk9CE11axNCHh1Oknnd23hTdINiOikixGGcduySa@pEt4S8gZwP/7K9KyxGTEfrdWqZ@XDKgC4Lc/KJZsCM6dTUw7q/depiiroLhcHgkFJ/XpS0EfhxI@Pa6g8sDBOA5tg3HJXVZumPjAFDem3HqdrHBfPC1UedXeyBnABZfGeC3sJ3ilET58uPZXbVAtggWY/r@Dow9KtcvwSZVoopk3x2gczYFRInWtBW/ENOHUxGjx6smojhlf2SZHSnijnIdvxlSHO/qY6wMsbhSWMo0gSIezhy8sJXaF@z3bG@Ki03QZtsAU/pElPbwEWK4EzgWkJ5AYrfOhNfE3HK@xwHBKJ4dYcvQ9ADq/ebNnPwMmse5spWueg4ar3jjYf2ROHc6c8CdiLKwSGcLEGB9DNBYjM6P0cQYNB7zsqgSdHkakuIbUv2JbUhbK86tU1RiMf808fSdFF7qRI0Roq5NWHEYN4UQB5P0nbNjKiC0DNoWxwMNlBPyMb5pTD4p9wkIkz0MKY0qFT1qkuP68/JLlp9kxeLSbM2jUz@SHz6rnLs7Q2TVSsS14ccF13j@xtxTA34Eesbuo@2Yc1xLhcj6fF38mRR594T1pqRiV7uabVdT0r09GrsdSBu5ha2IH2EWrtSGAc4qnf7NBTcX1vBDep3B7PRktOtUSSzvPBeXJkanbsqbDez9AggeZlDWZJerCVRxvw9ltzPnaOcioRDw@myQ@OycmUr57R7Bh6zecRLanothDPM4KQ4iJgksX0IQBdQ3F4IO89pm1bU/q4g2EixjkjAVzZAzxS4UfZ7DMkRpAParEnN@q03TxpLnvIESlH1QIUSEw7zI7qoGsiNfUiE2fAgCCtZ5abyjGmdEiGf4OumNp1TCXeERsWihEBuSBRb/FBFIdTlQkMU9tvRITt@2eXxP/D19NE373nRPJYrzVKhDxdS3Rm19BD5gtigksPL@naToU/Nh0rfRFPl7CprWFiwRYwa2Dc/4F2moj4wGKD5A2b6eeY6CqiL1BjSNoiSsfKmXuiLxfvsUgddVD0gwGqL94xiPii20/MqdXKV72qq@a3Up1DA8SzK7ujXutgAkliRpCuSQDtOHmoUq8Lev9UHodyoRIug5@nG8I1S97saOcIYiNA/lBcIzlFTKtIlN6bXHxMLBCQNJPP@/ZwxzqK0on5XG2Y3SMoFJp3sobCSgyU/mojMroy7VKdInGwNPJtuxxYFFFq7DBTML/1QVb6yxqyLdH@jQ22/FDHFdNtT6fvzAk9kjVUafbTZ7oOX4mA33HGEKmNynL5ez3YT2VpQ@DrijUDmLEGgBqV32gfvSsrOtiwsfE7IetUbVtXrc2aqV1IAYKaTmHudCIVsYa46vO2W12AY2BciWNYQWTs8vLFeo7EYTAlk/c0nMN1Y@YCYYCeu44mWjzfO0mvMb01Hcc8x3iyvSnHViZSTiTiPEtWTNEiavXske@4OzkW9UgQmfwh9ryTEqRN49z0idLWmulBMPDxcBBZG1sOx3btyboJNha8Rcz2OlFyyG0AhAJh1Qv4Fix8UaEEwsZoFHluXYflp8TnTsrIWibOj2FfNBjb0QXjUAkZhZ7VyY9cx1POCwum0elFcVh7FVv@aXrSA0eaUwGGAf@52dEnVfYcvfOWJRco42mmLDnM4WT8Cl4R@9R9KPjm0itmoxGsfXA60/LNoQma@K2cS@9FZ/Jz5L04AL@vUPvYVOAFrMGZdQgMRuQQqeR8sm8xTt9RiEbWhQqr3WdtTeW4r/5FIs/kKXMGf8skJscmSulqOm@Jq3p0pE5KuYsWaJcCnlxhAKrZErNTI60ycko6Rpo0TBx0pIc6Rubj/fXli@FSXklQAjWZ1bU1JACaZk2lJJRPvqDpNOUJOM@NJd7dhzt7bGAEENSzhsohr@uUPF2byFmBFNAcKmzUxHiX5TaaxHuNWRD01vMulBaAITovh0AYhGJyFGHkQ3skYLJ3qJACrU92EgBeVPw6ejw1RCYLHj6PsliV4TA1QgqFT@ZoUl@S7CArc/Y@ewhBEgyYh65VCUWEVFcwFZQUgexuRQlYEdnqQqGvmD1SqIId459z70oSqxcLVL97RXtN/aCn305g9V8y0LMj@c2UwF24AXr6aDYYGELoZCGO@pjS3A2JkgKXvxiniiBnWslVVe1bAmuyS1gInZTywb9DJ95E26Kj1DmaalmnczqRVvlsB@9bfq4zx8NpQQXnYaKMJ3RAHk6OS13H1kJvloFEjt3knEwoDGNJiBcACHjeBgBUH8SmEqqTj2V0QYgKIjVFZL1TmTVj@jpl6G@sgut8i@PyKR3wKthK1C7ZCbxz@GF1cU6xY3IMF598@bRUSsvs1emQfJxn7qDPODoO6t5UiZ0Ded8nsa5phUNVymljkfrIQCbiAA6iHsukPrlC2SMKRyV2gtXAb13IiGXfJUc7LCALNqAbj2d3CZ1o1OCgv4m0ZA7cQKvezObzbzPuYmdfPO1d@WEFRz4O8bXOwitegV6Yxm0hDWXj5zkQ4ctxrKpKkmZ9FZcNBUIUihXJrHDvMT/VBrVh1MIzccrh@kEJcJZAksONOFR2D/M5lLNSodU7wbUBfQkZGI9cwKrqOt5T3oiOkZPLTg6W13O08uwXZ/J6v46GNYezBquN/JINAX6chFHvNLCxekowUMu@oiDGCHVjd5mh4ECTlx8WWrYm030uIdekGe1dn98nJXlrGAUZvnSToxV94YhGjcTtwixyhep/JdPOm8xHb0P4zgoJDwC3i4/97DnrT6vOe4jNfUMuunCGzrXI3i@sZQ6ccyhurWBv@EBWWjxbJA5OMHrxwckuFsn0J9fxubrKlM3vc@@5U16YEJVBGciVEiUO2fnX5osRxO/ODjAtmRLR@UkuaOkAYr7109BrXIhv9g6Wmtp8rrEhfHTAQT/MNm37FkZx9JfDXdTgS/OaXGmGaq6qGeimZmecr9VlH58ztITPrMkT2Xzt1ba7Sg3wCarwe9MNJs2Ak@Hj/ig4FKOyKIDuec7hqsaZJYLj5IBV070hqK6CBSlkV5gIrmSCI3fLRFpsPFY0ATtG9pLo6quQzkt3Td7X7j137gs5u4a/pUMGL4rK5xDyr212LODH8QRgLi@V4HcE9Iri4aySyWGsN5JHyGkbzZXBZst@@AY9RA@Y05cI0XQmLFSjDb66fAmlWjG/zPm27DJCYz3pvEOi5klmDbGT1Lhw7s5@U3NsM2FZJ2DcTLEmmJRvTzUfpGz3p5YROEsNGcd8WSOSmxNmgNd04uZRopEoYZ0G1zXBe2fTsVpfSk8yBqFTx92w9/8xAc@YJAKELNBBiWWjUQRKljlPOevyTZefZuYvGnYVytROqEYdlHxBH5btpvNDbHvGeJ9kykm3TcX5NFGahSffJCGmQtanqUDoziI3aLE3r8YBadHpQ04eu8tS764wpl3dFtVmU21nWRm293ly6eoRA6tNHLiGjl4rCMWseDyKStQ1Ue/KYcUTSYFfZDRt6aI50Lo1E0KtSBWewuAaP0s0r04J96mze@WNVjRa4CWBzogMNfdPU9nocgyoMoMJq8O6Vp6gl1zmGZZUrBJeHcwQ9VWj5LAnbseyhI6gWiSLx4xAxWjYBc50Lk7wl6uPCUXw4krLU3QQJzadSD7RGg5yB2RgLtGPwnZsVLhCJ5BqA2WgsbF@e4p@OqtqGV@2ys9zfJJy8pB9cZHm3GQ7fZarasPlaMCwNlRmPXNeOKzi7fwszkqcMWtdsd4aHWIw3qqBYCoZREGIdCPK924VVr9qoMPmhIbBC8MTtZrZk9btV4r2XkKOiJ18ApB8/ItIZVmYpnxCRkNClscjxsMCsYj2TG2sgpE4CkvCRvmoHDxysYMCskm2HqcnfgcHOjPqhFqLm1vE3h8Gh6AzocChZ4KguestaiXy4z0vvU/e3UluwZPp9nsnMgS6OhAPZonw6S0QcLTeF4hkE6QXBOhnj5ehekMwTMZfJe5ZHihqxVAR1mJx@vopvFtIpyw33TyiZV6//Er92plPY9V0J2Yqrm5GWiqLvkJwvuOrWdI75nNnfIlZLbWpWxB@eZ7omSeyqlQ0x0Ovw3WD2D9hs8DZQbFPK3rTkFOYDn7iSGXm5EMR42S1dGtWhn7E6pxNBZYYfUkEY4/Wr1vs7n3g2FYI/xSUgQc736dkRUMi5ZKdp7BI4sCGRNTVzL8CQjM0AC/Uy1RogaMrXxMomQZ1XGRfIN4l/XCnco2NxTOfMerMov1q2nfs7uCIRlOThpKUc/Wts70NUawx86867kMpQeU8QiJFskXO7HIOBCk9Ic7Y6qh2V2K0O9eS3@Gt6vlzWmudUlpkVVAM95rpk7tI4kHAgD0PG9T0OUl0poKwhkgJw8i1Zjug0VB@gaDzVkDJH7yAZmJJw4pn3a/qAr77ez1rYDnRpGqHpI/2GxvE12OS0ek8lg79zqzlsCEw@TBwed@dP@vRxpM0PZTq05DRGvtMJ02SvKZnKq7iyiZu7HydFEDQzuSwWSYjnyHtjHXG0tXV@2p9oC8kn0wCF@E9k2Yxs@sUzMvVWhGBSGWeT8mO2zsiUBZSqA/PSbRADgBETuzTTpm6eC6Pq3SYClDIXjDRo9amsc7toP4k0mue16BV0oVRFXt7bPDF4RFjQLVH9jnkVC9gJ5nCZkd1vQ5YIXb4eUiNXMxZMeR/UUp@d3kjzO02F2/qHa5k9SReycnkHq@zLNFxagBCLkwusJZLzqTGgDUXAjXwmyEd04G5joXyvyuy7tHhr84LBWl6EBlcJ03ISbrIlwNj5M/MLsIo6Y7xhyRsJNGqyz1obj5jkPw4F1bmtFQt1I9AYav8uwfMBWO32S2LgSZkOeSMPhGjtVtZ0MbLJZfIwCJWpDvGUWC@Qv13zWuYtE7rFXr01eWXMluT2TYomYNbL@uDAU5Dhq52e9YmmatXX@BL69mTCzhlOfQ7vnL0Qmtni3dMKZ@LYi5exU6Xz3pEJyYsgHzYO4HUNFAn/CX5HwgaCuAiIvBYkQAji07QW2YDlg88273fRH4yn1TVoucxXg04g3l6rWvTo/CUEImYbBkfioTxoiQVPUDKM4FV8J/ZUpoeuFEND@yEvQpl7HViNZsS2c6/uyBm@hkoflfo13eQreZVjhDzN1dxqJf2XllHj6r89eyWkcNtqPGS6mC9VOd@jiektsvchuzhAU/67nElT1Glo@1onQ67OW9RhakrZ1DRuyv/dCDWQVPJPnvuG6j0egsRpGRdmpPFxxfLC4Tho1PioJYYlfSqpzfIkEsMA0A3OVNuwImD3AJVNGNqQ6fjPneSNjCT/Oxopwfvbd00hmZt/wKyTVdGRSP24Xuaw4EIK2dTi094rhzndAaDZJ69P8w56/tJVt3iM4pVmZLqOfQP55c88@l5tadMPbXNvxOVPJ1Pp2O/wV2xhschGL60gY/dBzvZBEswsCcr93aco8QhjGxMwqurq3NLnzqYCOOpTiZikyGnld7MUfNv3zeUUIwZMC42ABgjs@@ismNWFZe8OSuh4VJMITfnLg4c70zpuzFisxL9ISSvUQEN9fEs4uiRe8mBvKK1PUdLGsOLdWLyZa8OkHea0rdniTxri2TizxWRtTcToScd0bM2hLpMKUSzlHPJtZxRhOxOzkZZ8qcr2bsNEFcMaf84Me7lJWZO8RwmJ5UcGHn@2EOtT193z@7ZyTVa2ImlXQcOa0pcj8Baljd0sVO/cjQzd13MMhDT7YlxKjtV8N4q74h@lswmfCobgQE0vVdAZvCNa4fYjGL13uGLolYoMnydjHG0AxzY0ObFtQHn6pHEcnjAOZtMvY7pZdmcxEb4eNREKpvMsxeDXRPBBHNtv6nz47SgVHsbFijP4vQV5e27os4e1P6B4mNHNEcf1J8xnimzfk7F0@LihmojUAUtPTELIBFgiITLP6d6601MNTHfU7AB1LPa8EDMNmePt8uvTfmbYq1sULDjocNQGNdoSRhWdw3CSz7HzKHKB5QYVTmBFmUB@V/2/YxpBV9rfZ7e588CRuKmVhnaIbs8SyVKRiONGRfeoo@hTfu6J5dp5/4ltGEi1DksTJs37to9rKDDTOzPSwJnCNFAC1BxKE4tJHap6scUzTMN79ZTwg0CmpzLUatU2ZQMhFjRxTpdWB0lTO8cr4fXNQd3Uem6RPxTTAk3LeRoxVVUhcn17FMR@@TTaXz0WP88gemo4SN5Z@Ech4XMNHltBxGIvDl7f4KMldIkfDjJ54BcwA5kAQBW9bnWbUIBu5UJh0yQmqik6aOJ2hHAwqoy7tFUmDmMTqIJSKiyDWwgfBItYU39neRUjTvQyfTpVgCQTx/cqGRDnPqXzl1rCnBUIrx8siW2RSDv00moVNNLzhJG0cP0wivVVU9IXywm9XYFWsBWfyIrOo3GrYh1xcvZd3FRE24Dqn8cK1SOERenaVTt91CaopomiaL4V5voWMM8WLtVMMu7w/uTzBzCpJ89NKQxbKI6RykssqsqahUHsadrA50DndIS4ajPhDWOMelkEgSli4oFvNkn8Dal7HIw@iN5/skpGEboYlqn000n9qYWKpj5zLPHhDHoisXgdYBkiOIysWYTKkLNIttYV7y/edUAE7VjNpA9gnSCohhRdrWxMc@RRTRE16qw4l0jB@YiVBVyvvzGvW1CZxcx3g1NyoFgkBJoIMxkQp7ASCTFcs0up1g6Wx2TaNPCKY4nZzuZMKgFk1Tohzg3/GKFMmSfLnBtv5IqG7I8Dj1WR3/WjYHjuY9wV1BHQP/3gUG0/TV5HvYhv7FfMdhpOzcbIP9KMA@mM8dAbScvyYQ/qOG5EVhT7Z3iM7wcA9NKMBrUTYnA28IPdCnVGfUh1RCiKHivNZ03C1XyVrHlUHltsUUNXQ6fOQ7lII4lH6Iyr07KrJ1NBqYUBxMpBmOj4lkU4TLhi8oIy9kTJr7BAvJU4ZjXoMVfC5W3MTi1UU89hMyESY/EE/rnWX5@fHb8w0KX6QQKKsZV@epP1lAw/@tynXg@E@a4@UB08Aq7aFq2hiG/ucVQc8h1YZ5LWmZWLw45agdHQLNqiHF5hNOwC7TlmTKrqpwIATXl5eygWkuw4crnmgOOJxSLvSOuT@dRokOpcmY1hIbE29sitKiyTbHrMI/SJuhiAhI5ZGJMoxUbNcLQvNLKilHBoJ6PPxObDq7fyxXvd9bwPyH9Zz1ytv5TQOQf7x9/sYtZJRR9bKlpbwA34ay6ysBOvOKYchu8znPD4ouWbslfW0gdzG/X4/mQCL8z9tnzM3XY1KfNHrNZafbHllBQXnpHEXX5uewjfrTdqfousU8YVEMAoamk1hObEn0ihEkFa18GaEYKF3KOjlaPKHa4Q7zBUOnejK4pKbDXixQK6z1iOPaAPEGdOF@2lrXJmOQ25xO8AvjtgU5ebzezAlDpOQGzqGJW9bhK@zd4@inNYF3iYCOJm4A8FDJJMyCVmBQbLgFSY/qR0xYY369LiS5cgPvyj8IoULuuNNnPDEn4Lni0YFXFRLLqtq0nv48NyIg/@7NLrk@EdU4Tp6WnZeyoxXOyeCsvga2lP2RHKKjTWyNTl47ZpSddskGhaHxTnPozG/9UDw3LzAOt4HQSAH3oVGSOjM9R@V49wFBUf0TC/or5NluaZja@YtbnJobPm@snH4S26YVTTwH6ncSGPuPVkBEH9OvTZtSSFT2fC9Zdmyi7GsOSsw8/JKHH5sThnjQs8e1OfNMAoRqaMjRXCyrKhZrKOqrk5UUxFg1378Lx2qz6tskJKMTQtNA54Vs9pw4/fJB9eRyYs/4gY3TTees@X8qHCqR@v7BLovip7gkE/sOn7mlBYyEZcBiIyU2URkhUMrKUEhmWijyTvaIKepDw1fo7N2Q0jbKuh8h/0Lyq5/iDj1VPZAfOoFJg5jTI@Wwu3dlyYGeTYXGiCr1y5BiXjKmujEtBm2HFBYCGqupjNo1GjoabpREjOeTmXAbbWgere9PLuX0U1nHZuEzU3pDSxacfQRcrMXggFdbODhQ4Pz5DGKytwcmxHs3BoH2fULV35WuLeEPq3qkHxB/pNL/Wrvkbbr1xxbQfLbMfbcS4zzvhttUweubUKiDcEwZE2eyoEoO3e07NmPL2RCZyqSnTO5FsAcO7CWaRDZDRLMrF@N4yuGFj@Kc@6DxqXNG4OblmvOr/lezCxgRC9BzDVGnKUzhOZefZNtkj1@ex37ookWqX9XNP8jxE7KFvjlznFQiSqfvAuTvCeJ0vVie8ndPkvHofmoSUx@R8nFQRI6JMocVHgFv6WVyqzDoebdictWQgh2VNTBkQM86WZoYU0K@eI3ZFiQqJ80/gVebLBwTJi0JT7McrY@Z1D59O/cNRWDlE6C3v8fQI5/3sEBacC8cGPy8VwSpQ4MCmfiefEWaKhimYh2CFHF4R/M7oM1MRP0Kwj6OjV1XtI1xk0ZLuRPkTxlNn1Qr@4vaEx@LDWopPlXpXpDI2sc6F5@oWQ662MzWNAnTSzxwvPjTRstG9LEEt67GqjjixDdInTm0R85kIPKk9S7jHc@kRgr32c2To7HRDBa5su73LTg0nJ6Cq9DkYuUCK0g43zk7l2rJfX0/Uf9PuU8URn6lgAdhSg1ygMJh0oWIOm1MVhZ7DFjEAoRnUqtIkIKUjH5c8jWz8ShthcfYlQYJr21whN1@dSuQVeLZESRQ6sTNDQqjMvnCmQvKyJeobm6Cwz7Rh8zEkpCCyWkLtmoNW5TRg4K1qmhiT78m8SrNgRg0qI0ntI8VgHOsHXNJPCPmiLumWKXUhIXjO3u7WbTg9o4rd9T6PdmIjzEIxa87A62LwYAZ5wrL/yjZhyL/MeE3rz7o4o3JFTLHjvhaJ5QF1bRLzsH0tQcsV8@motowVUvTGR8KZe9uVLESWFgq8D7YNDMWng@rkvZljEVab6Q6Gsu1BPGGM5kIsLa4GvF/J2E8E2MkbHhXR99km0RfGChk7uHmaLp3mZGgMIYCOGkeqWuyDWuQ2zn3EWCG0pyRvFrLjGynYm@MridCopJcLUXEytE9nGVUKYPPuq4CqoYpYqo@4smmmC6WNOVD7RMtslWV@4uy@VA8r@nU5YOPDzW2DnRzP9H4JiWsLFWv4kkf9lyhD708wnhegs7q54ro4e4gXZ05h4BDf6s3PW6Kn87Gem5m/xfUGkVLBDEmq8ab3Q1VSgT32NhCftpnxlcn7Rc1bqrOoefRRrcbzYlOR6/qpU2Gn1Dpv7ClYcka5snM2/k6i21L2Nx5XNcdcXFVTrItNtGVxMToOtpvTwKYVsd19dRkbeI1PaE0ELw4qTtqW3Xu2xwzizYB/h9N5q5@n0MqJkBTzgCmAC70BKEdWV633oZN4znPmbPb68mDmRdlv2RKSdUFUUw0Lqs8XbLFsl4N9eIg8lV7FRwDDmIyjV/apQOTO6ryKzFlrTfDPm8lX1eY7QpYHNyuX6YhynEEwR4Cso1LAeTabDaRzxZQMwHNDKGdje6A7/pPYQvdMV/YWT1IVjO2K7jt5BRCjkE8l4jmvrs3vUomUM6M2b3XBKPaIJ97D4Fyfr/wBtpUHakE2@tASxeLzERIJTrg7NBu2PzFqB1zixV6dssCJvFWY6YgOEUBK50RbszjvFmN/OGzhBQl5Hxr@xXE6n1yRAWrQ5F2znHRzeCVLdgZJ6JKzFXZhfxC3ykujZTCenW3ml3PBOPl4xiyf2n31keWQj0tOlOZ9rVP88krghDw4PR7omh18/kyitsu5AaUzLjeJxGrcx5sGJJnUCFy6EJ5Gd5r6c879PF0Ld3yCcajlQbbBayjFYsUPaKs@Gm7jglr5i5BTD4OLSQQuS7mc6DEjfyJRHBHQsE@XClsMZGNO314rl7yn8qjbgAqSKF/ML6co2BqtC5@UnfqUXdUE19JgO7QCPWmV2xgXx6BcKYG/tXubWZHwgzwKrw@bbgqZZfDJBroh0wMJDyLsPqgafNzjnExMpsXU2tflkygQ53FckA3nA5lm4uQ/zGBwohb0XR4KY@8upuHd1pQNoH67aiGQx3KCd5iea3apMp/biAWwQYzeLN5JGGyHfqEQj0TfhN7Wc6pt2Et1oXSWvwx5ebsMh4m9kiOlI9sxDVn8FYBvZamVg/0Lzo2pZO/xeEyUUO8m1N3U7hW8MKcdP8rING3d0TW7lBBodfK3z2ubWCJ26MVAch/gRCK3RBDkDa2TeCiget92JOrmdU7sRDkq0@q9U@vLKV2uZGWjHDi@bsMCSgyF2QEeGW83@MTD1ucZjGQ5JDY@fr04IVDJvAtFvJajSXjVpk5XG6LuEzDL5PKe1GRADR8slBWzr7UmuUZfO4opGjhPPrYZmaqyiAAVq@ZTYa@CWAZyWUgFKzWZj1@/YZWWxB5@6BmgCqoDsdi2OMPay09/7O9q/vYQFrWhhcQapBvjdPawlwaS2EHRBoYOanjidQB6flzbeMknpbI0Bp2IrXGgdccILemQaVBc9gqHpJjPTB1AFVAL2WjkOmKfkBqr2nGbZcvdDMNWVbbSboE4fxXXDjs4u0rM26WEtDv55cR9mr0HDpZxENl6d5GMxHf8Xq@TjZ3F2QqqL4Sm3x2KJY/z54c1QJDLijonTs10wWnlo77KEdk3bmXmuK19@IAPKdHTAea3ilavvrQ75Wa8lwXsBonKgSKX3YdyWgrU2XfRfR1KMGCTdBo9A2BHQJBDyS29EQd/HOrFxPTqIKH303pV5cOxlEp1L5wbg@YzKyzwD6PsvGVPTJzRr76EiqllOlxY0ZWMObGqXrL1owqxoxJutSWQgovr@ZwdduayHhwvMw0EjixPYtF1n6mLKWZZ3S4FGToOTOuNNGZ/DtU22SMnSaMba706LdqO7Hv1KVjiU8hP2kgq@zp9KCpGtdKFXSgFPK@xYM9vYvnRY/CWbOskaaUezSgBQTz/PPPRDCopUwNrbeQ5qVj0WT2@PKgf0/F56caUXM2688C1@BED/jhiPB3yolQqaBZTeVhntN5oIsTNqSAmkc9x6YureB3aPER6Mlej31moWEPqZlY23dKkAaFD4gXIi3amCwWKnKBi1K1ORj8Hb11/LYFyYpA74MXneTACiiHN8@ad/YOT2EzfuDpiwjLBZKb7XD5QmFUeH7Wz2MC6EpVIaEj@KA0BM1dOZzUpSowusuKYVYToVcen4@bF9nqgtoPnwRxRg2jvUgI8gnG1OMnXZGfHkhHgILsNV0Vo9kKe2r8OENCUV8QmYY4L2la@CPZ1sQItVqBMofu5XT7d4VxM2AYpl9yvVjucOGFUuSBuEb7jT5HuRaP87F3OaL0kjv5Y29RyFQs8d28O0gqXI6F79gGao5r3hZ8wZG13jP/A@NvCR5MzxGAZSnbe5HVoE5PzHZc2hRNN@f6jmrcjs6HPJkr5b23Wn3OEQpOOg8DIJ51u4BEEyhX8fDUN2oTibMt1P3yg7SGOmMrEEtGXWEllEBxPH861PrJ1Q7KVZLbu/FuTImcV63Fd94WMe3vk3kELCTx9XNwWjdq3eePaE7TThWrqdLoIlXkJJQvx0YyXzK@NLND699a@tPdtwzWLM3tOXz/XWGHdUbdCYG2qawljpB30cft5Efu4@ucb0u@vXGINV2q5vRgcVwOknW2slk9CHsxHEIehW8X6qGz25m2lZc/etmzeQ4DNBq765A31VrwHOcPV1KN3zk/z2oLxPpitKHvJhhKQzJ5HExdExq1tqf6TrNqJIUfLEWbZpwGslDOBiLVrB1qTxRR4g2/gQ33EPngC5dNi/Un@srL4GSyAq6YCJeVz2rbzTaFqEIv2E6R23LQL4aCSufalsoHaX/f9uOkPrEGcHcNoFfNr1dy2jj81/8gUHArFxfW4AmvQAU97m6khj3p6s1OvD4MVUdRZZX3jwKmylLg9Dm7UpNYLixAn9Cd/aukTOi54c3FDD515yrjlkxXCG1jx1pfNflb9A20s95Ua9KgVn@upsCRJPbZwpYvx11rajw3t54sJlZaynM6@9qfv819/RqqP6jGQt2Gt2554g23tg72U64uoZDsn/3OOgKWGOP6akkeKWzygb4cFQnBvxCbbe9GOHH9j9JiPk9Ikxepjuj32@e4DE9opNBR/9zfWmxL/0PZDbw0zx6@3e4U@kTuiaoWAaQq1sQc6lOKJCAHpGDVvfVFiFmJs07zlI5i6zEMR1ePuyYpHZadcWd87uXhvjxLlak@f02WM3KGdfuvTzW5qfbBkeM/UChaZfB963Xf23rna5Haxh/wIm/7ueV/mvj3wFI8lL/9YjcgYOl6LDzux3DU1T@JzTe6n1o6Xbgmiepamm58LdbYK3eydomrZZ6CpoOA8@yQWTTZHZ1FqLmU9ZOwkNh4x@lYo71md4ODy4xLX6yLOrg7ShZCN7vEA420TeO6oKY4kKsQfqnZ6udH1t@Orq5RunyYSBp3hyu6TytoRcHas1l5@e0nGOHoNP7qdKvK4Xort2IcPzPKd6a97OD0m5SvEUupK/CWEKJ7F5bnmKYLdpYb4HRbi18hsrpG@anMN/MZoBDuvI9M/exzhrCGMZPG@Ozt53Kho@w8br5UpDibNpvPtB4VxCAtx6YcJAgdv9esvbx5yWxN/TddUY/ho9YGnH3zgT@zHRwsw5L2e7SyokpAdcXK@9xxv2S1tRMznoSmZD0mxABI2w@Nd@mITOv5l67xlSAvgUFSiQXbr3HbxYaUVX1MfGeLb5qkz4XbXrkEwmL0wq44QigNKn9CnAmFSUc8j//KWQBV5rhCQrarGsUcf3VMp4PFmeWohDWh/E644NB2aQfwVyaJukk2dxMMjncvNc6oh4Z@nC8i2oAN/cdyUt1hDVv6CtnXezGETGMg@E0bb5AFlYay9nq4Y/rMfoazT5ifBgLf6rNkiYhtnZf9j8hSktlukHHCLkWipjW/H82PT@TguvUYQoEojEyOSMtssLdZVdFz3uNz4P6N/EKbHnr@WZs86rKFQfc3yNxbF7aj6r06SlJ5kZZht9zKoHH6tlUQ6syySdb59hM7TesjRqW4Edp/arg@b6Q3jUcAOsIFIA2Xb99CaQj7iNhWCEDfHNpxsajI9EfcYkvlSs0h5Ga@gxiGi2UMZ2irH03Xfr@2Ya1LkiIQdZKuUstFEi@V1PRIDZh9m7mFui8mCeBBxNdfMe3isqGo9kQgN42QbkGbze8AoMTmIKBYzyak3pwtWuAXUHssj5@mCoeDRR41d7sLNQ/HSa1i0mOVIItNHreuCUQObcSohkmYpor@vezIaSozsnGqpELpMj5j2psPtrtmVdqtGbWmhhIbv5ZtnVtjSh0hReZJ2nfwDCfz756k83F@h8W1OwHT9SmTBSFJcnjgCqvD3TxWTOGafxWTet4V9iiKSQ0soaIgjq4yTGmEAgnvK4O7HErs2G9xPqOAbxM9mZVrNVSfQEtfnvPTIaG0afKTBOGo9VF@XlSNqbVsfTCLSDR5R5em8e9c2p2CFprN1meF2zCPI42LzGWecc7ctcAjX6u@3thwWO@RZtGw2yb8JOkw26M8nmHjb0aSZ1HT71BQjqO5hDVCCxQKjTPKNm7D37YX31y13YMn9bpn9nXlRxzWoidT81WIDCxyagN1mNdWAQAqnnnhuX1zASc36Q9LttRl87hIT5HV40DJcH3Ctneb3jNFaXavnxtriQbNk5EfGFLrMa103tiiOLWkzGRtP4M5jL/H9liVX3TOcCPpZNWBlPYHRBeto7wiYZnyFdXJrCTM3HU9OxbIg3V8wQ@JgrC8xF4hwXr3vtvBddoE2PqWdUdNzmf/i8RFydrvzGyPZpvbsMqYNSWpLrrgT27Px0LlK@BFH38WexVBN0cHhZC4V33@iMaiz0efBNw5IkUDTdns4lHY4iXVJ3spv24t1Kvh5bIUwDrw11VO6aGo3qnXqOEjP9yIZ8jlUDHmohre0wmzckmG73CA28CdmS6ahSxQbeUznX/DLnp0@s8u46rm8PWzY0Eaay9WhJGX4vCMIUQ4zWyu/0jvhKgEvbpSEzO@Wyd5idEs9uy@kGTermZswqCvP8oSh2K3qeqvzuhmA3sKQEECJkJBBvrrcgE/VbLXTlX3UJPCoQJ/NCREOk4S5wwwAyOO2FFw1uY87ntbwQj2Vt1T6ccu9Il9tboVdnXuyhB4QoXbZHc1DSKBxO3FqLtwYKqUR3twCbyUXboV46m1VDbvpzyNCBRj4CFl/WUmCrlsLeRs8/NsIhPNNlM1r0PkQsFxDpG7hWAjm@OwfVB4hLMQjS/KAO94I6QP2a59WORgtsxlPDslPLpqZ1BDZZX0LW@w3qLb7uOO3z2jWPsdCwUgnPz5R@DX2IX2BZ0KVALKuoBV7tnppgwKKJoR58FvKt5iB0NRbtBYWzIJE/2lmSm/3oXKYM1l@Rmnl0c9aFopIQ0vUPvPBmowcxnqu/UqVXhWqriSRdmIqnJdlC@UdOzdI/oaIOZ5wd@s8XaOPqu9KA6cou9TAH9nK8Z@86A8/72gfx0oNEi4LSRgz@H8Exu0BE/fhcd2j0hrTGAp9WbW1uX6llZ6UDbSZ8utZxWhz68fnByoXM7A1R0QdgV4Yq8JIH00WvcTpDcvn1d2Yp6S6rlxcNZzqLPdbXziQgE85fhAU3mOwlkZTy3BupEB7oy6TGolgZXgxNoBHobdWQ2p9egxVVo5@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@MdYHYOi8VsKqYmQzApem1ymzzA9npjYyK0Io7q/HoAqmdhavZGgSF8ZLA0Sq53GPWX@aJm0ON5@kTnW4ZSb@cQjF4xdSSsWTZA4pW7I28SNnAR5ryhhvWvMMrtuaZ8o1tclHD4j0Qh/gqqmA0NW25HQZ5asYdXF/7D84@umGFC21N6aMlsbW5mOvzlM0Ax3/ppcE2wLOodq3jzYEOacccd3OkE8yo7n8VnQg49xSK11fNqAtoUbtaOseI5l@b0Gm@7Chor0uywW9Yw1CwH7vVXXSX4FZ5@WroI8xgJI3JXMQDUGdcaauRsUcJgqXTQWgKneRRoPkH0Fn6yHYSGrRJPOiOOciHYITZIOJXwkPeoprbZ2b8rpBGhk73A811nb5iYEIcZauFM16Cr1Ju79DwPK8rGnsVAF3ejMW/FJDG7xkGAuCrL/zf2lDM3Wgs@J4iuQ3ZASZzO6lwNiAiETzKL6VmAytGk6jP9nPBUm/dlmrm16cdhw2jtduQIwbL/dcodg44jtpS5AR5efa@smv4HFcGT0zWQdu9OMf0fVz9AxcKnyk@dBi65FaNqaw76IkhhgjxUbF3vFrCRT0hQ1GDIo7w7/nEuGN3ccH8Po5DGeSRcY9KZpyNYS/6Xgs4uFPK0NAwc2zBOPrDrGKOn9VZ5J9UqqSgEx4NxVd8eXL6tlbd6uThq3jrIbVnR@BpgMHQE038Y6QE33nIIlbYjTYheKebTpUlpb1B9Q1aK6qJq/fo8TObXiIWM1KEsdJ8I49G8xuZyKTt3m9JAPRqNMmdlN0cfFap9v5slADEoMurOIvbmxdp6j8WLN3hFLCVraWqzxGxvagllbihoi/IjS1@O32WGTUvQUQlZXvu5HRbUsdcltVym5dee8UVpfi//ByDDTZzd6H1WUAlmjX7xuc17KV7hMZp18C1aui7J@gqOwG@qJYGXMt5sVBQ36o0qxTkiR0vgfI4koj3qV/kUE2jr1eAEMe9XQQX9v/doKKRM@7Z2DSt9KEMpAjguIUsmZtKzy7qoxt/WWAw6D8/@cHUmu4cMQ76VTQ6rP5gCNQyMnEbbMVCT2g9P98yXhKnr9Ugt@p@8q0a9Y2WNT6kGkrmcWgNHIS2vZ70gYv8aEz/8UmUst0xST9ituSSgFQgxx3t6Q@y3@J6LidezROi7jwNhYxtLBQ7/@dVvsdPNuKThRExnE@gacWz5D3qZmxi5dUQ57ORu5Lw9XrGqfXlDoLZ53AN0PJe931GBQx/n6VE@szZNpRbUsmxrzmt0xLUU4JZ1Yl7QLeOFSuZ8A9moDWnETvbdL6k@VQ4zkyNpswjHVr2mQrdlO4W6UZEyMmb@pPOVc2gE8@M1AX1yDK/27WfS6rWR54awoqMKIVkL63VMD9PLG5LpFUKNB5rH9cSmp/Bo0ilCMMHEX2k8wIhDGVMH93E149T/Sl04OsRzMJMKXkAb184TF7hu5VHwusviid8qm29scZ/yoxhwummknST3bGlp8lGdk@NIuYqQRg40o2Q@3yvw9S/8F4Yf2Yu/wJYod@3RYQ3CLB44WFINveFkhNvMmUiiI89KaPlvuxIch9E@BM0GrocMO4bAzZkRWjdocWia@5Vj@CLFxCtYtd1yerci1d6Qeg@7W0DhtBqWoH/hc1z3O5lSfl3VlXgXxqh6lpipOrm6aRSIQmZNPzUFAFduNbobhbjG/Ojg7qrXDwI06rQ@X6MBuhbAtNLLSD9j6gXlFqU6tWdwzeIWETXeUml4bStFUPwXvkfOpUsJ2Rtil4PfEicE58k@2nUUbCvXe4n5vk6IuZ/5LalkPn7VMG6sIGBbOu57qb9WKMhkSl4sf@2ZIBGt7SBOE3JuH@@ChCstgGSOpVJNtuFgHaRreycA3RsIV@9BXm3S5kgEp@mEkR4CZA3OONmoyOmfKonHm7TiQrpB86vTQVTSzfFMVGKL54rllvnL1aaBRZLHJHFRPMHXKfEneWetoO87kmDzcA8EajTh/yLvxX84jaUV9oIbUTbeXTB0amijo25klpxyTTd27j3VarCu7dIfX0mYokZdJwJRfdr67ex6OZ0MpRbudakGfNIK23eGEA5nc/4@VP4Mknu0NPyyT794hNetcMecWc@bp78Ko0QUYkck8ueYRuLc63onTO2/CkA0g91vXFqTpXSvWS8lyJsq/8i/2m4RtpNN9hD4D8hHI7gW3G9a2kGpQ227xh8cwabcQYMVavBJ2KOo/LBkfem/Qc34z8YuaAUroAF3RCz80o03jP1uUlkhzLVt7qKDBcFhcYo0qHFeYi6gX1uHOd/BN97GO9@pID7izSX0TLPaVzN8u22e3coue2I3o/YLQBX@PKxty7VSdFMxomIO2GoTksxS4q7FfUMrWvIEp2l7apW8hLjPFoLh5IG5ELim82RTBIxNLF4ynhusbyfJM8byu0vI7cbYOttMoTAkYVRTHeqENzDyF2hUXdPsN4temVhusx7nrgwsLwI46swCj4abuA8FQ@RleLyqPMLbmAkrCzzuX987@ALRqH@lM9W79cH9oDfGvQsxTBT/SqvMGn5w4KaRLLqr1rHlt24VyWaNC4QGcrmpPp/@Cue0PPXmFm@/XiHbde8hYEOMHDFNGKI3ywNY3T4mcYbG1Gn9ZHZQqwI5qYX5eK6DV8ktLv9E@@Z2Hjd7chOMQkGU0cvVc2@xyntr/TDR/ScFGfbIiPyNsJ8jtuGdjWTGxc6362R@1Kbxo@xvFG6KgUtBl/7Kre7pJA4k1IwwfvINNQJiiIH2YZ1uLVTox9VWMKQO4K93Zcq3ijVzdAwlXIPUHX031StjdHjehEfPDnVl2MF295cBalSIiw6jG3XQS9gK2gT6jNgcCbUFgtiq4gKT0/LufY7HU5vEQcnSDPPnhKSfIgDNfdzj0GTTxTEgxNmNd5J9DTp1lLI94b6ZlnvipiVRD3rNVhFcUUc5pv8ojtd7bcUFym2iFaIrx9qO3926yBHZoZhjamNsm1vt2IjXDocm0KZKbCGxF6xWBJIT3nNxtx1M7sF7Vlt/mOF4hI/chCBjPuQbuk6@88U67PeWt1tjpCcen3R56y@xoQhVo4hn5W4m7Ch2@EOjngQcbjmuJyQQInwpt5rZd@vEijfUmTrtuqR7Zywpvt73gWoVuQnO8p0MbUPB1StFlARnnSVStr6VoTGm2I9z/tZW0@p62O@sMjEBdx7KtPmFrzuk5j2X5Va90AZ1x507kzCEpWN3Tx5@wSZkW9zyrGA21ntWQuHpUftOr98NIVAVUxafOy0x/vJKV2OlzbeKoEYvwUpR0QOv0pC3c0v1vnz3gagfTRTOg3I7eILUSXGgnGj8rbo0eG@mcW91LsmNZ0MoPnBxNOroRJV9un4Xft7Byg2RpHn20mhjaaP39fAX1Nhqd3oP5s6sY5DOrFi0@98H9QHH@jLM2Bhg0SZyt5psR4YoDqk/Buj4AEMMoyV50ZRMYsooK0Q5EAqLg72zMpaP3fAtcXLk9boRwspNlgI@w5SynJZbr@UGmuGPWg@9Zkxcl/M7z1ooGmOCrzeP/WpFnlT69bzf2r21Aagjkvs27YJhvCRBCQbF0fDb8D2rW/5Hg5/zMd4OG7a2JMR96y9JAxJhOyag8Of5hsb8Yrz8ldOAah5vkjTCW12U8MqtY3j4S3EzfhlzXnwcx/kbz9I8Cc1Bd9mH2GO3lqNoXGRDrSu51Q8mYjo7wY3cL0aRjpxzKVxuxd8aEH6MuUEyBVPFOJy1lXdCEbcp6qkGvMlzPX9x8G/q6GgCqBhX/SvnYD9ZVFY9RvX@Gc5mGqJpL@I9F2oIaQNTi3uoaCKeQt42infq81zl/Fx@tdLnxWbgNgEBdf5T/q0bAVyhL9nj8D39@DwZuKaeAYcSGLKZCAnLPnksZHa1bkfZNjrrldeUOzNqeFD//yozcTtVKF4qGNqEr6eb123NIr/xz/qrrYROVNMRQMAPxXkG74xRdtkQN/Eurqjxi@5bf0HvkBNqRMAGJgAB2q8tihwITz1mWLcnSBWEoqDX5kwidgjRQ@UxR00@sHEOqOt9Pls7hY7ZrBfblGJDIe0ZNgoivs9JEcFIDdk02b7hFpJEGU20otobPXoemNLqG473H@zByjq1ByHRq@9N/GmzNI3kjCjKhaTC9MvZ30ifRBxVteOT/G@ix2bPt9Q/QGmEZ1Ecqb@7W@vvDszaJGz9MnXOIf1uJiwIsq26i0/oIuuNJ8YCLHlcj3LTCTGYFlQLNpje6t8gI8j1x/0mwdKSPMZFw69McdYoaOH0D2CiPhzBdHLzL1PuA3Hir5OsaLRKQrqFAErrE2tiMaRYakLM8/QuRlIjJEQdH0yrkk3MHk60bVAYX55VwZyJzRQN3W/tNIBPb9HQMmky7h45qYjp6BzcL8LxkQP1IT@ls5LPGAeQbqWCs0n36Mv0wr11SMqtcsg2lXyYwTiThNO/q5eWkOo8NTBBAVytw9PnPqAvy9qZGo7iTSfa6/KryfiMjjkAaC65eoariL6Zq/mN38yoeqOa/WVlV@JKU@j4wKhO0YOQkJjtt6TYYzimbL@axphuzq1ioywDRIUxUoEe2XH9FoTYc4Wge3G@qQ0hIsiEEi6nO8K4MkYYdUI8@zAlufHJAegsDmq65Cc/VMH0LeWEMB6y6nPhdC75nu/pqFMAJ9ZjEJYxtGMO7EMedw6SNpUWy9ghF6C9tQkqnJo@b4EKiXmv1dMundFBn4dl5vdvOOOvun@9l3qtZKHOi5Kejc5U8i8aPVdOh2q4R7eOjulW4G6kxq8sYZEknLPvWpN0zK1hwCN0k1WCCQjRHPQ9tddKuv47B0QSMheGGu635njoxYr9UHVV7yQfvLxbk0pDiwf6wOjoUjUNBqCQLsposT4hW1XiX0PKIr8biwkGwFrutLXucS/pmv2nKjXj4EdTDDKsyuSuSKxt58D4VJnT5pwBTVmznJbPE0AYVIFcncKKUHteIgbwvbsphjlBjn0rfVBqA0diq@c5L6VGhK6zA2vrByXka5x@1vMtTA5S76BNfxTpVqyWjKGqRAd0bqGycjvJlSWDQo7FjXsDWMr7ufffaUht3WCtjU1PritQBUe/3qKFVsiMF/6w1jPOUWSvUxMeSa7EZtODKFUYHKC7/lO9IwHY4781m9jDH0NBGwoHANrN13ErljfCADSHO5VX3EGUHszjj@dN/uUrWhriHFbneihG4rWhYGNxR46NoLd4c9tw42yHKGHaQ3JveZyxnnTbMX5Ir5LvGiSEW6lqgWnsV7dS8csjzCm38@GMNbPlCJzutPX6y6aw0I/87SYNA@93dncVOpMgY3gVW/mov3Sq2Ic0yT1CbcBZmz5Gtenn6CDtaIqyDIK5JfmBhAp0eRbH6tc7V8Zi33Vn8cKlgbr8TBJ57hRKMbL84Pr92tlhfvh2T2QQkkm5aH5UXIPbm15Rzh@iLh6zutKBqezVeYkHBA9Cg2pkeK85nvuZBt38Ig/WOzp/Gz033NrrA01VKMkCz6hcu7npqZkRBJh6G@/MK6hOcto9g9Sqxg1i0tQ0lKkYynuK1EaE@@JFKwYyiKnRtDT2VLl@B7wxEx2l7F1rmQt0cD0X8Kzh/@/qbJNct3Ugupy3LlrSWIplySVKdjxV2fsjgG4AnH@ZzM2NPygSBLpPd4LgVrHJ@2FqwmadgaNjXiUzBQmh7baBh2o5nbbESRlUnbLoWzFmcZ8/h8jNrNWhBY7fkDLwA/vsqoyToFXKhtLeKVoRAH9Y7uW1vhx4mzrq2Lm8l0SlBCQZ2@n@f6UlME/ETYV2Yd8/0u5cIDKUc47daokbnv9qp0LmmuAZoN/Av7ReU6937dXGHbqrQk9QAULTR9XivbpqO4rsrOXB7zw@TFhhU3RX7KomPciSjZo/aKZK7Yy1/Flke8YCCXhQ7Ux0NYCFuD7JwFVheLUzENv@9aifYpFQMh5SPz7w0VN5jIa@lqq/s2/LByvJN8c3La6apCq4HVqZCgoS5j49qgYh45PPcDJcsAL43IoRrCwZiLUvZ/ujwavJlZ47GHDuubUZJV63MDHTRfegluu4er4mZilibmBbzJhgECgOqesnC7CV3DHbqXHAPJ3rOyQVUai0gKj6lWgwP73BmKt/VMUIu/7hCxK1NSd44huJqxdGZ8ZjW30rlL6QcTg8XouWHUAyOn6oVa77JSXtMSa2EmBKhdOoRaKGthhLtyVw4xLAoM3dxDrmJIzrqYPLe7A92dEh86HHJSZK4xbUpqQefEWV3NbZGltCdZ5HQiplV84BjHtMfaXFQUwV2UW5yYAxmef60N29TLVr@pkiR1WJFi1ERDVbgYpp2MzIqjI@8VnnbpU9Y6dqi4RWz7xw5/IOvpvj6C1mIM0cvGszMa59Ee2FHcgX7fkBKTuyZMEjjr@wl1jI7@GdlDIIssO2L@zw/FV6UThg2APyYjWslOoo0WOq3fier/4bjNaizZDx3TseRhe2HLsa2plmvpkVCb4GTaF2xIU10/Y3ySuYAJwmV5Q7JDm7ErL9wMYcKrTKMO3Q/Si9yZb8JI9mgfy5SOFnxBrKUSuTSQcLIHzv3/aNf6YbhXujx8IpWbGm1qoL6cSMdEP@7DP/RtucRKTKNjjuGxt0N3bLwpdb1hC30E4xhuvvUX7LY6ZqGK5vP778dNWKZ5168hKN5juyNB/Lujs5SZKeH/VODoljcmpqHbHVo9nq6e/kyq6dLbJmx@TQKwxr14NKJwllLd/QJSqYPC5M83dsJ@s@2geqD4uTfVGlsQL4a2lAVYhG96bpksW@zMtHFhyGVe8/sKdfpDvhgC6Yl8guzPxmBhisuCid7ib1C3RNcPCtmLql0w3hi2fTT15JcZTcqZTQc@rl0Vro1HMiYElbVMsbE4Wx3IvA4cPqwfp8v2RQMe@UAl@/t@lBZfqg@nkOaaXtY1B@5lX01/aK6/RNpCFfg/2fc3tjD7BXJcuUsbVTPs9tlsJpnw07a@YEBYI86VCH8SZvxOaHwYIZkRUyI5GsPQKfKTgCPvqQD0/utGbdgtv06PlRKGcGTzm6zCpmC04OZ/RDJNHiPLw/9VzA/BLNiIPW5aLn9@lQysZoufPr5hRae0ikSvOep1zMwDmQp9yv3@3fLhLfaVWpi39suL0cq83QmGrUdi3j3rRdph1/30xtsrquqJs3ehB@GVNQiKVpz9PwAHkHwB9ctktbL8dooEKJpm6F0e796eSg8nuM5bT6xioNeHImiwK7ggNuOAerDgmb99JEFZqYVc/f1@7zVZ0Fei7XPSm0YrqKxNPpk@kD4fiSy5WM5Wq@QQ3fLFrWdfcrPZblH6sEpfBiW3hQRA8qVsrzk1pg5aOQedbi1QBeof1Q@sGnPS3Sr9ffWQ3ltzD8M@qa2YE2pqt2HRwlSRMQCy9Jisr2Kt1YfK@THuwzM30D3e3CpaSrVu0l2VaAkqIiudDmh8xQWgvmuXvnxdBW/ymXL5Ci5UODfhMtewOo8EbvUAlPmujciraiER9TwzOJGpodTO9VoKJvi0KbUx2AQbU6o@UNC2NyNMvGqbHRyxSPPu6D@hdGFMSYBjc9ctxGBFdC1OCTnadNMmF9/MIejfVe7J7lQ6@ud8TjMWaCNobi9FLsmpRhGz6Mm6Wus9HSZuLqY3hJx4iDcKDdR3loZupS4CCo/Xk5gnclj7a1n6I6/iVgqq2C6R5nJP0axpHE46GenQN3/HZlwKU1RwxAMznM@MLxrAX39ZXEGtqgw5Jqp8wwA47HQNTez95p7NALKjYoNHd5B5iySmQKkIRLfZO8vfpMMEQ1bMxGs5SMio@fEcq4dRjCXkMf5is9FPX6kwQC@xEbzjF0IF/OrHoqqV1bxb1q3UIa5N5c7lDpv5fOJ2G54@CCqbwalwI/a2pHddKf2hbpylep@8plX@ixS454xfe@Td0g8u2Nhz1JrdD51C1WFxGbYaKRPL@vLmCFFy8RslyJKoGrz54kj5PEgDupMzkt7TSm8Xn9BniKpLAMamXPqizQBvqirx2BvmYBdygKpaRHjeaG3968PnWevncijpDKfkhSX0l2G2YKypboYLsQiyrp4Azpp6g2LhQAWnd6DF72rr/9fp6v6xX5ev9cBnNU7duIILNWHnv7pZWw@tmjtgC@xxi9P@XL@3XUicy43YUOCcFyLes7UTrHsOFzBMhE0CksSyjv/jhzsRGR0FvhQpcy3j7xZ/sf@5Tmbcx2q8NaJdNuRofNeWZ141hx8Cwrgd/O@7YP0@z4zGcIAdY8ydYKxUI@6nQHbl/6/pOwdLZQ0HPnqRbjzuyKxNszSjAiJBTtY3mhN9um9WvygWMHU7MnKcx9scWQNEyef9suMnzSLvii4BggdvOnrsagmCe8LWu2FURGaGlrVmfhI//I2BVPoWyzsXP5dliOhP6AyusQlbkrYhX9YIeWt3pq8hlws9J60wk8xlhIUO4l7o6zDFj2F@h5gAofHbqksjNfeVpRKzKGkBmXty3H27RHKMPJv9d9r2t7Bkt/zAZ86tFeDH2TgWFwAnPe@DZjqfh5Jlceo@v4kIaC4JCAaPWGZkxY5npxVYp5r/HFd2xE6dQjaciqbfho5RW1p6g3U0JcI/2wW7uYe5NC53joywaY43rJZ4u@@tH@IMLuBY67pehZ6osloXQZLZUuWps1UhCy@awER@c66zCTn5hkRTHWsS@3HRazFGclYu@8gJtSWsU63cMvh1iFBTVEe@tEDcQkffh61NSwuH1AsqkzjDgoQN4HI1TPoCCkaHu6RxrBO6KFU9jw6zgwlfo2QMojvZiOUJHtS2X3ZRQoEZj1ej75HlfxmrWfTrYpZAPuJd@MYw9weHueMVK27FiAFtzWiZjq87ls3DaW0KQJqfB4uZXLhla9KIw4mkRbwtboY1c1atezZ3v/aT5XH2fzlHLSHFTkmQ7XzujFc87Q6jERjDSHDlwTgL4u3ZSJ@V/78Gjn@TODvDYXfdqrtcedK3Et/7rGX1x3WpH@oS/ZVF/rVNRRUio/C1JBEjpKTdGtlrTrBQhfTxZCtW2WE3bm@pQ/Shd2Bs8Wz3ByD32O2SAWP@ddZayY0QioHQlXrp2c2js7AwfEVks7EOTx1FtMbRccr5TF8OY71lvysQfn9LALagq3xcE84io/BgS7DrMdePvRbV9fm4hMBLJ7@JSdu@113traQOlW8gG6yMJjxRHAe1rH2h/lLzU4e3qWLfsQotS2XtYutpaTua86OmTTfH9M1f5rCy2sjpB4iLE1@@6Bk5metzUgSVekwMBttNYO2VQ7uCebuCnPSNIBtV3DivgFwuS6tIuiWAvOadlSs9y8a25xrBldoJvNdmcf1EG2TIoyq@mBJNOjo3LnBKDwr1kQdzttP4jGDhWBTwcynepHY@Y5wr4Sx7d@ROlvZ4oYD@gAUE2wUDz/Zr7U//33fw)

**Input -** Anagrammed word followed by the dictionary of words as a set:

```python
anagram_word
{'entry1', 'entry2', ...., 'entryN'}
```

**Edit:** Updated Inputs.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>248</s> 202 bytes

```python
from itertools import*
A=set()
def f(s,*G,i=1,A=A):
 if' '>s:A|={' '.join(sorted(G))}
 for _ in s:s[:i]in S and f(s[i:],s[:i],*G);i+=1
I,*S=iter(input,'')
for p in permutations(I):f(''.join(p))
print(A)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZL3NruNakqU511PELCOyAw0UepaNbCBHhRrXsFBoUCIl0UWRDG5SOvTufvZsW9@yTcmjgMy41/2eI5H7x36WLVs27@t9Gv@P//zP6zI9/9Kv3bJO01D@0j/naVn/9fQf/1669a9/O7Xd9S/Xv5a//@t//Xv/7//l7//x7//xt387/aW//stf/uX/Kv/2H//vv/8/8W//@6@pH/9a4he79q//9W9/@/9Of7lOy1/@77/041/Kv5X/8W/9/4x/@@9/acZWH/Y/@n/7n3/nb@Nj//Z/9v/bv/@X03/7@7/@93/XY/y1H@dt/fu//MvfTvqMWZ8xd8tzW5u1n8by1//2t3@7/vVf8jvnv/3tNC/9uP71P/72n//Z3N/3/daf1nt3ak7T9dScp209la5ZLvfTFH@9nN73Pv49/rVf9L9Ld7pM49pc1tN5K/3YlXKaxiH@5XTtl7Ke3tM2tPERy6u/dEW/UuJXhv7yqH@pB9D/dtM8dKcSz9mdumfTD6d71wzrPT5iiY@Yl6ndLms5PeN7Lqdy54Pzb09lL2v3PM1TfPJ@GrfnOZ41Pq@JbyvbrE05PePhmlu82jXW6VSm6/pu4vlffdtN8V56l6W/3eMr5u0cn3M6T9OjnMrlHlsbT75M2@1@ineLv1y6V9@9T3ssTbzw0urblv7VxJfHLjxLrMpzbsb9dIvfmk/bqJ@4dWO3NEP8ci7pr2bcmmXPTyt6m9vSPE@3Jp41PkJveFu6Zo0PiI9tT/dp7YbTpRt5g3WKR16X5qW/m57P@Gs9Wb4sS9B2a6xkrHscgXI6d1f9Cp9S/LLxd5dmi1Uapkujt5zi37WTNz3mNsQnTterNmjkAMXPtF3pb2OsddEj9XqWsVtPTdsu2v53v9770RsZrxTXJLbg3s9zfmbsevxa2c6/Op2abn133ajDuj1P1@bZD/vpHNvWns5DE6fkcu90Vubu0sd3c1biO7pziQWJL2@7n/gMffR7igU4rVPb7LG5WxycWE6@Y45dL6dXt5R4gTh2F71IfGPsSnxwrFaJJdEaLN3Q6J3iR7alX3dtwRj/iO2I721Gvc065drGu01v34g4t7ECcU4f7PvG7nAideKXLnZpWvX08UbdqZ3e4zA1LSulC9ZcLlo4LdvjNMbz3E/x/UtsJ4scR75r@4aLtsRJfDf6/Huv/d9Pc39Zt0UrHY/E/sTmxbfctjjXcYSbpWVveefLvRnjBsQjx@KVZzPEYYz/Eqt3ibeI/RtPbbw5GxWfql3cWo5V3DfvYDysFuW09jqj2oVyGjodwba/9bzlMl21JLOOdazrKf7r6DWOReufuoNrv8ZPNKONSrnrSeL34h206kMTy1HWPv7yGcdnP/1jawbtR3xSvPIQr84zx4JokXggLYVuYLxY/Kg@/dXH052wy7oVca4uW6zZk2tx8f3gmsaVeE5xA@PhxssQLxx/PQxdPOarGbZ4zGXtL7zQJGOh07XECjdxxibde21emJpYrmbhUGFS9ViLjF0zNm2jX2aX4wniPMet7UfeYYm91T7rN8ql77R3Tftq4p9xEJshnqobb/HK91Nn41i6Qaf6HYd/ehefSZ@zOFOx0d1N52JolniBWyyslmxtzoPO9y2WTocnTm4s5Wm6rJOWYZxeXo9nszziLg/9ebFhit@P8@8bE1@/yB0sWqrn1MaeX8M4cfriYWJx41fu21MXxUvVxif8Y@sX36kploaF9m0v@rawgmEC9Ex7E3b2dJu0KjrwMkfX@KrR7gODt7W7nuJ6rXtS4gm69ixD0dxiSeOoTw99Ql/KFv@1ia0Y4nLq1@OGLzbMQ6dlXONi6nzEDarmkzt4K3I5fAqfGV4svnNsdZN8yeKRh@kd73LmnDc6tHOz8wnDdOuPe1MtOkZU3x6nKl4r/OpLuyFDbjOO7Y8tesq4aPvKhL1rtlssa5z/Sec6Lu@m2@ObP814dN1geQv5ie60xwG8VYMVPriTk2xmrV68UDxt99NoAU63fol7McdNi5cNE6EP0RfF/34sRTmNOIk1fkv27sEuxJaHL1ni8HVe53gEmZXzFjZEyxYndOBybXFert15wcs1w7vZS7qVeLO2n@Kg6ePfi@wRS2SHWeLxXvIKPedf9kPGGXce12nYS184WnrmMF1jE2eJHUtzGFvetXriUnqd/CffE8YkbOuz@RXXNm59vNJ146fLLMN8iR0@NiL2Ks5rrMQzTok@ORxl2A77u/zaWNt0xXcZkdKH92riFeJz4uEdOMQpDzumJQ0HGfdAxkv/kL3QxyomuO1hkYYe4zZP86YP0R7rnv2KRRwJGuyp3t3Ac@jsKJjAnsY@TaucdPxOHD/9eKPlDbvYKzYYJnZjvMSf0sYV2SBdm7iC8c0O74pu5jPiDS31yiHs4myzbmG6mqv@5EvJ74cxlPnqWSaiKy3pglHf5hZnem9ebIwtQjm18ec2DoPMleIjeX9dF73sZVD4ocsYn9guei48/1URny5xvFmsE4ZTlq2VX4oz1vYlfKs8w5M4Cc8c/3x2TVyQNgxQGLow@w3RRdeE1RlluOLjIvDjceOK9FMrFz2yL/HwjeIQhz@6i@@4YPrJRs8hL4oBjuWQrca2xkP3JT5AZu@iW@Vvzj/pQcLoxAHVw3cyKPGq8u9l3eOMRioRx9zLhlGJk98s8cBPbkHBtcTRs/eR29G16Hoeqp0uG/ZHpkuWNY4lDx1Xa9VN6lpWL@I7TvOyYTw5K02rCxnnJ0y/w5Cbj1en6KuZ@TG947Mft5Uovo@Xu/VXPeImty1PwdXHnMrK2uJu@I91unmRibUJVTB91ziRHJ74zzzVbZjO8UByFdMz9lybSmhNIBdXcl/06RG669Bs59jt@N04saOCNOKSiI5id/OQtwpoFbWvYc5iWdrwZxEJNgtxyZtNiYB@@4lQ/ElciZ2Il17Yta5XrKp7LMPjm1LsrLXGt@a3Mp1uWXS/ZHQjStPNrr8b2/KUV3rG60/xXWFV5xU3@@BzIsvQsY8TuemahWmLt5EvjXAvbJdv1ho/PNagJx2vrEp8WHjgxxjhZHx50XbGPe8j1ghDJBMfnjcu@LuX5VSIEgZiLDpnvWLk930iBIsUZMD8L4q7nVpFWHGbJrmLy32Tj/YLRGIUf8AIx77hwiJ@1mfOi/4mjkgYwpa06trfNnKNgW/rRvbBuUOn@z/hp/S/rS4WJxXnMXcK/hddo7gwjjbvsS/xgF24CJ0DOzvdhsxz9vA4cRdj2xechHxBrH1uv5zsFkHDNQLceBmZVl3gX02kaLFF@tYIyEeiXOItBTIYiM7JXQQSVxxq2Z5P@bLwUu945rC6CjIisbtgJXlTLkR8MGukqFVZLG//7hR9jXpMmfCwtTLZmLWw2LL/ce8vDz1bxrYlrwBBoM5aM5wjT7KxUawfue2gI0RsFiuSieSA3Zs2@T7ccngjLG33kznAus8dh59MM/zEqEj3soTHjPM4dtc@vlxelNitUdTTzAqiSzy6crq4czYVRLs6PeHCwkbnJp2a8iDPY1HifPbjdHpNwybfxbfEB@hzItxZb0Q1/fDi9BcH2cNmx@J9WGx8I1mMexyu1HeD99@1D2m1llX3bdlsxAcytEie40d/deE6F2UX@cMjV35RABwHLN5q5ike4a5L2nF9ExhFhAad7m0fuYUD43ElFb70JJVx6ePNzzrCEaivsdIyL4qEHQvpvrat7hOB@OpghfRCbuHlT4lTgQ2Nv9SiTU6R4/Ke@0YLoUgnwsA4CnH24njZusYVWcBUHCUpb4stbWaSsevExSgO@nS145G0or6UN7zVJey/1vgaidc9DOqk1CGsnt6cg8VThSXgsZzXcGriOsgh9guYg8AFIQP6hYgeIrVlJ8kOsX3jGAZrcLgPMBDr3CoM07XSB/GsbaegwOmugaV1jcXJ@K@wVfqVGUPKhzmxi8O/xCUJ29kMz/BzznsVBsT79Xr/OIWxkApZMNjK@a/hOEvNY8KiTNNTf4zcuJP1eCruXXou/UVOcEl0SfEnt8KBcARsM4lzXDyduReL51CJPbp34WU7WdBZziS/UFtePUHn9Ja7NYfLU5Rip@JoW/BDBL7Ki8iPdBacvWtx4@9vE@Fb2G4S6PA1c3xz@MiwPM244g3DDeo@ROQcKxhZFVnztBgHOTkma8Z43yHTXKEPP/1lks1xYCpwpLOPUUYeOzj6nHAjMwNu9lmnr3lNju3nvMukny/FbnsmQMNOyB33ol6rgsmKjY9kro0AV6Fj54R2qUALsZEwnmbBTI6R9jX6WZ2YODdjUTLx6CMYIL5cJmLGJRY6koV31xKtRDTka3LzY8sWA@zFamuLw//gTvQzu8IWLBv4hPDBRmmIolUuUdx9hRCK9ptnGFoDA827IRBUCgnMqQUI86A17McwiIowup94ZGI@vva8tRERkdi1BnJ03o0SPZuf/rnp8xMFCS9/gAJyrM/md6z0HLvBwrwzz4g4mdO@8DxXLKPdRiG2KH5nGRBhrz4DRUnzdRsykI01EFCGNSCCOS8OxWN5plsCxWQWO1m80Z14NYXQJyHOAIazQOVVbxeJj5znqhPRt4Q2Ap26UUdScYsWdu0wfBEdLv6j33slvg2rImMlfFQgRBwvQJAxotG46aOyGQXBSp8FQuLc44NlsFsjDUBWxFovRS0rGDaWVsH/3I8GC6f1LC/dnIutUlg3vUeEsOElAGnjVYf@0Q1K5sLiTXMawvjP5KmlAw9clNADmveKOOLbuBkyUUryDD2/morYxfNuSp4vkWwpJI5FmO8KgokS5dBnb/yNdKw1nBfXgKSJmFgeMTJpB57hweR5ujuQlqIwMnWc7mL0UXtwjh/gHstkx2mZlgy043B6c4mzhdlNAmvb7tooi0i8R8vT6pfCu3P8MO0k12sXj6MAZc2clnwt/KpeKq9AYmvF@GXY40Yuauc/Az71XjWlU@ANikHj9MQ7ExXiKVqd7ltm7AqWIqSNz9pGouFF8bNuJuc9fphoUHuO8dWtXHW0VoVM3RzxzLkHg3w2@9mAoUCBhSgBYFdvF75tF5ogCEgYtJZyx18OVyWMjrLls3b9PSB1PI2MwTk8VrzSo9udl8jGxz0/x9F6VLeh7FlWJA67PjAWnSsFwONQkbV@s2gk1RM2ndRrUbygsylXYzclJ/bU3QgD5DVSjJdQDP6iE9LUjb@mnR994TaujZNBDFHELvpcJVVCB7itBDzEDUpq9J/DlgvGN@rvkNnFiggewnS@wuTE3e3kdeTPrv1PfP0bq31niUlV4245P1YqVx6RbNoYd5ycvgDu49p1Ada9HscS0V/swR7XVZ9xdSyJyYxzYHitFjoWAw8LyY3M/TY6x3qDzOf7kWfrNYmWlK51hpCe80Ye8U50t8GuXCbhKRlXGxXUIZT1AGzoXB6ThYuTRvwTz4IFIKFVuEUIquB8F5BKqYS7ECZa5yQscKGUMOtGKRBIfHvofpyi9F4mQMc464pUlUX2t0ahZ0TmEWbGCjoVL8IoDHxmPr47CyvKj4dZXgFcSLi64l7jtRGvuEKnsxS2BfwunmHaFdLd@@4KtKebvSpky3yn5D1M3LElBY8ssBOYCn7VtHGUp10mf1B2Vd7y7RHpF2I6ooN4NOdpowsMBVPw0pr@CqtLID9FEKqgEljwrCRl5dDLcCi5wHzj0AuO9dXdFKD@Y2uAQ3TIEp4PI@UdwrYJJ5gW4B4ZFn25K2ZkAIYmO8VJd6HOArPG0zToZipgGKf43HhW1/DAvLTlnVKRsGsb4H0hyI6DjR2S5dECLooEb1xHgqu4z2QkFC@vEdDrT9RCZFBjywh@Bd7p1xSzFwCp@Kb33fBbAlwR6BspNuB256UzVel8cJ11lKwQOJJQESny9q3U4xgLoVQwfnbkXGSZo2S1oZCmFSf5qjbMsyCUgWPiQlhk10OibxnYZPqjXH40YtiBinVLhL21GFYIFko88zBQ@XXtqihIWiNP12KyKhcZvK6efQVgO1nFYIww3kl5bYR7igInlhmosq34Rjn97hqilbP@ofpbLPAmJE@lJ9eW4pIAtUSi7GKf71lcBEUsziIjVIgbH9@QYFvFTZcMofU0XS527EgYz2vcY4Dk61XnYwafAfjX9of3L3vmXNp9rKOwhZ@VcEkxTfz@wiWIIz7oMj8719RwPrExv6b7qFQHQEkXJJJKxY1ZhuWa9cCfYY37JwaUd9sUssttr2BITaFW9Ajn0@jxFdDIJU0Y7XA420VJtCGbe//EyXUjKXP3Exvcq5yvdyJ@k6nuBSFFUFkWgWEuFBXQpa4i9yVrT8LSlXKGo4gIuameNqIbQL/4ERtl1YmEDSS5QCFrLJOMzDwJIo0nULHuGuZYFzAMj5FXG3tZ82W7FcJdmfp4SVW246MjZw@bt6iguc0O13wAgZNYsDU@44nxY0sb40VpaKBPRPi3g1D1RAMrRVggtW2mzNMZ3JzZxsj7iwpCAOMypzKV0yZPuXaKhgVdurpb8gTppOI9KnhqvK172OW1KsZGDB0WaFvOMsQO4Z47u7VS5I1IZNVn6LCr1tLGYY68eSl2dlfHa8Yzil73tdvsdIbOqYToRt9luxXiLqtjR3E9dOXgLTwFz4FmZTxLCPZyIa972h03giSeWlCK4hHUKZbAemUtTJWN3dBjH57MhzgvyzQ04VOucdGK3g1oOSwc0PLkOOs2KVEimDAkdcMTKTRUBk@CUnw0EzMAO67Ruerw8XZxxLAHg87QKfJm5UMAwvIrionDUt9kee0lwoMpHImwLja7OZu@QEFM3xVXWbZHXkvGivJvyXgxPAceQ2ev2PFnQC6DIbRAhmUUNBP7fN1V8BA4SNCt/RNksQooFtWlmRULYwm3Ypym4bIDkCmZ1uGYeGRFmaMBxXhSXOi6qggVZ0j4CsW0iMPmLkswcAWSM6KD0QuzvDWRcOuBeYi8pA7BW6VXegEtbCf73g8AW5PTDzl4FZRtwE5KwuK2KDl6ksxG2o3XfnU1jy@83dO13H50JTAsLMmgMuY28wXZsUh07f1Xw7ZtJUcp/ixbyVhcda7tHH8Xry6z2one4IRKH0/wzXGUXS7mU6xp8Ur6H1cx0jLOZrm4Zp2UhtaVoLjYGSPFfxCOED@j3CBMlTgSN4Ugo4JaFTxlBzOf0ukBnyZIHXeZZWfz20LKEbfeUObilKv@PcnNCLhK/tCojBR7pXg7wqIepCyuQJiFuD6Kd/dMZRsVD5YKe@q0UqfXfSariTD/KZBo3FxjWZsfeAg6@jKBjX0XJS3K0lQRlIl1PxtJfmQ8gBkY2emsxFihclzfLhERCuLA1hkSXgmMEgZgL8iXYGKQYIrYEglX32fcQqC@7EDDLScAj3RXgSLLH7r@vdNymcu@PA3CUSto4VxFrDTLLL3wX5nzV45BHNU0YHFkO3lIfVE4EBeUexc84tX5l1iTeT0l7erNLZ@Vd@mItH0m57KvzTrgWtvmMcU/4obGyTA/pbisJfwnYhzlBW9FsYr7VWYUYe7Jx4WF0hWMK33uVPidhHWZioJhlhlxGOBIHyyC5EvxqtZbpkWXabooyrdvLukC7Op0MmZhmvdmhdgRmY9ShqGZlRC@tLS3zhQbmXhwq/iAQTC5gFxj3tPo2NTvRQBzpuDVXR5iZYn7oh2JW3CbVr8415MSu6wQRhSewTlL/Arm@PSrgc42To/QW0c0zgdUctjWapM4pJMKfKojP2IrIiVpwAiozuHEZyCAuIBTWGttjHJy4X471TLSIOLUO7tKpTjMi1DE03nX6nKVWxXlKG/6ZOhjZSSBP3wdMgcutVCnqMwVTFxRi0WVQY8z3muVH7GoelxVVyPMCjsQcZVybJkrFZBuNqeN8i@ddxW5JxuGAzQ3oKOrEG8ct/MN1Kr4wRTQnctPZPJLYNivCL3ne6Y8umsk7HGGmvfOC92IM3nIrk2QKteHTEzGS0Q6VxzxpKps3ASnF94mb5cySdz8qXASBx6lN4IH81RnQowoUigbz6USHkxfeYYb6antXEoWLJJwaGMuu2VqXzHak1b8jHUSLqhsJZ7WHzZOBDDK3lV@bDNubrM6QPZoX6vqaFZ@TLsAPorMIAmnhgkijiprgjstqX1JrlDc@l0goSvrpYKWSqPiuEVOVoaum5VxLE/9Maztb6XwxMHmixEmhF/vTnd75Muy88ZXfWgx82dxJiNwMSzGQGAwPYZG1Zd6Sos2WfcDHDS2fA8PIzi0g1oLJpCcwEunAlgYm1Yg8ijGbCI7csDhW5c08AS7LqXqtgA653HMTxsaaCn3bhSHDoIEYG4xRqOrdhFiZNo3u@mtFzdDOJ0yLMHbsdoGTX/ZzAMkqEY6Gw4Td051q7vgaxWLYue21Yn@nGTjp@pnlLyW/scYs67p3CeZjapguOEHRR1xKbOUhitdBe105saNAErzfQrP@mOroaMhI2WCVyb305OUEvwltl/FeNfD7TRi4@30tOebcrPzNIoaFqZcqX1l7VJHUdbTtNNZvFNT9EyoKr69ytmacwR8td6jUE6PriRB2bfJxSJwUARqlvOOp@2hGMVTAIVPuJawzefBLNarq7b6pYSkiyvAIGqbfP2w/cionCMvL0awANe1vZd@uWyKvZKG0o/JOiDeEyBw/PXiqnR86UOQ/eUhQkCRwVibfZjyx3w728z7dmPTnLvYYz2MsvwLdK8hDedTJBMhLQJQHZPL7m8k3uF@eNF73yqOe/X6WFA8qiPKyyNA4MMpzuliEuvLe0dUQ@6usFoWVylinJE0XlMkc12EFEIcW5VFheMRrGUpK/kk8cyLfN50OsfaNxvBTUdhd@AElOQ/yUQJAitpvogWVcmLVdPBtvWOFdpbHRYd6WKqx1NnYTSBysyiDDN11hQE3qnZX8U3vFOyV3jZwEOJOF4xdhzyeMlI78q9lipL@rZavon7eO1VPtXVaUjLRc4LI7PRN0BgLwssaFqvLmqzqnDikAnSUdVR6ePkKuQ8dStsZSIY2HYuEN9E2wnLyZ/iPWJZHf1TPmzhleg2mfKB81YdQtHynsaXKx8@UBHaYP/QDJfpPg0w6h7217gjo4LvTC8VBxETP2EGx00y9MYNciUSfDjeda7MA8IvmgpMUCqq@F9IdoxNFsWDOn9hfSNii3dPsv2B/YpqHM8NW4ngIkLHc1et9UkE3m0mQ6GO@lv8icg2eiK5eCtzyxYTWiJooMpHhfwRZ5urr7BLpFLnlSVBkbC3rbg45qSYIBDXgLvmoibFqwaOBkVwrlN4QXaHXyPXX6k@CNhwxjUWm4leFAOh72ExFL2YIBw7Fh7kYroOUFdT64AFDh5fX0xoGLuXGOJrOEGCR4H18edm3N@x4RycUk/1DsH4ctKp4VlkVoRrx44MnQsIUGvc0OKYPn6@a4li@jFMrY62CCt0TfRDhLVXbYWtMv7W/0KWVpLkFW4ptgVoR@sNC1Yx92aQo7tk2BKXS0ygm0Avla4xFYrFwxjsz/MkX9GIOCi0V@933tpWSV9tDIlMcsaFJCGwFHEvrn0BOhZTUgdofDlyHeDnwSwRmhXxTzKVBFD/QIu9xnfAs2F3HaXPXU3xFlNyFN1AMzlHBDJByAXAePgrzu7xaVREievRRv6/Jjcm/YhwxQQ2h67HDcHxjV9WmKYXqklIbd7Q@RD@ccfuc/3uWzkn8U1P1WqxfgsuTGqQGEYNJRFdnNXcHzgIXYt/pfjz7lQNgtzViJdVs1K9rdI5AxMOTZ5UIX9FfFKg@VHFHh@Z4n@nSkRPtB4kWfn0ngi@VE/VXb8um0HGHttKAE9qKetnwt5zL/@ozs05vfhgipw5J7IfYYLjRpjVOuix1K2gsxtB3GD@U/PqKiGODMV9NRzCYvypax1ecJCba4T9wuWgVYsTKds35mNQzPBix70Ts2UQa0m1LWES8guyi6PLH@STSuh0T1uzOa9mGdyFDu@wC58qrC1T7SMpmZu6MKhPa12NcdMGZCaC9QRZSmX3FpCqos4PG3koSIPhXMFZzQwqASAdu9KoHyiiG8U6g1z8byWH6u4YlEgsDSiBAtY2outTuKAikztPpmQNKmSct3hmKreqp8fN/LkKJY@sXmnyAYQ0CYZF2CxjL8YyniMxcHjUAA6Jag2TstFnD1dWLimTpWI/8VAT2eDumKy/HNx3oWcRiFy5gHFHI4Qxqkru3KhQ379Vw1T5asQBqtAWR0cQytLchehGOKomONCh0S5ZEMVwjcWMVDpuaRf5i3LvyBSxOLAFbvEIT6J@2j8Iq2MdIuSBWm6ERl5OpAe1NsQuru9OqFa4VlGa5Gsq4nJqXo0AaBkVNYJEUhRxrUnIcVZGHA8Za/fUZV2n5xQL9k40iVuL/VkUKVPUMyL7jnV5Qx5wxxclHoHQ1M4VLDZugwCniO/DbMtdAljCoQ1rHfaiguMUluVSaNZ01qyjuO4zAeoKXAa3AfaZIAwFM2PrQ65KhNOIX9DktG@AD0IcnyqDuuXrZffVrKqkRT6n8E4prtgycgfv/ulbPO/mFcft2oZGVQDx581CCY8la0a8y4uK@rryKvA/@Tsz/OMNYpdLIs9mMcaCkhiEg4pr@ixZaxWuYyyfppwePJs6qp5iVSmgyAjf4uTLkzVC0nttzttAUYuPvFZY1UGW8J8ntuS8CLgu4YWyXpEtha6IdOqi6m6jjPT6hk0oqqKsx22ftbULHU8qEkPMG8Xt2hV6yXaJf4vHGLhRZkIJwNt8b9tYqI7q0b2/yqK5AWPL6n@vDgxn567Til0e0e4Z0tALCMgNgaM4oMrlz72qIbRkOsF2ZhNXhEh/N1VMjdIKxyeF0pMgOWIW0@yBnuJnzvqROc/Ps4lITjGM29cW@AZi3snIya0@Fe0pRexG0s6MOWUd3L1EC@3dFcNZB8yw3pOMpBknF@Vl1EQHEdtG/dy1q4SYJ@Jl1/ldl4PUVOTOoPJgqDq6eJx1nHvngvGgDwCl0SjHYgLQEv/XuErRZ2BSDEsXiBy3moYX800cPVMda@ZeCW/vtmEsb9vBX4srI/O2uITUOCsRKvdziQzKfTTxiJtujNt8QFJJrCI8ITBV0Rh4kiqx4Lzs8PH9B9o0a4F22xKRCa2s8yYM/TVlX@a2rLUlCWbHMvW6RPHPsANx4M4N1K1ZrJllUE5DYqt753/Jxq1dmQZOP/Zedo18qwhCCEfJZzyStmxGN8YSr7omv5UeVT9/nu1X360jOaWwTNmQQimEri1DkRxvbb0wmdgj0WWp2ye/kz7YzBTw3@rhU5/tbaLf61rqrxGrFmXsaetB5lWyFJLfw9QU/b9T/EDU/zSc7yS0A1rWCVL/eeTgxYac/5qF85IB2EmMYB1TYaWGy4yBZPvmeRDAnIEMnWviyLRurOqyO33VcRq2HwF2T/h7o0OVgVaYdlscMs1h91UHPl2bswJZDGOcVi6cu15KUriVVw@7ER9tZmxIx9khXHXvmD7pEjGSwubZ8PV5u16bIdEK8OjFBV3TNjv3wl2h5QBdmU7SGk8aa51BTWAtR0iMo4EKgPuNZTaoL27ncxI6zGyN9J3Sd9FxV/w2wq6UrdbfKe6LezojAaEFMqdZHJOspqokFKdghdIfiQyZ4kjxbLUfSRTHsJkvHrZpWbcbHJH3Qh6Lq9Cd1WeoXcAVvxUGqMDbF3y1RoVhrR91WxWXx87kXHxJErpUCKLwv3STvCB73QwJ9Qn9ydum3T7XZjvV2VXlAxambzAbDCLKpoQZh22K1WFp1/Bj71M2ar56n5X7dD73bnHdWuiUBSjHNRI5YHUiJY9arZ@Q4Iz7tcb8ezuqeXY3ygpcGGH2axqACOI3YjMi5nJ1fnLrmbp63JCqTS1ZoZNLVq1FR7GhJzZikH2gnCC3PboH@T1Jv8KLeaNJmTBWCxM7996dXMTTvyie0ZWqWADqVLxkn10T8Bm1FTCVIiTBij5BCE7CUnGPQ1bF4scnlfqVZuqSNnq@5DrKQY21ZH8OjzvSYD4voJMRxHaGoPUAWRaX0@k691SqzZk2gidlnwvtnxHMUbl50pp0unY0sDTZVeS2HeztQ8RY9txU4uI8Xn9Jky@tG0JdZQa3EdqCsbWJrndRORV@@FokD1gnn4TAbMbGzM0M4NTFoEwblvNcTH0AjaHCalNuGPUZ28wPuC3IBValK@sdFAaSzbU3j/QqgoBBJgVLxlvnJf5sNys6Bd1HjrdxOGp2ohQnKArap/IBiIedG47DW6hqmL0BxXx7ek91WppdNmyirL7aWplAGudYoQtwjsleNJbeshRUMMsKflB9cAE6EwrlQ6YsXBrVikDjIrRWFb1Pbj7RCnZDX9yHRR2FKE2O4UlP1S8x7ar4uiNepRPWK6wkMPxmBrfssWzUtuhJB4rczw0S3tzPHSa27JE0/2gxwVwFnri2U9zboiKb6kyyhyLmskOWDyF7B4CM8ICAGFe@kFDEki/Od86@DrpyspmqXN2VwoosJBQfqt5ItRbIZQwrdKN8Rv@DGo36lXMjig9933I12YtdLkKJxXvUIVKnm4rMtZtTROXYLljpK102NL4IOOLSLKpNQSyHkybahZKcFRbndLYYxrUn11JF39yAzJbVgPekZmt2jzH3Ai9IvzWYrZkUz9awv9gKB@ObkgnlltVd@SJcrkfXjR6bjrZBFqzJLmsqHltLeLhKgkWH5wVbwiz1OJh3@lyWSVGpK1bxhZ1Wx71B0Ic3Ewv6i0Grck@XnQox5ksuifiUrEHLqDdqoo5zzPv1go1@KsAq4/ESuWt0rxQEUpecR0rDtf0QjwImmc0P0PRkGJMFX7KLzJRrU9ue2BQDIiW5SSfhCXFr1YWhXibHek7/QGopJrBGvCd1A1VzupJcDoUhuwKnzYhhK3YPDTojNYUdSQbYf6WmQzIT5JkCSRxVgjXRqkJbVLKb4rdoLi4XBaRTcRve88wZDXtvXzfhJgc6dFh2UTZ7YRoP0yHvkwP1CJxlaHAHRnLdUa@uYXgvjfGV7izfqryW5r77tjjeA98ZEIUw6Y1WZrX@OXitLRSFxiqh3WEDWzOLY3tlOH7/bgRK81l70ukWyS5EYPfUvojtoKXfHgt1pbDNLI6gTZjLw@b4i3pvsZBTk3w7NWFOACCLbJLb6nuYAFokmL8b5fEla/6/pgeMSh@OyLsfQg7jNIgP2oAz6s5GIqVe9c7tPOCpsC9bASECsxa3t0G9UanZdbJW@ZnaVSPdjk9QIcBdtXmQw3yoQuKwnd6YJT4sKXkR@cKwnaSCIkfboEEh6ht4k5AhlkamM05EfxuT8RJZzDb24LFva2q9mssWl13ofLaxlCzGk@3GpoQzu2Sj5fLCIlhtgwYl9biq2iVGbaOmQi27VVZUTMBV6mkFzyq13Oks1jGlaKGq7oIkE03H633AxckVCEiVksQu1rYA@DXZ86JgqtVAjRRmTFx7SOnU0xVUDtjFQo5wluGNq@9keREJNfKvmxbfglngUza1EH1@67qJWDBvv3@Lbd/bsEakhWF@Y8QFkg@9D/hIv5mZNBBfhKqp7Du4J1Ux@qMmmbS6kJTukQXKcs6xdT1M9Ygc1909m8DaLkf0S/OP3r3bZBeqq/wSWnph22c0vQRT0iSprg7RsGaJfRXBUctatzCLY8RNRMU3N5NO7KPAHPhRytRS9oF2GVqlaZEtEqA4uR86YgcFopK@iDU9b8ON49UApsBkWhKcPRrCdTmmwQW87UK990Xne3x6ePW8imE@H/vEBRXHr3@Q0YwtiDY@7YbMRawWGARRKzRCyv6yNQoPRchWgRVoY@NWNAOpeQPxVFwU4I7iJpiH3aqdwiUujjxMfyGGnJQBXZr0KleIPhRui3PU7C8204ze4dI5blPB8KxuA@yPktHJeD8yAG45R23KaEdkb7F7SWnRk6eKwWV7Gii70HajM0ci3w/DXvl0KrF2y61mLHEy5H57@RB3nVnBAYKHpWKST6v4Znh1VlBJYpGuUpt4vkj/415r9/RKGGNRN8YKk57wQ4Ges37xui@d2f58j3ytgOKRAtDzPNDqrpVG4E/8oln05T67DxPAKs5QinU40Omg@xpzKOD8sqe2XysLduN@rOLjqXyu0zzfF61fxM6bCc@@zYJaVHU93XeRfU8uvoSXF6t4UCIB4LuYzwdI2slNaUG2UjlZGBvEuSKyOLnt8dyQ4T50DyEAwJIjezdy@fIxdPAF8Vyf9Kt/PqGdhXVXwB6@W7hEpIZLl0SCf5xKZFba7@123msNE5K@0mQ3vKkQ8dzo1FQpw93MJUEzWh6FkxGJcIBoe8LgIwFILE/uMTqvb@HmHsI8bSWMLbVlubKSC61rMilyIHSb7XiczmIk6CR15sNua6FeP@5qwD4LVogDAswwbojUdAqsFKHQcOjK7uxc8w53WD7o3F2EqYmYgvSOehnCfMOWvzWJOsLMIgjsB1S5BGTL@psoTCdFJK/FXRfUpYulywqp/AQ93g3GU8WF@KQ2FQI7WbrwB2oBIaByUbCh3eXyyIKlkLi5Ie@xwRfRdO0S8CnVRJpAIXM8T2oSbuNgGvaMSEFSb9mVTDxa4H4aClm50W8y23l66xIRslGOuKT0Go6luFXK6ibuUBrlHBaQ38S@ko0ijn1L3DZKCwvfdJO8CsQWhWiRBRBELa4GWP9Ny/5wlWdAMWdICNIkMVr26QAfBl5HGhuo/CTQLzYQN/xMN1SclFFVbalpmNCLhkM4k5kbP1o@DTmCNs64IR83tmptBr2YcAHMl1Btraj0AM8KoimLrGE3RgqpZtybqHvDScB6hF0W@WgDOah7Axx2ZP6RLALqKeAESqJE2yqHs2CUEh@sia6UKGCxvL2E4VS7Tjat7QzCOzTnqVYhp7PMHSRuKKYmm5wdPCYgULLaBuDpiD8ezjosxunu1o6cTBkXE6Rkw7R5Y3JHC4mVmfZxg5BLQBRymO9IB4gx8IxktCWRe/zqdBp/u8S4zOWUDXTmA2TxLU6gnA7SLkIi4lWs1iLz3km95kIrvcJVRS09ib8zw9ZX4grxwuTcOEK9UrC4QCV1Xy3hKBpL5PjbLH06ePjLi65RwpBCcxiEhkhlI0OOC9LCdS3ZhLO4HUa1mtTH09u@GnOPFGfYbFx2aM8ifTpZ30Qiat3j5uRFMA4RjSovpYb81Vpa2IBQwVpRqPQ5RhQ8NM0UcDpXd@hAbQaC6F68YMCNjtA2QskHVVxXvzjQqgW3k@oHQ9Ue62BU/qJEfZ3caY3@IIIc4c/0WiN0@mdz@rmvTxHuhfZNY4Ij2QVbTPLN2h1aEM5@pewj6wY9iRafpYOaR1842KsBBBiV2l60YMQZpHmcg9Y51tdOhcndjO8TAA3gtE2zTAZz7sqaV0B4leWgc6eHKRjckh3BXdZXLZiK1CD0Pgm/qbLGm@wX5/V9O2bvn7CQYc/WN1i0WGOl4BH90/IW/4ykXphCb91R@hqGjEXArMdRInuq6YKXUo2CgE1GlxpQPTws9Zq5fxTdsdY19/MgCKlsYnOKZvCz37paRFBFQzETukmm6oipDEIwZxP81Kc0cMQP4WzbbVFkYW4nFf1IZNnRF5K1iXeJywAibIazehqyG1GvQQCnuDJzZDSTQEfif4tVGJoZyqBi9njncH3D/pwJfJ6OjSl4uMJcXGKPvz8L@Yn7rO5UNp0evXQodHT2KQW6IMyUPNitVSkk3uDevfW7ldRYLLLa0dJ5eSyVHVvkla4qVsTDSMTrTqdi/zSgj/FRKUphBT0/CKqKaqWarvo8qekC3@qCuD6Kalk5ZevBCjv/oQJymDQ8WzhPyiURVpyVrIjncek/qIh81GO3dt5ABLNGlikRksl60bEiOg1Sg75sZx/8DRwXbQYL@zWtw3UFpYvQBvVyufpXrEIkIw2YHXt/ToRoQsr0ihiXRHFOqDGtik8bgn6LS5fsznt2ABYXVVSNesmbWTEW@QHFJsnRlDlwH5Wd9jY@Tvc@xTlFvg@7NEh927VTVY@aR/LMhgkNgjcEL/V3qhQmi1C2HgJMavAp4W30k782mvrpeYYYKWyn2SBqWaclcjxxZSIIwzdRm@7KLtShG7NJRubRi6rzCiW5Wys19AJSB86lr3UmEdGnKoFnGSQRrX5t6lJTr0SYO8lbXiYEB3TMJXuq1LtwzH1FW0iDtkFFWjoor9C2jzW9blaF6R0fSxpjcRlKGYvYJ9sIG@zVpPTF3W2rXVV6Uy6PjdiTi6X7PcUBbmh1Q/oHgZErcb0xb1eUuEc/AjLGR5PM0VIpRQWOJzSnhrarOASPTnJOL7pRHibbh9umVROwp/1lkOzc0484bynd2cyHuBwtISlZsZlOH3dIp83aZDBYlPab9lu7d9O25OELrz11yU1Tzr/Ho55@t6iTL1WfuzyTTCLfkDTH2KXVVVUHX0vvbvmUfJGjkYaJwRiiqO2mwpw7NYQLb4ixqhefriYol@dUmVIneOUK8OD/sHDbOaNO5ZVTqh4Vy92rwNQLFrpDBKLo79bSZ/bIrASN4jJDwFWVzZ@1Uv9ruXf08pvOhM7Uc/pNmVqZADwRqafzCR01LjlxRYP3vpKuVS/ou9FQx7Q4tor3lbrX77AnzfndWQIt5d0d74TdjQuiDogLhIxOFYRxHyZrQxTC771ymJTJ0RG8ippHR2GEMCma8QOzV4JZbnRAuuSip8UmpQIA9KRuRfEWVsMZhhu87ewEk85CyZpYc4XUKALvcjSKaAfFSFD00qKupdrYRhBctiQ4p27NtiZhXLy3sI83lc/c8htx4SVlb0qqt7SwoHJiwnSNiESVsTA4ncLhCU79jX5FcZyeavZSZCy4sasknXgkCnBLtk2KmRHOzBI6hp2EE7s/s/ZW0rojWUhh1v2hCyNFushEjlSWgPdM0PZKz9/TNumsiQL6aMm21aSZBFzoe78p9vE@LpGcvFnGKgtlFl/E6saZI5IZ9jG7Ekoqx7CQBPD4jghnF7rfIeuLHKDnlaaDaWyjNiVuDIyuFrsDZtQCo0WMNt93C2zI@6pUl2VbcnBQV1vKX25KJGYSwm12qsCq3kxieafzskl7XRhq2YsVsSqc67QFBKjA73xMbfPQ9VIwG@GNUaTU2plG8YPVFIi8RAQ0qpxrg9wr9qITA8F76AS/aY5qXA4Wckmz@uCG4riNyp1pPv@xO7zEJmzSNa2yutcsGinWBu0DJXQPfKkUAeuIjMXFoRU47ydOknNU8B3tLxpJB@e5YK1LNr5lg4O2d/yNQod02jeXCp@C/iGD4oI265q3vxrS93VLIc@ZPu7uR/CN2tKvp0SchNgoxYPUVRKfT5r3RyXAac9Ma4Pq62iPWF2kUxy7K/RK6hLCQc2mIA@ibfH0hIqBITno/ql2Ekng3I2/QBfDC@uKDeaebe1@cEuU7Uj3ScKTo6PfjfLebULE/5kCrUtV/igEni5Loj4NBm5C9ykSTNb@vCEkvjaSPfgNerNQalQbBEeqQaBHUa8a569XQzIiBK7GT@JJz9KaTlaAdFA3AWldlVBTClxcBAl384vOMEvBiIZ3n89nLRUSEQsFr6kf0CakR8D8n@QMOhGjhu84N/7SahBx/gDBk3uaEh@xaHP3uyrmtIyUoF@OUGubuSBQQLab2e1AguouV8QfEeFq2lU51f4Kj2@Y3cSGtZFzfutUN@MPAmUKgSemdrgEQD0w1s9QVOSOM6otF6r1T5A1iyQj49m4WvwTF/QnSwKKToWUd54Xk80R@t7Lg4Lh4NC/U@0WyYNblUZw1@ArfOtFTPFBRfFsCrDQyuDuFen8RORET3PBhzYMijlDxZo3hciSKHy736P/hetkok5Jkgyo7JQNJ7V3r9BkahU4jANdRjLYM4D84iEA9jCUsoSStgWh88nDUuKOUVdzK@Mz@6Ppb3r14yGnZ3Y@ELGbJ87ZjePc/5TFjLNkPai2GfFshouC1NhDOtCsFAEXTICAEJ/kZyuMgQslyzvXiTpMtRmYkiKc6JntFWMTO7mcYhGceOA0dX0ddBSVJ4E0JtVwVBZSvDsJrBcGUiwt8UjdvB4FnxwT0F3cPzQZEpOq0CTqYXmrm4RTXPwfT5f9TOEaPSK38kglSzSxFgckFUlk7CIJOrcNDSu7l9AFL6YPwc6QJgnpc@wYMPegIhY/Kw4vToOxFUiBjtOwDZsCUKukmdl/j7yc6sAC/NkMiEGoO@vqgnZzPkMzNqHQTYHxAM/m3qSYHhmMUpT7IddVLC37ZHTR5u4RmYUiuk5KgJjND6KPxRUPa6buIMW3dbcanayfNjN7xRYgKCSRi8Ue4hbHQR6tUX2PwFNFjGJqAQ95785SF7gZk7D9FvGhhTm0ketGDjqhh3OwKSw5TPrgVCYRdVKPxp3G14Qr@9wb6g4HZ18RiGjHpqIrVaKFgrrh4mbBpMghHTxAkUmZOdF7nzRQ/ISBChvy4Gac@98givGxinqkxtu7IjAS2s7Zbsq4DmTIfjmjLdI4CKsiFCR77wXmM3NKbiP1xpGdlZzZvUEDedKdVPMriPEZIfUljUTkkeVUwTURFWikS@V0eThVXM9nvrObyYnhlSR3jgJGl3RGjZBpQOyZPaDbTcU@IjVtERNomuHVtLQWDI2u6Rhp32l1hDHDawUlEioz/gYKnKuI0DZmY6ii9Y/GlpUuTVKlYeeXjpKaKUaEmRUXxcckcJo6XYWauNslbiaQ/XSCWloBQb3lti/oB6sSsGRb94/EcXq0FvcxTlcPct2igxyGttdeWbI8b3q8KEJlUF9W9ATD41021uA@1bFMPpHWsFKWvsDM@7F@a0MbP@zgqrkKfHXezoJFslaUjG1YEv1ZEMNLnyqGfg/ucDFogepUV3KLLPC1YvNpTOCPEp@77E526ViPPK1x/50n4TQlr99CjCXU30KLbQ1/457dlXWUiyxUjucKm4GelumI1i9U/ckSwtkYmfKjyCo5WlytBsP@RNSJFDn9fgBNan9psoWNgHiCSaSYtiNzQ3Y06fTOix/hZX/1EFFwCFn1XczZtUVGAZH/KoHiHYmpLmW4StVNF1Bw2wQmxYIDEWVQpbxcp5xKFbVrimBUqG@YV1mg2J8fFbt0VF3@JNFjygnN48YsaBlDjsP6reaPwKd0wwdUlLahu6wDTT5HqN@jy7gcCgRVGx1EjOgmm0J12X4cYF8hAl02QWXoxSqqe@4essNFIx7eh02PJfAwPE48pvvItB8Q9WVXkELAd6XLYEibbMd1UA41hJ9XW@OKAA0lpMyNO3T6O738sPsGEBPK9fbIigxCPVfa5MwajT3d3iBBTKFr6N08Nha1wwTX5SnmCPLpnX3XbiDtLhXIMXZEF0iB5WY5vuti0Z3FncPqX4h4pEPnCcBfVuW@8eJlzfEFyK@U7EKvoGTO3tADqgW8ig0VhPIHSvS/qIjOzc61UfWA8FjYZ89ZTjbMvU86@dDoKXJqVBHtTctp2oAi8u5yHyOK6VIYFOOgmwhm2g1SlumfT9mLuKFaXl9LVDUSTFsajkE/Zke97md4ZEqtxC9uT5aaYjJqisW55eqsQzMkB7@ByhexWyWNdWdlLs8@@X20Ihg5zb55uln6litIFwjCEa68jrdHrM19k7RtmP1r7NQO4aYKQVjnXH3ZXZLhutNE/PjsRkTdXq7Zop8sHg1oSkm@qkyRemjOTZWtBhVSpGXeX@KpJVGXMJRtawh/QLkGJux52ZukzQMSyJtaAzK@4gGe0Hvu5juboZiTlkLpypiScC1CqK5RJFvnzvo4DHAJtw@zzc2bRQOC/CmMBMgoQh1vNiaKit64f5dDBdHptAEoWTdAOPQ7Z2laOX6hCKdn1ba/Gmor58JUI48Mu5uoZuNu7rDCbJflFDJtFy2c@iN1ReFvgEb0V4GlKZGXmLpO8GVIe5uNaePRd06ebMw6stjpHHYWPHwBvQjDKyOiZZokQHVmEcfmldMXRKpPxcBSO5dI6u7byHhBGposB9Q2@@qeR7htzHSA3bbEXpyMWqF71SDXTz7R9nFJn42p/eoemsx2uOR4Knm7eNjLNOcZWlpkzd3C2Au2j4c8bTcNroO6ADtcdzPMatuAeITxUhr5VF/8LtRVTTmITz8GURpIr3bqTYpRKPsvdPEhzhtW7rZ42mB2ksOsQ54Z5Rx1pZqfRT9GFVUuqSVcnDPSUC9OgZrQImpG79QVoSwjprRAxcbje8MAnetEwrCjZfu9PXq94BjvpiKE0fA7exleX0n9hUNrtSx0u5/os8h1NhoecWNOzk1iK9OWE1QmkOA7znA5R8ClZ1/2YumU5TVtJTPCJJDH4bskSRHh34uUKjfX3c7uCABfhDrctHWQydnPvlaBvdp3Vqy9L3r6XSJRKpqMt3vTW6eD1gWdLYaq0QM4kTepKUFmuFnwh7f@XCbz2S1Ar5ZSJEoUZJEGhBmZhmQwTKf4ilFn6Ibk2E9dS5LklMS4OuJTSUIpV5z1e5xXuQ5e0J1VdDNmOxPhL0oO8JXikP9uKPfd91YY@IiHhe9YcoImFFoDJEx7nbeVjhhYrUqYmVc2eWIkrGAHPY5aXbWj@ovAlKGXnMoQroNeK/e@3kEWmCPh6Amw7YzGl92utMQgVDOtQCKyFpEAKsKFE4g9y61HZoX5L47SkLeB/Hclw48Uc@xdaOp2J8YevGcpgQgcyy7QmELsubuoZG2N4qxvW3gGrXEmaAkBKfG/Sya8uuJzPEwYHKCFtmP8KdSn6cdiuI1bnvT6RYFjjrHBgvQTUSLh@TDtqUpV3PTpiVUQiyNO8@2FR8hcTNSCBjXJpITJqUj92@NLONZxOTRvMjlfwl9Hcz8ZHtKespS/NLuVnc2x1j2Jj31pDlLfoln0iIhYxSgBJvIvjgMSHADmlBIN1FHLvS5m9J01DptOW2yjp3hKgWJ4TFPtP3J4rIA1Ns8ilxbypmApbQjLaoiHAwW8ueoh5GhWjR9DwkpTDKAp01KyWIKh@d3SSt7jL7Tq8QhxIIlt3d9TdvFGuws98Bd4hnEV1ka4Vdv847Qt222TNFD/rOK@euANz3Cb4AVIKGfJ@ZYeftwhuVPQAMVniInRkl1hELIDhP2TOooJlJYDsdwD8PMD@AxQKtlsK53C2YVeHCYytjAlvNwjQcogKKCNr0GrIRXRzpLbXihNaX7EdsbmtOabz4pxqJLsQoMwrNlrSW@Ig0XkyCYmFoQdu0@Ibm5ZCWO0lPJDS6Bt1MJHq@RLI4FuQSza9iuef3Nu4EDzgnbST4MmhOvgGuKgSht05zb5Kdz562L5TRSoxfQZiqbbCrJKIWZImFrcMplvcZcEZZ1FWbgVDmcc6V4NtxyiAKk76IYWpU/kN5qZoebOe86HiLO@US/IoTkMoYOGkgLYhawReEreBbOz3vtwHY0npe7ZlNElKRbHNA0EqSyvAKJmaH4cKXNmx8ghwnjLqlnZ5fZMBRuRui1ioYZaMRdYB@l/y3/pIozd@9znTBH5pLZZ3i5uP1wAQE@7HVwaWzWM4rpkX7s2gsHwbi19mkUqBplhh4isFPTEsqSuT0R7SP2z56ktFmbIoX4k5fSUvyRKIHZgR3NI9l2q2ji8JqXKss7TWT45xarMoRdomp07vzZ8oLodlE3OhmdbndJrE/fKwUO4V9XYGwoVkAfkOYznFVonPJe5d1cNIiax2zLCqEU25dL3ej6X28TUcgfhkjSulpbiNZsHVnrz4F6QmaDQy7gioc7KcQR2En1lOaXN4NSfWExSTC2@sI69NkXW/HrqPHuieMAh7qP7QZIjKWZx8HLOzEVZChZlyrJctykpQCVC9fMeJUlKWMp3Vt1RCb/eN3ebAMc1HB7mQnVudSvkx568hQacG0cksblMS2NxJ84K6RQyO13euzonwl2JVCx0kZb7HqGNx5s7P0XpGHxBijE0nqMwVJl7bJfK3BbbUePx0EQqxDhgZphC1mHwMEv6TJaAqCdTDmU3J6ZHk7NUkR4ShKdVky@NNQ8tynq5b8oJdd0pHI7oo41UnjVshzyom83YGtT8qoKR5fXe6@TpNnsms8UzDqpqGCx/0i6VruEy1OYCZ/IeOKLvR5sG2dzwRpLPSJoqE13aJKxWjSgoGvJX4mq@z5Pggrtlm1Xo1/14SFu29mHThb9bmVqblEjUsAFaKKhG416wHapFBU2NTY1NI03Xe2YxtJyQsUnn0Per7XVHLERBO7UQrTViJp0GsTmHmxSismMVzQZoFPpfEXTBrVewd6W17oPQbMGyjQAW7yUVcyzPVlzvTBtjlQBhi4oi3OG4tRjMMYMKa6R7dByKUa2oswhJ6UHuyquZpKTlvzaOt9GFo7hLqCu98AEOeU8vshVfr4OGUyiz09K5xC/oH8SGhkohcB4/rxV@TgoZhPBDab1m2cwgK8iTLEhqOQPFKvJR95pZesKT5MIU/vJIprZJodJDYKyQ0JJAMmJLM4J7xA8kvD@5b9dkBTObrMHejGg4b6hwIisRQQKKWxYRkmUWZyu2WCFWJP7q46cssTAEjurYTFCg2SXjmn026nkQPex02QfHqx4/dJkkwTlvmrT4aHSB6OzGQS85sDmiARQhZtJodRn2OXp5NDnT4nr0vLgNQlrQp/IUQpmjRybdxJE2TNZcG24kvXqmkr1Vnhah7kcGSbRZ95D5jFuOfj0NVYSfuOKbMluacmlvKnha15BoowLmH4ocwJRkqX1EKcji45WM4eCgA7RgIKACtP73b0/liFBGF7XHfIjddAfzk27qbh0pntPatB5Vofr@Oen@0Cb95eEms21XeoKNNJ9ACjWxW3cQJNnCvaTP2hs1CCCvIV0ANT2rQriI3hOuyspKiorjNChQMlWl2XKQkkNeuAka7huvU2OFqrKriT7WhZeuJbXjMBnZmCDsOLtkhQLeptTI0o@GdTpVfTUHLnUIdTEXN9ZrSBjp7T4Jz6eVOIBlwemkUm6Gom4ZPI37dmu6Ov6C0whEKPCd6vRIKd/DO1eU9AvVPG3lvTl7RCyTrZhOT@iGlI7mo3Tj7z0@7LenxrBj8VmtulcYV315DJCVra7WxqmLNE0lTKX76C4KuaSxf1GjD6hOnBl348BJpYwE3xJnfGUK7oDKekQxtZmsq4rbqsbIM7Q4Dz1IB@ZVsNpK3tRTW@xhxaPjltDMQ0eE6pth3NR@qkiaq1XIVSFWe7iKZ6uqrEN8NY05gRBYK/5HSZqUewrm5y5CYyp/lay@pkpr8a2@UH@Hwq9I4rKdG3dUamU0GbgFnT7TebgBvMeCQQj/TZ1IKWHkhcJznhZEcHOPgBz9RbiLe9c/OYQUAFpu/cBcQo@bZxxHl1WHye5JeNZNScYjdRLnZnhCR5fmNnPuaAMZLAE762OaC2JUDNkRU03AvKvbyn/fVZkdds5zU44m/L47lzpB0jLJlBLRudW3ypX5QIE@kEaW7MPjwo5C/PscGrx0D0OswMiL2YpG2Jkd6BIaebNA7UF/vKCF7yGKgpA18eIKq2LW3AsrfVr@q7ksu/YsQW6ZzsXTXFNeehwp0mvKszwqjTYNfZcE1IpIJXZDxU296Ew4kqqwDkLSvhP9VdzVKha9IEP27k/i0j9VTNJ8ApOzoIUvkMg42wQxDZpUzJQk@Ws0LGlM9XTjgkqlpJsl1UPFBZExN1It0pdfjgk2z2Irvrv@TmOhm7c7sCuQi9G6luqkbXBBSQKJEymVh7c17l3LbU0Jsf/Wdf7ZmGGzJwrUtSlx5TJNYgYY7F/TuVpFtv2moUxF5Yy1DooodR4Qvmh4ohgqTGh4MrBLyWCOW7igIzd0M7Oldl3mU2T9qsnX5JaaSifCNy/1M6vhT4gxtvOSpUSZD5GyB2tKlZzHeJ7qFLA4/0wUj/CxR@5v8XRfcR/ckRj/dUcwgw/xLYFUZRkrj@rqYPJVLi5uw@jAvj3A3EzTprn3YglMhY@0LbqolPKddL95uEOE3b1bkeE9L73JcjnVFr61@rWZYLAhlFUcL2tuooc7XihIPHdLRWrOohBcI63Y@dUTDH4jO9qlKBUxpENM3Y9NmYoKjdIcue9qoO3VT6Xj82qsqko/f5PVf9W7VqPFP52Yr2p@BwK5ekAvXZr6tVGAvEdS4l01lFIBIneNQ/cG/7PS56soPERX143fZU5p0Xlraj@M@j@eDIloa1PyLYeoKsmFLerBTDjS0fqfc/p3JKOO6VYY9fEiN/xYthshjsv@Smdju1/9Qg@piRkzo6/UHSYJFrmKZPqXGt17JYTZN0udQMwzio8nRRut7ObaoLjy6tTvGZqoQv5oE5EK4MuTmVjq9dE0xeuCXAJ5xh4ux11/e4pQFZcqXeGA7hnxxABfLlxqRx8E4WRsQfj3W5VssUYiJH43qUpmo08Fn@IxrqIs01n28GBDVmfF/0j2gB5NZXZGupSWReIX7j1xad/Q5pwN9tvTJNvzrNN4U0v5xWrsA5TCEZkelHnPKV/cqYBEjlIg4KuJ7qmlnMTHhaMwySct@tYx4imlvHP4ROiz0ipJHV0UafSGygItbBumdlFBktqtgPkrtDDPCl/R/H0iTTYxR0MMmth3P2@KnCrWCXPI/NlRAr6eLGcue2ryJXc18dacsiZOnCcfvUlTznRjSgHGooHxVZEASVKyrfNy88BnqPpChppsT@29bm1lsoC1Am9qSJnNIE2YRyoAfbGoKCrhI/IwjFPYRF8vsTQKn0VFF20qCcBxCN8cICQ4jTg8ctQONCpNCrjSVaGKd@0k1Oj0XSlzma3dFA5EQjA4qSo/X9woMDfYXItsz1z30V34CkN1HSOge@2nFFZgbLY8I/gOMzkKycaORgmdb8xns7ax6r0QK90NL@PnocDPGbbY2HUt02hhZC2Ursd@eenh1V@cs657tcy0jD93Gziyu8@mhRAYNuhS3OQnG/fOjqOsb6t/VC0KF0fAxGsvwi2GHL3kO2ho2xRYWLkewRL1t1jtoFi7ynLSeuoNvkjskh3eA0mi2KKIUSXmoMumuoDmbel8rbB7FUOoBNt4ksrZ/ApNrbE@JBwR6bt1qMrW9ni3TEzqbV@zEVEPcvYMSqS3sCwKZCTqJwYO9kcoxCT1OCfgber/aLPU1/FuoOnem91jcqznA8tDrN5YMDUjxWeDRTwnK25ZGCDblD0e1S2pdEQ0fE/r6uKv7q0ct2vbOhu7VEEzNE6z3cZl8lVRfvwgxSuZZMbOxK2SwXupOXRNZp7Szm3g9o0lR9OZuHndxockpjwA4hcijO9InjoqNp1Z7GgmrsZJY58gL0VE29OV8GaUTxw@3R2q43FoHq4EeyKYVB7L@VfOOsa/rlRRFQXXrojdGLFQ2RyhKd7IywwVaEjKv@EJQXthFNihXwCDR87tnFI74sjKS6C@vVm35HZXtV@QMS0ccqeAb7@7UxW3nVkGAFXSUTElTtYKs2TCuInzSgWpQQjAkIuVPtO6KJt6Nj@uTUTcWLgUCLpBSmBg3HlIwJ0C78lp8YxEJ11l@l1Gz7iX3oF5fNVtdHbqjpscG07YHanwTB2prXNTjVSoKOvUWnGvCuYWc/IIA2YObUNpTjXSEQfV@m3y5UhGIgas8t6AqrD1zly6VZ/cdWFiIw1S7kBoPaOPXtzF4/U21fub@9S5CdmqzYw1H9hhLmgEK3E1RtoOIxIivZ62oVShwWIZJuDUyONebqZC1IN6qsZkSH8/LKjgIVWg@xXmmet2heo6R25Amuks4TtuuUZqj6bFeCScmAhisNNkqN8zlcgqtAMwvtM44KNj2iOlSaqS0xBWU1n6j8aZzEaztfdx9DwP@uIxhpEeuQ8WmTSkdWe9enhSaX05cpmPpMzBxn1Lrkwcu3vc3B3FYdFRRpp5x7W28pbaC14qwmTd6n6wZITnO1EPUfVs0gwEodFTdmcI9FNQM3gEgCJxVSgFvai7tIdpFjeHqhtl4L404TOmH93MsZk9ale9MsK5JTsKifkpOxV//zt@1lM3kR4EZqLIp0DuNmwX2QQSME0wH5pde6iuPgER75ya0jHT8Ko4YiCHZsTBGZ/caBjBxJhvGUpliU965dX6nLI5zHUaNVmnSDOmqrZzanShi4QUTqMbBEo4C936p7vrXm6HFLf/YaIW11yd0677Q@bdKWuy@q9p3yBq967kqDtSpHoZxzDJv3@DDKuM3Mtkom9tiR2xMh79mvmCvuyJgOnSSjvsFD5UrhmF2MkLstCWZ1agqj0RHQmP6RdLZRM@nuNv3IuQfXSqh50V1whwklvJYbtCY28edys1hs7ynKT3ZrQb@XsjMS0SVI9GoQiwQGb8cBYC5s6hnrlbsnloZ/RDDse2JgxKoWWPg5W4GqOxwTFFZOndrbiddRbGaUXCcGhJLIktAc@XJ5oMYWZk4GnhOSMSe6FMHL@inurYrw06xQw2rwkDi2cr52gEqpyewfdrs7S4Bc0xqbtgr/t@63Wm5kkTVMjL1o0SW1nr9WTE5z@2bq0mg9JqCz5LfVRiOVtxpLDSdXfm6TGrTJGi4YN3@h2m6LqmiC5DRPui4lIkNs2Px7gABaF9hywWAyzGnEgr6iS0Gd7qsgC5Tdn891QNfKyt8@oNM/S8c/PO2YHUNSMzmExe2lq3YTzGxB08OkNgwH1b8YxrHTzsTpPWhenFg/3IxQDDhjBD26gMSMw0N6ZDMJ/IiJorg8oYO8qs7SRL3cRqzSn3GSh5fFnR@Na3nfOiChYRssIbczGVfFmeXad/H@I0EuAp11oQJT9ZfOES51mNzTk3R85JmcI8sWjJPqUaELelH1JJYt6tn5YjcBSYekLa04UjSt1ZyM2E3GOwCX@zwePpzgBTrMGXPBi2ttNvi4mSwk6NTCydRa89KuXpeVQiPue/Wui958HjfBLauHfcpNRVlE1zC8aql@32Ef916ea1gxyM4qf/@wyXcc2OUcmuSahTOmT2S4bhckSSSAruaabZxHLukfJYAUZjEnNVVIVZ73VaqmcBQeN70k9ykJlR0tcFmJYRJhYvc3EKpZGmpZ6@nJ3kugZjNTHrCkQ3N7xi91So5MHh0/BvlF8qO3i69HWHhmOwuzTBPdQue91ApbVxmXFLhUFXVz0h@YBdpG/xk3wD2Jc3KTyZ@@S@FrYwwL1fOvNmZBXCcUrTLIxhDsxDRftYMQ2grceoW7KxGklzK9bJ5vJ9cUsKKjuewGd8jboX0SIzcJb8ME9ZMXIluvklR2R52pbr9ueMNmXWJtrQLOvjPnzockPmST5SmmWC11OgasX1@qR/rJH@3jfMyhtGOXgHDoW3UP1FjP5t6jEXE23t6sw6mhLqFn2O@amjkQL@vsmvOae2q1tc34cfpleoRyhJl0M5kyQ9l6pVF6@xmQh60cPqPSeGyupGc9DV@RpmPEfFmXVastHf78QYWPXX5WybvGHSI8dbvjsl9y01C20QrHX9oBow/O6tZ8ei2C0ggoIkC@F51jYx9YjVs01QK7jVFKrpsvnU/fHjFCrVFUS9i2YIJyLmC1lyVfwXecdI1v1LKbmOUpJ/h5ZP5WFqC8mXVthGoZWzkW0C@bMUBN858GrMvamnbrEoWj37Hsnl9b6g49XW/btAZFy/dmXPzk2b4RxPO2TvsrqiPk9MYiqBWlMUVQxWlIUOCg9Jz99VqMn6sd69Pf@m@a7b4ur8y9FGfMI9h/9O1jv1DYOB39ksWaT68A9NhfkYhDukP3l15gGXKrnivfaFQYFl@yzYpb7MkI8d27VOkBSyk3i0PCB5QVNtqvUAv29JHG5tIdgASQ2WPTu4i7WHFhqxO6vQqsn/mcNsFN5blBTAAEYtPQEwbsRDTMmK4mKTRZg03tQz25QHnbPFUGcuITG2zfG7AtYIQcnFmJGTA2Zzfb1SIixZs@8wd7jWxVqyn@NoPooQym9/gB/Wb/qqnNUL6U45D1eyUGo9Nd6kdnOck8uvhdEb/uEAe0fckUN1QwZMXt7jBb/GOPDe2iDMJX@8UaZ3zSH9zjFBsKsihuYXc@ZXD8uCVmT7J0wWYfIOlSQf1/SdQMqaQdwdgquX6cs7Zauw58YwHHhIQ1DHvLaWqsyzcq2uMfZjq6dSPZtcJnhOS5d7U@1Sxl6b5uGtFh8kYNGNrDEUfgZRmy9rYWqnCiPqRU3DZRtWT9YKUOn1qQJ@3uA6pVMWNee3uAggw69eHBW59NSiSwg5WbsvvyD0Ik@1ggPPUUpW8V0UqNyRvCVq@edn081kp9LHmHxFSXU0MbZLLbv9uHEzFIowdArFPzvLnOt09BNTmVAtShTzw5TUZpzOeopqSVFK7nEmOtmljkzPjsiq6WkDV6sD3OxyTE8qHg/j5awDpto//DfWjAo/57dO4IWgjDNTF9uAD@2fKK@CYWq4xG08aqU3f7BV4bev1106ybz1dH4TpVNQ4Wr4hyJXjcW4ZQSZtdOcQZ6h7ThG7vCypOSdrg91kUDb8gQQvUiH7T8eVnUiJDxbxKyW7Mp1lGob5Nanw5y3OTK2Pexn5Cr0jjIJJgv29rxL6v5Qrxj2zymq10lhsTM@Lg3oPkRFFV2Khr0o/PJYjRo@1fggy09HfMYqVPZmOe3wvRWSHHeoPb3RsVTVjzaoLFhkuFsOlyIGFYGZI0DHvuesUlWfWeoQHdImD1huP1Yh1asp9r5li0bJoM3wMNTU7RHprPZ3UpF6CjBeP@HwZ7SqiAWTFNBQfSmKHZqRRrB6vg6PI0DFsqZoQqTNoy4VYeLlvolR8xVqHepmw/6ViKiaK2SOXM5Vnc93hDG5dVYSxbPUoEP4R51vXtMchIrUhJTuzAEhsi3LOuZp8sRZkrYf00Pq3a3VA6nRg@vlLI/MSJg8kumLj/lFGifjhFQ9B20l0DxuurxIRAru30gN1lT9gfnrmXdxInuPs4KBxeQJHF@dyZv7UmoWov289wKih/hno85YZJatTGji6aAoeji@o0mR1G/3W5hqL/PSURKtpuB1bNNlPyJMijwfC1ZXvNTRkF1bM98/rZrQjra20c/UDzLZ7FPP0DlX76ZaGb3I@vupmkJ2FAEZQyDkJx4LoS6TTy4ARb84oxH9kEsO7cKDJWPBIiWdIXZXb@sWSIfq27r0@Xc1synaXXTMPd4ZbDH9Ipj1K115DjDUm1cbw1Ce9Y5eK@GdtyVDrGSBjamsmUBG@ZyGtNr8WhVGrLeCTsLnH75Loc15MdviSIrQXhlvzaxU4xNUF09qy5GLPuzWfVqP62XZoLjyQ3IPXQqXMJnUEFWfXbvKI0rgJFPz@Xh0w7SowI@NG3M4ACDJ9lkMOaxXj0fwtDKZJVwvQtqO549w2MqqOOXs0x9rgSK/GgyKrURQM5W4m5aB4nFuhu0PTOYCd9SzoXCJx2scNqfSBrgjHj68vNJtipkEIf1XJOz@3YRQPI27e9U85Cu20xisXw5ADzvTVdEOq7LkyVbpRl3/k7lXGeQcjjNb@Y5A5PWZ515y2HI96xLDToWUOOGJhmGEgQkivTlLJc0CMTVJkkrT@kEXKjaie3AkPdcj1j4yjmpc4cAvjad8PcWe4HrYXoZ7PE66LqKNiGgZDROy5YFLP889eNCxQuTBl21NVyfDdwREX5YFuGiuYdQHvvq@ZulWGhr@P3Bdm9BEzd6/AoNsz7QCp5B@N6JyQbLEZZdyBIEJdnw@nRFbArcGZhT/7npFq3VIKFi1j8E3xLB42MHLsxfELvcE4ErmuKtEAtMC61hj4QK4pRXZnqe57KL1CVrNZFn/XRW@pzPecsQMaQcITPxfuky04jslh/GE@QCRxpM4BQ2nf1TJxrp2UFud6t@nCzppyCIVyC3nuIiulvPq5pN@QX8HUuCM7ttFlToS@iIdu5rGZxtuTZ/jeOUf8oN@8/lr/fjEbxVk40LxePVfE2ezI89Tsu6fuKekKl2PBS@87/6VJjgEb7E0GgUlmZdjjiIfL25J4gwV2zEmNhIJ5UDNKovV51057IarJalcKnUVj0YNYyOXsBzdKcrK3v3624HIJxqoCQ8aC89KnmAnLGpyhPgFp3irSbIAiIogVz52OtUJ@Tun1r7XqqItKbHDf/7aFwW7tWvy@N7jKeL4ui@whk1SJ3LNnnzdoUqCkwZfqq@oSMbnTjEdSaWeA85LM1wR9rbG668uNXFd2xAGQvlKTRVWMpq29cBGdDErkPAkVbu5ZkObQfqKvq15Jwdlcz/Zmkr/B5xHk1l/Vuv4txFO6XgbgzohxCqsOX8Y1e8jAPuydl17TPCkmarJ7PmATehTaaHPSGDQW/gN6KF5Ux25xEjybjDcG7aVpNmm7fVPW1iHDh9rcNhPZsKkJC8RcWKl6rp7e45dXCFGPOcJvuwwjB0QCN5XkbunYnpAdWfGRACq1h3LWTlqApeJqKLonL@asX9Qog@eddzhGgvd9yTM0uhGLVrT8OyPrTLG7M8DT6xx9styvVKZa2pJIY2YWmciNRK18J7PUSdEsnObfbo6wRuzjzNJVsSBAUmz1VUNJPuXZ5WX@AQdtH/17ZHkt5518MGzn51WNOegeksAQp2Usn8fMBh9tFy/4xh9BbH9x1rI2lqFK1fSWpsUZLIRo@SQLTyEiNODQ7RaF6j1uArqFkaIH3Ni6w1WSq0vOOqPfVc@INCXEfBM8vvm2RBfEWs5zr@YSGEqxmOCEMX4aozdbAF8IlP3QUfKnwnq8dxDd5QUdxq8/imYzJ@2IkfFCMbjWMYbKet7nNOWOi4991xzUXmbq8DwqRpb9u7jTsN3vGvie9QSyyc7fHGJLDix6Ns@BbbnFOeQsk4mexdkLkTd36sgFOJG4jL3jrI92Wnu3deedR642@OUxixh/KV84a5ZR3QaQQogw3IkAQzwmXsUsFTLyNj8AD4pW7TCJNE37N1z7AHKNf/7ExciA9/St1f5lza3M81r@oJv31vqfI3vekVGdtTv8iaVp8mOA2NjQZfY9KPEWg634DjeqwMRdiSNtatI3UhEO861GmcRFopjRy2@1iRrExFK7560M31mrZdscEqbjJ1xtKjGTppGvkrppXqWnFuV0xoOS4C1WBxHJivv6zZVRCyPNxOhEmhpa70hxxR@F@VqijElrmeWKJ2w7sAy2ul5L8NZbrar8HOptNpfpIY0raLuMn3sx6d0Cp1EztoxxifP3EYPlah4YnXvCtZrbFVSPdhBqteGfxcM5mbAO2G3WEjHVbeQ7nqrswc/1SpPGGeoEOKXXqOXQ5kXLRfFRZmsHUn2eJzUznDAVdJpaP7JlLU56N1Q7ngUqbHLqdLcDCJBqK/fuYUqAZ7WlEOdsuriYqW4cFa5dAToMU468bMIOI55juJDgaF5SUR6WT6X3MmtygHafRCIWiQpn0iuN7U5fXysC4o0IExHH1f/rGjOJyrMDGpcv8HKWaWdxE3Hx7LN62WvfNSmRrY1D6oRfRaylv5/SR1tJnigj0Jpn3Vf/eN9KFz2xnshkGVdsaZSkUhNrp59E2NIaPvbceMPSLQcJXh0GdcaqledcsUb2W9t9UdrIpSsSpOJqfVL/2@OJpN4dd9yLLeLNW2TgUQuCdAqJq9zW2adwotnkUo0vzCZaVeHkx/w6gqGidZT8Qxp9rdhlKVDeixrmouLjvSoP/D9lXiReDnvwBwn6Hhx44yzkG@BPx7RYkmVRf96f@uP/IBpZJVImmmrBZNynV@W@@l9KnImB8NLLcGYhG6gxwp6@PO@/PpxaZuW0deoOVeiwfhPRARf3Xg8@2M6aiotY8mtUfe56eyifX4CPD937MtNMIkl4GtsSJSuUHo0bh3H5jklG/wTNB55hHRNj3zFyiHPA3JAaQPqDd1KY1Pukgo55lhXAd7ZUatj355@6SMdIAZ7N9uj61IziK9SQgHCSJeTB02JgnsgRGYuK0CowaBER0kZvvAZ4/rybNWj1ED3gqRKI93T8jywo2E/@BEqMjDoXitz3K2vcDYHChHASkRIveOwUC009SlXiNnWjw7upzgatxp1qO5OcFONCvYl@QljTW7WOtIQsyehlYyFny44PT81q/JHpRan2bnU4owc@akaldSZY3qVo/Zec2G09Q5dziPpyfhaEPbXaVF978aHrsx/tBKSbIEDCFcDhUPWeKd55vTcI2nQMk5qChheFZReKh5YQ7fqDF3yzdLOF0bB6n0oMPFj6lbmG6nQ3/tU2h@s4nLAxNner@9oEoroD7T9i4ZVcppGcqLkwZIm5gqJ9RMr/ISzrdDsLYcIy6sdkVAtMrfWNaoe@1Mf7yvGVAHNlBKS/Y274BZf1rj3gE5/ORMbuoEvcncZx6t8Cjifd2eWa/fStN/1C/886tJCADSyZCxfb520AxFR@j85m1AVPnuNbqqZHPmNFO8FmXbI4EofoF1BTs91lw8A6gAkyifIKFU0TIH@MGw2Y22CRMmVS06Qsq27JBWeHnb77KshyNIMgHTFaVwJ6Z0F9Ec2pmHyLYDqNVLB6jR@bRHnJDehlr18WhIEaz/urE5u/KJr5L/W0msF57Me2M88xVEzLscw@GI7R3P0F/PpE2JXGIrT89vr4qtd6XmZARZPgDnuSi1FUQ2vwQYDWCudIstEnwq1LsTHiXl8zZYUvoNk@XXbv1gi@wHBk@fopDt1UaKanpODmhlPKk1WPlr5lOGXLzAYI3L@xsoULDefStDYJ8VGMh789HzEabVcuqSEXabOiiJqQDgL7BVEKss3362krO4By/SWrIrC5xejoKH/6BuuyT/UitsHolaG9sELDst8sK@YZl8qb/ku42ISVq3/IQutfE9GrA7b9qd5ylWFIvIrX92nuGmBZ0s2oF7ltTl8VWwzs9IlKS7@v7iN0lrbVojY7t7U1uPnM8qvCGc/W2rhE3O0tbDAjdFMXdWa@mzynVP0K/kDFvVSqkX18IDVQP80TLGCh5xlZwP9N2/Yt/JW@efoWmQDqvTNpGrxBbh8Jd3FXf3frEDV9HP23baomm@QsSJiwL5NjmRT4hkL6ohIPJFD7BDQ8fr5tw@L/sgjy59l8/K50/puM2ttaROhEYDf1@oIuRyTKp0I2AlpeMvBfY2MhJq02o3i6y/d5g14NuNdjzG6sUdVnD/4jhBq44grtEzetUMkbTWN/2rJGKZ3R7eOVMWgjnTrfWpdbSKue2ejw7ytx109GrxdqsDb5kjarK4cJFPk6u40xi0ZF9dVhT96HJNPBTyuLXfJ2idv2QaP0tPPMoDRsrRJKPvV1apELVMqAUr/@Ls7sm7hJB6/k7f9iyxdB7kpxDRLT5qqRy2IPMoS4lPS2w6ebjEGjqGvtHi8lfWeZEfqE@7ADKghHGzjgx7i0pBS4UTGHN2dMjrgCI0aZF5SjypZiJq2VCjvK2f4vUlqQllZNaefiKdhQoukJytP5UMYLEk2ywJRTY2OK/sJ01WucDjFvSd5lVO4Nf9UZiofHNayZGj5yutX9GH97kxRBpB9AF3qp@cGH5UaCGkGeBqX5Pvc6riNYJ5HZpx@YrQ7Olhtrfs4Ks8bLIPku15OZTlr/FHv7lPISKqDmn40GzgwfTNMuVJYjnAoIXkKSCRUBkr9OkaVGcS37syUOpxtf@DiP5VnnSt8RutnGptPd4jnuyW/VCh11urMnBpAH1T@qKgx8mGJyGaIfqmlHg@18NXpftSKUay69erU@Jowzqpa8BeuZ5jBnQv9gYCqGcqI2BlZDVmK5P563GCmplQXjwj7YKmUT7yKENZNXRn7N@mUMY9bX2ywn5pzJLtA62PNuLok1NLsZhQ3a8lHQP/LZ8NUwyRy1kq7bchm6g1NyV2DSQRhbt3bAL9JmphHJRjo70DmROeVTucy7N9g8CtZT9lq/Xy6aPFhrTFM0gv84TN8ys1SJZ1uSU8AOPYcsk/5TxdoB9fanh8i6sfSeMwxbb3rZ94uwuUepwAdhU7Q1OZPvLjL/JDoyj0Kx3LQd1VD54oc7QeVoD9aCmVB6Yk38ans4wEm@Idrl5aiZt52@@meAo1vOU3C9O@vxppB8jzb5xE@dEthK067qr4j4V@dFe@TQdJeGX5bv/4Txd7Vx5dhkg8xWVHH9NX2lhSkMwmF/VN35Llfldo/q3vC5vNhoIocFYtMX49umPaPAkT@mJVELTe5fWf@ipVFGf60@x3n4CAfZ2tAtpNYQaFIpO@o19lMfNW0PTeqpspj@aPzz5cmt7NDHIc5SxX2TV2iqj4hbTja8u9fXMJDZU3ExeLxJV8RKXzwo9bhKKjybtHRbZM@f0QbbtfLBjgUGq5M3ovnzKm@svJWUNvGr3atbmTGQ20/kxsbuu8@QWV4l75zHLc0v61batN8wVGqmNdp@N8UXkTynzqBmVDEBt89nLDoLkCOS8Lin@2Ex5lWiUHwThXxGg6f8iGjfmM65YuwiqtQmCq46qqcuTWrVnyENr/w1bsr8g8SVfkC@5h6nMSPT1qnTHrZ54RHHQDZ603z3aVEj6nmqLmanbxhLHR367KedaBzyGtfrEn9Of11EipE5WPbFf62RC6n1zYICcnAP5sQ6h@rbaGwqwA76yzJmK/hD/YQLOOfeCKFKpBd59EB5rawZiYopxCZQPvRaDd8ua6DmuO56Zdlejf@2WTlajTU5cMizWi4fADV8t3tUb77GEqVJvIve0i4GxJKX4lJn9qKPvOcGcvxNnq1sbtNa3/0cwIxqcCYTRhHRUklOs2GXI6m108oj@duv7KApzz1iDKmcR6LGqJ71H0ZOwux5u9o7G62H7hJljS18r0/TbhQZJTIcKI9LLQnsc7@ZmkNx9Gi/8F0UST0NBVz7FG2ms4VQ/zQcAUFHf56HJQw2ds0Esi5me10TCp2LHzJZnhN@NhSDLA5QMitNjVrG1zuousgHogxLdnhTExba6NMiCkVYFbYe5czVUFJ9@9uXUazriEz11zVhFaxZr9aZ7ZktBtYsHDPlsbzYN3u1Y5@19/LQU74Y5UmcvIhO5zr8CozJRuH4suRzDiWyAD9i/pNAlERP4YyOSJJiUS8TcUPq/PkuVNcrjcPCFFbknOXUFCOtznC090064duhgh1rSTojpkk40Xc6uHydeNNKMgDXqyirak1S/dJLUz7GMBsHSQQXmT2YiF5gFj3xJJRqeFMnSWNFGWU7syZV4fpK8XBtnQwPYaV5eLvvhCVrwpZ@RRZ2pP4ihal@ZTP@@6LHshKSNDSPiqnHNWiUSWq/OrCbTP1mbOEEEpXSY6O72ga1zU72oxLjujy90E7fHWZimb7IijJcjRiSXsobqZ0fdzV1PY54VOSXGGF37rGevnakWekxQInRIeNh16DoWA/u1etmvuS5YDq66egcilV@YvY6lp7p8nqacaHynRM21alvkOpu3LGEEromlEzmEmMNOSDHAwIeunG9GU@T7OwGVUypB@UJKYjA6c9YnuOfcnoTvroxxBm4ClYiVS/CLqSMtWKdo@4mfAlqtZFpT5zsoXBft2ZAhBJt@d3bVhJfO02Wr4D1FK53ZV4rnvijvmDb1gOf1fLDblJV4jjKMAny7m2hHooN/w@K9Qd9ehPD3v55GY6cd896NkVlsMDKh5hWMxGYD3KTp@SmvSmzhI3WUQqa/Fdt@1or82psp/TX1zJvNe5k5/6PuflVikaYyWjtweXLUVEmiUFNjRZ06uTriglcvW73ac7FLgoOxY1x2c/T2gN1HhmOIZUmteApZNL/6bpla@7SlnMsfrRditrv50/yhTIHODyjwO2lq@eejjJQzyL@tQqz8ajFGq/sUbBJBWaOJN8IfkgJG565dGo4PSp7BJRTQvgpxulz929iRiHAbOmArZWExSfNDzM8d3JFYEJMypG7q195iYQl7/arDGlenNkd0z5KeacrG6Ky5552i6J421tP6nwF0mkfHDAQ/q7Pdq3EhFSEq7he7Um5CvsIexH0bYc40/4PellIbLovuflSMyVYmQXPeFfDZHrMBsvxUEFZdZnLfgrwpGooEE3z@NRgWhRtUEJwBE1OrL8IllF1KDntRrj6Dxt@erIP2id1tDRUDod6H7NLvKKhMO/0fGLsEDjBTQ1rGP@IE44I@Tv9kys0kC3aVWHaRkpdc75ZYvlfkrYnjllmA4cLy1AZuG1Skj5cVyzj4w@OiuCHlR@JVSaCgUPLGJA2XajZxr9cf@zMl@JRkcjZPYNw2Ietu6bb/TN2fqSDjjGhtMgFVfDktBf8VoN1D4V5vz7lJiWNkFXc1eGhwqp/bQ6XIGEPDhYyqi9TBjb@WmiLl8091IFRwidVfpADKN8tcfICjyKRhbL6WSvF@JhXfNQfEWM@NVipEWSiiwTyX0EylFsJe53IES/d@LA3w2/HlCV2O63VEhBCCxcKPsv2FvTjv9gYpSjM@qTN8KlzwadDDG@Dk1WU8jjSrMt27duDbirqJeGDKxDAPXkcuAdOiARtlXEt1RD@0ytqctRyf7U/GmnZ3ZgeqRUnyh/8LMYEHP1V4uNZjT@7dFeqzHMYumv8zakIVFm7T7KFHU2wTebHr9UdxQZTZvCpaU9OsdpFm@MQ/cS4h1rySc27exNSwA9O2UoQlgU4OkB8FUhx9lx7fn7Fjc5FFTG2oV@8ETmGnXFSRjqpSvZhfnVMv7h8S5I5tVKixJKt9TXju1PmgcQngq5tfeo78oX3KF6MYwTifFW@TIDILTsjWrxgMChzqBPXq/zvVLbluafp@ekktQlrV06FkZxf3QwttGkJy1mPMDCVIQ/O9AOjf3mQ1/B4H/oqxrusWSm2lzUbikzkNbPf/319ZjamkdnOFQbFOCsatYuA0e/Vr@CKK7WsF9H620cNbkVRhMclZaPZgudkrWZQob90@QgGyF9xs7j/1KLx7bFGlEaWfPAgH0YC@X0uUa1G10HsNN1aKCLNQo61Pdb6UHFkxUukoZ/TXvs0rs758TTlAxH/6Qc4FDSKkRM9gzG5@dvgW4sGyQT0k6jQYqzMYRPT0oz1JKsaZ1tZd8/mt/N424WVvYkpeFO/4FfHrrvjnI3PU1MF3j0w5S94ZrL8ig394gercXlSLqdMDNV6PicetbKV8tB@XQiXL5ZJOUrZz@sqsuxe@WcIEJXA2amoV4mMft9ZFOFKiMG@7I/6ZYZkQC4jSj2NwyeT9izgt4l8z/jho0yw5QJSAqztUc@CmFV2HEgVF6z9@JIecohEDcyzOyP2jXbZbhD39qk1MSKws7afZPJwiGX1aVnJ/T9C4yybW4Nc7a/WC@SWxXYeZ9Msdp@n7uH@XgXuIEulCh9lvBhVdv8TqsK6c9ZBc9dAorrPR78gQaRZjZ4cEb38VDGXY3ZuxhRPp3TVXjuYAZd2rMeVcj/p9@2RaH0jnp2HMh3V/vREjLVYigrETU7@zKW7@73/7@qK1lqGwiid/5SJQusYFkujWXifH3mLd093FyECiDN9PoWpt7Z6sKnoN84Ekg7n7JN7@XX4W5@IzwMFhshnYdy3t1PIJRqhTPwVMohg7bm62INUFRUK1lxuE9ukvpXVhgeoPbJRTQWRutx04xc6sL9/oM13O9uD/jvYqKjsqC1V3aALsBJ6jxpOzV/k6NsIjSboqm/14MmijCagfec52WJl3ZdK/cJByJb15MlsMaOLEmvqElCFtDJlJgaboGu78fuXQdn@dal/sptf206muypirsWKG6U1Ri0t6qf53cBvvqp@If@df2DGgSFgIZXM2nMrIgCaJjbtJuOZOmg0YcY0eRBH7laSiyyatfXkdtdd/sT8@/VlGAhz4yNiDX4QvLdA0rMBaPulzUjBeZHW6lPhZyb1@SJPCNeRgx8y/cwh54eIhJEshzCwr/q5fVz@ETBTeUxPAQibTwYBIU1ei1TCVN1c@AF4IxZgrYFE4HVWMxm3CWyCuyvkI38QMvjDvkCZxNovFwAFn3SQmZd4nqx2ud/EjKZlxzojlJzGjyeSfflU7rS1Pru8az6XnW1qK5zuD303UoEMc/X@Fn7BRAeBFCTXIECDE/CBbq1UQBL3MUicmbDwaMXuEntVY14bGNWuJCRj0tEA/qstv6JGN/fW38GzgVCikrJhYeU6N6DnVcvLN14lIAjMS/zlS/Jpzy0jh65kOSYgi@@R9r5SnGMsJMYuVQD0oL99KQBP7hOAzFeuXMJ@qABVAOIr3meH4tfDZRq6CMu4o9jJjWbTJnbW@AKfO4KJdg/05DSdUNiwDlleZhfv1Fxj8OsEaFHq19sUb6INnytA2pTvkFUIyD4jOVjRtw2sNT75x5ajDpCzTGdsreCK1Dju7ovw8rg5cZvz/W9Zzk9IPFla1AAlMvz/RikX1VsYwV7JpOQBfCe4JUFRj9WvUnWgrKMqDu3d9DlQ5ugZIrU209yZcwD2AadwFZwtsCMoAxkpZDUlpE8tQz4@ldyQqWvd0A7fkqQrhTsEUwscREwHnLingHOwV7yZCJjdWMB92JOvdw/jc0UjTPXPydEVoiIuFD@GwbFamrh/HufnBVNcIaq1Of0VidUlYlcP3YotRDo1RvuV2reXILmFSN8OTgsAVt2cfGLkcKLHZpSjVwolH54clv/MZ7fvqS8h5qg59wbjDj7ibgSvYsEt023EH@z9hsejcheUrOMhf51QSji5q6CO2NVf1H7Z0pVrGVZrVheq4jiG/CXl4YVhTVJfKZLoL3eb7UgGEQZcJILZh8XV@pXoaHYL2NJv6DtwoaSTll13lssZZSvdNDU2gEqAo1yZX4@uh@sP3j6EZQiAmQomY6kaxIlcABbZyQSyX8I2Nkyt8RD6tqzsjFbWdy7lGtboyO4YhC7P6idYbGrY6CUNk0BhQzP3ecl4F8s0u8lodsPccnRvc@vvbdnLynrRSIJ2vx3/8HiIxQ1z2pfFTru4rM6kssLdRjiCmQVq01WEWxyC9g@ruzTuqnF6xoUTTAVpCaxajbySehNtn@NFAUugDEtgD2uG0TO5DlTCnrl@cCT4jwPPow0pILQ0z2tPoTTgvPESk/pGtm0UJMs8PgU/GP6YkrxZFhqx7hXNnXPK0qFKWTgXUgsqdoJS2Gj2i1JuTIL9j9KVLXaRs1vy0jPqwGPq@00W3IxLrwAFwkgSFSDJsdWW7Nuaa6vkhqrbUhge1NISNgHC9OFk4uYFIAfor54yxhCgjPt3Db9BTegxfvnpxpEhKsR/iZjphCP6/eHqxs5e5CCl7QIGuo8t/Wua7kGdgGqI8fDIG2Nqkc4gSi@ySl3YPEKhKSi9hzV3n6NxdpHgJHaqEZBFF2pSfT8s1pj3E0zFrdor8mlDMG0aZgzS597n797ltpKUuBuaA5@J10rnZPb9NcYRaDhWfv84pdjB8ZqiDkexdc2Uec0CfAk9vT6BSWodQY2pes2w7wWMaxt@CbxhkpeabJyczK2SlRUUoWlW11SBmKyaRtajBRkCU4UnkGUViPbAyWuRK9s2x2W5Ky9AE733X/B1Wc2nznmOkA/rKYwg@d0UMOP4QFhfj@GMEDH7kUCeykrjcwiLzzheaZKFSsOhrJlSREKBN6/Sf8gf/dtuhdeMko29Py2Cm459NfIbv9eGm1iibxtJg9@g/BR7C4SdWkFaUr4GVq0Rh/f2kBGb4NYjgZPqXQMbXy2wKqzHtR6ua29DQAQ8rms9xzW0RgySAStCG@0XdNcJ0WapAdtJ0Y7h5VqW2kHF@r8Q9sk1g7Dls2Tx2LVf9KOSsuhM9Wn2g@QioivtHlUEYmuBto4v/Vn28fHfw)

#### Input is as follows:

```python
word_input
dic_entry_1
dic_entry_2
....
dic_entry_N
                 # <<< empty line + \n
```

#### Speeding it up:

For testing purposes, if you change from `I,*S=iter(input,'')` to `I=input();S=set(iter(input,''))`, the runtime will be reduced drastically and the output will be the same.

#### Explanation:

In every permutation of the input, it tries to split recursively the permutation in all possible locations, starting from left to right, without skipping letters, with words that are in the dictionary. If a split combination matches all the input permutation, the split words are sorted and added to a `set` that will be printed at the and of the evaluation.

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript, <s>139</s> <s>137</s> 129 Bytes

-2 Bytes thanks to @FelipeNardiBatista

-8 Bytes thanks to reading the docs ;)

```
k=>w=>{t=w;return k.reduce((a,v)=>{r=([...v].every(c=>w.includes(c)&&((w=w.replace(c,""))||!0)))?a.concat(v):a;w=t;return r},[])}
```

Takes in the dictionary as input in form of an array of strings.

```js
var arr = ["living", "code", "golf", "highway", "high", "way"];

var _=
k=>w=>{t=w;return k.reduce((a,v)=>{r=([...v].every(c=>w.includes(c)&&((w=w.replace(c,""))||!0)))?a.concat(v):a;w=t;return r},[])};

console.log(_(arr)("viinlg"));
console.log(_(arr)("fceodglo"));
```

**Explanation:**

For every word in dictionary, check if every letter is contained in the chosen word, while simultaneously removing it from the word. At the end of every dictionary entry, restore the word to its unaltered state to check for further matches.

Comment: @FelipeNardiBatista You're right, I forgot to golf that name. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `j`, 82 [bits<sup>v2</sup>](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyncode/blob/main/README.md), 10.25 bytes

```
ð+Þ×vṠ'sṠ⁰s=
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyI9aiIsIiIsIsOwK8Oew5d24bmgJ3PhuaDigbBzPSIsIiIsIltcInRoZVwiLFwib2ZcIixcImFuZFwiLFwidG9cIixcImFcIixcIml0XCIsXCJub3RcIixcImxpdmluZ1wiLFwiY29kZVwiLFwiZ29sZlwiLFwiaGlnaHdheVwiLFwiaGlnaFwiLFwid2F5XCIsXCJlbmRcIl1cbmFod2h5Z2kiXQ==)
Makes sure to output all acronyms with a single space to separate.

Answer (score 1):

## [Scala](https://www.scala-lang.org/), 156 bytes

Golfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZDBTsMwDIbve4qoJ1uLqsGxqJO4D3GYOCGE0jTpzEILTrYxTX324lBNghO5/Lbz5UuUaE0w09C8OZvUg6FeXRZKtc6rd2nAcBcrdc9szs/bxNR3L1ipp56SqoU8mqA8heR43owynSBUW/d5xfW@mius16GcYTjV61Pph9BunE8Ae5344BAv1kQHwLpBbYXPeqq5pL51X48eLN6RB1rXKwQu46GJP2ZYacLl7wEtb1AkLoiOtTeSOJavtzgpWVlrmOWtG4oJikBHOVRoVdihdTm7IficO@p2J3O@ljlzi4us@ZCrUujhzwfIj7FQR6I@dAX@T3rrhrYLw8yOi3H6Bg)

```scala
(l:Seq[String],k:String)=>l.filter(w=>w.foldLeft((k,true)){case((r,b),c)=>val i=r.indexOf(c);if(i>=0)(r.substring(0,i)+r.substring(i+1),b)else(r,false)}._2)
```

Ungolfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVHBasMwDL3nK0QPxaYhdDsGWujOHTuMncYYbiKnWr142G7aUPLtmZ00aQbdxbKsp6dnPZsJJdpW774wc/AsqIRLBJCjhG@fMGEKm8LGGFG/vzpDZfHBU3grycGqQwJUQoEwxudbso7NFFUeNothlukcQyy0kiHuqdifRD1cQwwpjzqeMDPbY3bYVIKU2JEiVzPrTAr95BgOWJ@0yYcHr@RJa4WiHMXAgEmkVvkWpWOBIgZnjsg5XCATFoExg@F/HatBe1SOx346h9X6ytN/jPKz5x7BCZU5nl8k89ARRxJYwK1XsORwY07scWc7oWwZByYOC7hXDc0LeOCDFJjPe73jCFRB9ESzFP5lqDfJ52N3bW6blKQcms4Rb07aeTM4eG@R0/pkm7436alYaPDruePRlS2GcHI@lfLjCZ0q2V853viKqFTF7Ir@FyYz1HmhdA9soiZq218)

```scala
object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val arr = List("living", "code", "golf", "highway", "high", "way")

    def checkAvailability(str: String, keyword: String): Boolean = {
      keyword.foldLeft((str, true)) { case ((remaining, result), ch) =>
        val idx = remaining.indexOf(ch)
        if (idx >= 0) (remaining.substring(0, idx) + remaining.substring(idx + 1), result && true)
        else (remaining, false)
      }._2
    }

    def filterList(arr: List[String], keyword: String): List[String] = {
      arr.filter(word => checkAvailability(keyword, word))
    }

    println(filterList(arr, "viinlg"))
    println(filterList(arr, "fceodglo"))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [OCaml](http://www.ocaml.org/), 224 bytes

Golfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tVC7bsMwDNz7FYQmCbWCJmthf0HRJWPRGI5N2TQUKbXo2AHy76mUuOhj76IjT3cHkr6uDvZ6tchgIADnLxR4ZcgyDtKMDiZd3Clvm9Ki4cTKOTurWhfJRvmWB3LtilyDc@mPDDPUQA4OFdcdEEzEHWz9AaHXxSIO4z7KnqDf/SRk/7hWIBfKomujc9a9XqvsfHn1DnUxZ6ayAZXkjIcx4qJmXwb8gOlyn9eb1KpLEVyjwm1BqSB/AEhlNQyQw5uwdIpe8Qyi9g0mbL01CTtqu6k6f5UJU/seF1syBgyj5XXMMbc8cSJythV/FZtvhanRN631i@YYB@cSXWPJIcjfd4bb@SvYgy6AYkCMEQK4Qxc5jCeI1A5EJuK7V@lvmUg9/1v2Rl0/AQ)

```ocaml
let f s t=List.filter(fun w->List.fold_left(fun(x,y)c->let i=String.index_opt x c in match i with Some j->String.sub x 0 j^String.sub x(j+1) (String.length x-j-1),y|None->x,false)(t,true)(String.to_seq w|>List.of_seq)|>snd)s
```

Ungolfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tVLLbsIwELzzFSsfIFYDKlwRfEHVC8eqRCGxEwtj09gBKvHv6a6dgETbIxe8mZmdfWGL/KC7TgsPUmkvmsz5RpnKgXYeMIbVCIDoRhSDpKjzxgWSoqCIGgUr2IT8mTKluGT26O86ZYLwkPuiRulZ@ToAV9jYgwBVXmC6HvJduwuZrwHfPsIJoS8w55D0jBam8nUgp9EL2RR804q@yrs1giqgJAWZa0dEaOpNOT@Lw0EiWwNn25QovQ2WpWD3OFwUWl1mWkgftUnw23EoyJzUCEwQmWDC741hxUEA4zGqeO9And7H8TZz4is2cl3HwlYSxodF2j2nK41GVDPht0vlDd4EPphWJ3RiS2CFLQW9ldWS3lpV9Tn/HkJ66fMzOsdru1b7@X2C4W9B5uyklNEVe5Qv/pHLQtiy0rZPOCLlM2FKrfAgyV87zXE5uEwlMVoBY@BrYRATeDSEtsBShr@4dOT6Xvnyad4L3nU/)

```ocaml
let filter_strings lst str =
  let rec filter_chars str char =
    let i = String.index_opt str char in
    match i with
    | Some idx -> String.sub str 0 idx ^ String.sub str (idx + 1) (String.length str - idx - 1), true
    | None -> str, false
  in
  List.filter (fun word ->
    let _, ok = List.fold_left (fun (str, b) c -> let str', b' = filter_chars str c in str', b && b') (str, true) (String.to_seq word |> List.of_seq) in
    ok) lst

let () =
  let arr = ["living"; "code"; "golf"; "highway"; "high"; "way"] in
  let result1 = filter_strings arr "viinlg" in
  let result2 = filter_strings arr "fceodglo" in
  print_endline (List.fold_left (fun a b -> if a = "" then b else a ^ "," ^ b) "" result1);
  print_endline (List.fold_left (fun a b -> if a = "" then b else a ^ "," ^ b) "" result2)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Elixir](https://elixir-lang.org/), 188 bytes

Golfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVCxagMxDN3vK8RNNigHXQNJpw4dQoeOpYNjy46Jzz50d7mWkG@/ymk61iCepPf0LEQpfkVeHfm@uDkRHEzM4EoDID3guRar3/msEp71Zv@S577zMU3E0vEZls2eEvXqTjC52ZJ6nzjm0AU2w4l6GtWi8XrGiWe61RmLV8bjbbOPHh5aW/IkX4/PitFqdGUL1wfFNCQjrkJg22JI5WjSFrxJI2mxQZJE5Iz31o2y0/ikK0isIM8www4@2hQv4tgitLY4qhhK8hVPMZwW8/2XVqzlZ1PHX986WW0gOynfKTET9hJjTqHV@l@Ft1ScbPurkVWaGk29cCeHXX8A)

```
f=fn(l,k)->Enum.filter(l,fn w->elem(Enum.reduce(String.graphemes(w),{k,true},fn c,{r,b}->if String.contains?(r,c),do: {String.replace(r,c,"",global: false),b},else: {r,false}end),1)end)end
```

Ungolfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVI9T8MwFNz7K06ZbMlEYkUCJgYGxMCIUOXaL6lVJ67spAVV/e3h2W1ou@Hlfd2dzx/k3beL02Sp6YIdPeFNux42LADuIY7nAmicHygu0xBd3yY8oukhfBoUNhJ3TwUDvPRjV5@gpyGj9pcxwHzmFlgkOxoSH0WxbqPerqmjJPZS4bBRGOJIx6JguBEVVsdrJcDoRDjTTegHtp6eBQONnF3PK2sxGYczPNLWa948gxWqSqH1YaX9AxrtE8m82Y3AsrAZXubXM@rt4iqXl8JTJ/i8Cvdz82@eSSXRMd/HZ@Xdjn2xj8oESzm2wTc5rl273uufOc0xl1@F/vpe86G3ZAZx@0C1YGWG7pzrfVtJ@T94YyhYvooTIbssTvOvqPkzTNMv)

```
defmodule Main do
  def run do
    filter_strings = fn (lst, k) ->
      Enum.filter(lst, fn w ->
        str = Enum.reduce(String.graphemes(w), {k, true}, fn c, {r, b} ->
          case String.contains?(r, c) do
            true -> {String.replace(r, c, "", global: false), b}
            _ -> {r, false}
          end
        end)
        elem(str, 1)
      end)
    end

    arr = ["living", "code", "golf", "highway", "high", "way"]
    IO.inspect(filter_strings.(arr, "viinlg"))
    IO.inspect(filter_strings.(arr, "fceodglo"))
  end
end

Main.run
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Erlang(escript)](https://tio.run/##hY8xa8MwEIX3/ArhSQLZpWtLAknGZPKSwRijWidHcJaMLKctxvnr6clp5wrEu7vvPXGCgMp1OYxtsEN85L3XEwLvlXWi2OTwNfgQeZX6l9daFA/Dz/Ik8h3aMY5vxmKEwM3k@IWGcyMPy/YXedS4kqOcS7lfiLdqBPbEPfQflDzKUnjDYpiA4k@kASHCiij23hAopVE4wgJOM7pyPskUWeRFyMM6YWdaLq3JG8Hy3YbR2YfAtqzK0N6s6zLJstZrSNp5NEmvtrt@qu@/Mmlqa7nmradfhF5Fnt2HuyNaGU6PkutmrcMuE7X412pa8LpDn8zF4wc), 156 bytes

Golfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hY8xa8MwEIX3/ArhSQLZpWtLAknGZPKSwRijWidHcJaMLKctxvnr6clp5wrEu7vvPXGCgMp1OYxtsEN85L3XEwLvlXWi2OTwNfgQeZX6l9daFA/Dz/Ik8h3aMY5vxmKEwM3k@IWGcyMPy/YXedS4kqOcS7lfiLdqBPbEPfQflDzKUnjDYpiA4k@kASHCiij23hAopVE4wgJOM7pyPskUWeRFyMM6YWdaLq3JG8Hy3YbR2YfAtqzK0N6s6zLJstZrSNp5NEmvtrt@qu@/Mmlqa7nmradfhF5Fnt2HuyNaGU6PkutmrcMuE7X412pa8LpDn8zF4wc)

```erlang
f(L,K)->lists:filter(fun(W)->{_,B}=lists:foldl(fun(C,{R,A})->case lists:member(C,R)of true->{lists:delete(C,R),A};_->{R,false}end end,{K,true},W),B end, L).
```

Ungolfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVGxboMwEN35CovJSCZV11atlHRMpiwZEELUPhNLxka2SVsh8uvUjgtVki59y/Hu7t2zHmBkrZocLDWic9OUt5r1EnBbC5Wtkhw@O20cLgJ/eCx9K@FCOjCVdUaoxuIdQdsM5a8J8pDCOvsUNzDvFT4so4ChImgzopd5T0sm8TINCJo3goY9QWtKxyv1DFpb@LnQQvvunbxinyHN71YDnOnBn0FDlDCQ4CBKosnznzJeSxt1/i0XMt7tgWLJDSdXjWFLLv7jdfuwsOx3sEnmE2gXcg6R42pJYG2MD65IpTj53FOCUqoZhNpoyUM9iub4UX/Nn6EGWkYLoX3epq0dTs/dWflpcfMnvYOXnIRQskmzMvufjlPQrJE6KFfJNH0D)

```erlang
-module(main).
-export([main/1]).

filter_strings(L, K) ->
    lists:filter(fun(W) ->
        {_, B} = lists:foldl(
            fun(C, {R, Acc}) ->
                case lists:member(C, R) of
                    true -> {lists:delete(C, R), Acc};
                    false -> {R, false}
                end
            end,
            {K, true},
            W
        ),
        B
    end, L).

main(_) ->
    Arr = ["living", "code", "golf", "highway", "high", "way"],
    io:format("~p~n", [filter_strings(Arr, "viinlg")]),
    io:format("~p~n", [filter_strings(Arr, "fceodglo")]).
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Racket](https://racket-lang.org/), 299 bytes

Golfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVBBboQwDLz3FRYc6rSqtPuAlocgDiEkIcIybJIF7dv6h35paxaQ2kr1xfY445k4ajPYfC9Js4e4NdhZF9higARGIdkMDmvClGNg//ZBIWVIqqkZTo3C4JCvRBWQKt3amV7H9wqNjgIZxShQt9b4Cmdg9YinQ8UBwaDQBco24tcnLpukxzrC0NQtlLn5q76o38LtSnnB2uyq4k3sR7G/vxsz2stcAUPplEJ/rNPTZLnDdG03QDgnsfgTENcMZ7Hc7t9Q6woJqY5bgY4RnrGgMAungMKMnZXkR3KS@uD7Rd/2StLaPG4Q0kT6Rgxyh3VHMYfA5P8ZOmPHztMo4/s3)

```
(define(i s c)(let f([l(string->list s)][n 0])(if(null? l)#f(if(char=?(car l)c)n(f(cdr l)(+ 1 n))))))
(define(f l k)(filter(λ(w)(let g([r k][b #t][l(string->list w)])(if(null? l)b(let*([c(car l)][n(i r c)])(if(not(eqv? n #f))(g(string-append(substring r 0 n)(substring r(+ n 1)))b(cdr l))#f)))))l))
```

Ungolfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVHbbsIwDH3nK6zysHgTEnzAxodUeUiTtER4SZcUOr6@c5uqAwbS8uLYPuf4FpU@2m4Y1qR8A3HyVithbO28BZG66Hyzcd7Yb0igcQUgyHZAIbQgyrQhl7oF9zF5CSWUmbKVI4M5Ongz/QBK4U9Ee8hchHUtl4w@qPi@Z7iKS14jTGILylLi1nIH2vwCxRvsMhRRIuLVHLWjzsZNbjMBwXGaJIdZS31WRoHoca6R3/WkEY48VQXrjk1PdyP3KG@pTHY1zJP2dJ8cX/UgNlZ85Wo6r4CJ8gFqfqW7O1DkXUl8SMjdBD6V/TrvwfHWEZ9Kz8udxVXbWm/YPVU5woW24PA2wtt3sOO1Q5XPws0/rzCWH7F0fSYVI7yIgtyZJQsodDCWTROoZnNwzaFXl/nHZnSYLoxLLakL@T93HgWLs3Oemv8ga22DaSgwdhh@AA)

```
#lang racket

(define (string-index s c)
  (let loop ([s-list (string->list s)] [index 0])
    (cond
      [(null? s-list) #f]
      [(char=? (car s-list) c) index]
      [else (loop (cdr s-list) (+ 1 index))])))

(define (filter-strings l k)
  (filter (lambda (w)
            (let loop ([r k] [b #t] [wl (string->list w)])
              (if (null? wl)
                  b
                  (let* ([c (car wl)]
                         [i (string-index r c)])
                    (if (not (eqv? i #f))
                        (loop (string-append (substring r 0 i) (substring r (+ i 1))) b (cdr wl))
                        #f))))) l))

(define arr '("living" "code" "golf" "highway" "high" "way"))
(displayln (filter-strings arr "viinlg"))
(displayln (filter-strings arr "fceodglo"))
```

Answer (score 0):

## [F#(.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 171 bytes

Golfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY/NasMwEITveYpFUJCgNuSatIEcC4VAcyw9qPKuvWQtJbJsN5B3dyVDbz3NDvPtHw2VCxGXcEUP5/uQsN8sggkIBPRlN6TIvjXwmu3jAO88pJpYEkZNo4cZqgMUvB@T/RaEmMkLcEkyfsZbTSFakZXWbuc6G01p6m1yHcT6zTf4cyLtDMycOnhAtS05WRkwOy4mwkuV2Q/sw4San7dmDymOaMx6q41l7acSnvKxag/KhQaLtkGoaMdtN9v7X1m02K/NNb@XyIN6OirQtI5SE7OXVpn/U3IYmlaCMssv)

```
let f l (k:string) = l |> List.filter(fun w -> let mutable r = k in w |> Seq.forall(fun (c:char) -> match r.IndexOf(c) with | -1 -> false | i -> r <- r.Remove(i,1); true))
```

Ungolfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZFPS8QwEMXv/RSPgJCAXfSqbsGjIAjuUTz0z6QNmyZLkrYu@N1r0mVXi4Jzmcn83pswifR5bR3Nsz2Qwe7oA/VZpilAKh3I7YJTpvXg@g5@qaGVDwJ8f24IbJEhhsZngedINycvl4MBn751ebHoFm28oR9CWWmCiwP2f5IqkuAGukBpHWoogwmNvXTPNhXlbvNkGvp4kbwWK4GSkRdb3CB0ZFYohcNDHs2v1NuRuLrG7dpO2tMvU5VMsvyJKnF6vtKltd6YVmPcnd2D1bahlFurZcqdarupPJ7LlNPxPTvE1wrSgF09MvD1P6SxbFTK6JaJ/5WyJtu02jIxz18)

```
open System

let filterStrings (l: string list) (k: string) = 
    l |> List.filter(fun (w: string) ->
        let mutable r = k
        let mutable b = true
        for c in w do
            let i = r.IndexOf(c)
            if i >= 0 then
                r <- r.Remove(i, 1)
            else
                b <- false
        b)

let arr = ["living"; "code"; "golf"; "highway"; "high"; "way"]
printfn "%A" (filterStrings arr "viinlg")
printfn "%A" (filterStrings arr "fceodglo")
```